# Documentation reference for LaTeX internal commands?

Tags: macros, documentation, latex-base

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`macros2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/macros2e)

Is there a place where I can find a reference of LaTeX internal commands? For example, just a few months ago I saw [an answer using `\@for`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-can-i-specify-a-long-list-of-math-operators/327#327) and today I found about [`\@star@or@long`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4784/169). Is there a place where these are documented? How did people using these commands learn about them?

Comment: I was just going to ask the same thing. I might write such a reference by myself, at least for the more common macros. It could be written as LaTeX document (of course) or maybe as community wiki here?

Comment: I compiled now a ten page document which lists all LaTeX2a internal macros I found useful. Its not ready to be published on CTAN but I'm happy to provide a copy.

Comment: @Martin: Nice! If you can post it somewhere, maybe you could also provide a link to the document as a new answer?

Comment: [Done](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/464339#464339) and [done](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands/10465#10465).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I now compiled such a document listing all internal macros of LaTeX2e which are also useful for package authors. The work title is "*List of internal LaTeX2e Macros useful to Package Authors*" and I'm planning to release it on CTAN 'soon' (e.g. as '`macros2e`') when its out of the beta stage.

The beta release can be found on [my website](http://www.scharrer-online.de/wiki/LaTeX/Docs/macros2e).
There is also a feedback form and email address on the website.
Please do not hesitate to suggest more macros I might have overlooked, better explanations of already listed macro, report errors of any kind or anything else.

#### Update 26th July 2011

It is now on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/macros2e). The [source repository](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/macros2e) is public. Please feel free to provide comments, patches or [open an issue ticket](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/macros2e/issues/new) if you find anything which can be improved.

Comment: `\protected@testopt` is an auxiliary command used only for the definition of commands taking an optional argument with `\newcommand`.

Comment: Even though this is mildly spam, I would like to thank too. :)

Comment: Do you have any plans to write some kind of correspondence between LaTeX2e internals and their LaTeX3 equivalents? Maybe such a reference exists, but if there is none, it would greatly help people wanting to get into LaTeX3.

Comment: @Jubobs: Sorry, no, I don't use LaTeX3 myself, so I don't have much knowledge about their internals.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Well, thanks for `macros2e` anyway :)

Comment: It can be displayed locally with `texdoc macros2e`, but for some reason in Ubuntu the `texlive-lang-english` package must be installed. -- Thanks for the great summary.

Answer (score 24):

I guess `texdoc source2e` is the answer to many of your questions. Both the macro's you mentioned are discussed in the manual, which is basically a documented source of LaTeX2e.

As for learning these commands, it's reading existing packages, reading the documentation and reading tex.stackexchange.com. At least it is for me :).

Comment: That's about the best there is, hence the work on LaTeX3 includes quite a bit of 'write some documentation' steps. Not perfect yet, but we are working on it, honest!

Comment: Yeah, the current situation is not much better than using `\show` on these macros.

Comment: @Juan: at least, by reading source2e, you can read a few comments that `\show` won't give you, and the exposition is a bit structured. But right, it's not a proper developer manual. source3 is *much* better in this respect.