# Adding a list of bios to the book class

Tags: macros

I am busy with a document where I need to add an Appendix with a list of names and short biographies (about a paragraph each).

I would be happier if I can do that as I describe the person in the relevant chapters save that to a macro and then add at the end. Similar to a Bibliography.

Is there a package that can do this or a way to build such macros?

Comment: Answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10919/215) might be of use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would take a slightly different approach than Seamus.

We first define a list to hold all the names. The list is to be delimited by commas:

```
\def\alist{}% {George, Martin, Seamus, Yiannis}
```

We then define helper macros to add a person to the list. At the same time we create a command on the fly to hold the Bio. For example typing `\Mary` will typeset the Bio for the person.

To print the Bios in the appendix we simply type,

```
\PrintBios
```

We also add a few helper functions to keep the list sorted, so that we can print them alphabetically. These are borrowed for the listings package (just a BubbleSort).

To loop through the list we use the `@for` from the LaTeX kernel.

Here is a minimal that includes all these. The Bios are just paragraphs from the `lipsum` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lstdoc,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\alist{}

\let\sort\lst@BubbleSort 
\def\addtolist#1#2{
  \lst@lAddTo\alist{#2}
}

\long\gdef\addPerson#1#2{\addtolist\alist{#1,}}

\def\AddBio#1#2{%
\long\expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname{\textbf{#1}: #2}
\addPerson{#1}{#2}
\sort\alist
}

\def\PrintBios{%
  \@for \i:=\alist\do{%
  \csname\i\endcsname}
}
%example
\AddBio{Yiannis}{\lipsum[2]}
\AddBio{Mary}{\lipsum[3]}
\AddBio{Ann}{\lipsum[1]}
% print the biographies
\PrintBios
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

I am not too sure how fast it will be for hundreds of Bios, but for about 100-200 the compiling time was imperceptible.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I brought cake! `:)` Amazing answer, Yiannis! `:)`

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of using the [`newfile`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/newfile) package to achieve this. It could obviously do with some tweaking. A lot of this is borrowed from answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10919/215). Also thanks to [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer) for comments.

The idea is to write each author bio to a file and then read them all in at the end.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newoutputstream{bios}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.bio}{bios}
\newcommand\styleauthor[1]{{\bfseries \begin{center}#1\end{center}}}
\newcommand\authorbio[2]{%
    \addtostream{bios}{%
      \unexpanded{%
        \styleauthor{#1}%
        \par
        #2
        \vspace{\baselineskip}}
    }
  }
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\authorbio{A. Author}{Here is a short bio on Albert Author

\lipsum[2]}

\chapter{Bar}

\authorbio{B. Buthor}{Here is a short bio on Brian Buthor

This allows newlines. Sweet.}

\appendix

\chapter{Author bios}
\closeoutputstream{bios}
\input{\jobname.bio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This only works for single paragraphs...

Comment: @Seamus no it doesn't. You fixed it, remember?

Comment: @Seamus: Why shouldn't it work with more than one paragraph? It works fine in my tests. The only trouble I see if `\par` is redefined in a fragile way. Which can be fixed using: `\newcommand\authorbio[2]{{\let\par\relax\addtostream{bios}{\noexpand\item[#1]  #2}}}`

Comment: @Martin Scharrer I hadn't actually thought it through. I was covering my back. It think the way the updated solution works should be even more robust and more easily customisable...

Comment: @Seamus: Why are you using `\tempauthor`?

Comment: @Martin I thought it might be more robust than having paragraph breaks in the argument of the macro. But I didn't actually try out the simpler solution...

Comment: @Seamus: Also i would recommend using `\protect` instead of `\noexpand`. It's much saver in writes. Here it might be ok, but e.g. `\addtocontents` writes the stuff first into the `.aux` file and then into the target file like `.toc`. Therefore you need more than one `\noexpand`. The `\protect` is then `\noexpand\protect\noexpand` :-)

Comment: @Martin but I just tested it and it does seem to work without it... I'm still getting the hang of when you are allowed `\par` and when you aren't. It breaks in frameboxes, for example...

Comment: Just use eTeX's `\unexpanded`: `\newcommand\authorbio[2]{%
    \addtostream{bios}{\unexpanded{\styleauthor{#1}\par#2\vspace{\baselineskip}}}%
}`. The current code breaks when the `\lipsum` is expanded. It's fragile I suppose. Using `\unexpanded` would make it much more user-friendly. Otherwise you should write `\long\def\tempauthor{#2}%` instead of `\def\tempauthor{#2}`.

Comment: @Martin thanks for the comments. I changed to `\protect` but I had to add a `{}` after the `\par` otherwise it complained of `Undefined control sequence \parHere`

Comment: @Seamus: `\protect` seems in this case to be set to `\string` which doesn't add a space after it like `\noexpand` does.

Comment: @Martin I didn't know about `\unexpanded`. That does seem to make for easier code.

Comment: @Seamus: I can't follow. It removes the need to use `\protect` or `\noexpand` in the second argument. Also, please add a `%` after each line which ends with `{`, otherwise you will get a space there.

Comment: @Martin good point, although I don't think the difference is noticeable...

Comment: an alternative to `\par` is `\endgraf`.  this tends to work in situations where the much-reformulated-by-latex `\par` causes problems.

Comment: @Seamus: like I said: without it, it breaks at `\lipsum` for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here's Yiannis' answer reimplemented in LaTeX3. The idea is exactly the same: the `\AddBio` command saves the author name and bio to macros, and uses the `sort` argument to name them. The `sort` is also what the authors are sorted by.

This makes use of egreg's solution to how to sort strings in an l3 way. (the code has the answer linked in a comment).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,expl3,kantlipsum,l3sort}



\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_authorlist_seq

% Sort, Author Name, Bio
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddBio}{mm+m}{
  \tl_new:c {l_#1_name_tl}
  \tl_gset:cn {l_#1_name_tl} {#2}
  \tl_new:c {l_#1_bio_tl} 
  \tl_gset:cn {l_#1_bio_tl} {#3}
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \l_authorlist_seq {#1}
}

% From egreg's answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52967/215

\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \string_compare:nnn #1 #2 #3 {TF}
  {
   \if_int_compare:w \pdftex_strcmp:D {#1}{#3} #2 \c_zero
    \prg_return_true:
   \else:
    \prg_return_false:
   \fi
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\sortauthors}{ }{
  \seq_sort:Nn \l_authorlist_seq {
    \string_compare:nnnTF {##1} {>} {##2} {\sort_reversed:} {\sort_ordered:}
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintBio}{m}{
  \textbf{\tl_use:c {l_#1_name_tl}:~} \tl_use:c{l_#1_bio_tl}\par
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintBios}{}{
  \sortauthors
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_authorlist_seq {\PrintBio{##1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

  \AddBio{foo}{Jethro Foo}{\kant[1-2]}
  \AddBio{bar}{Horatio Bar}{\kant[2-3]}
  \AddBio{kant}{Immanuel Kant}{\kant[5]}

\PrintBios
\end{document}
```

I'm sure some of the commands and so on don't live up to the macro naming conventions of LaTeX3, but it's a proof of concept...

Comment: I should have actually used `l3prop` rather than rely on token lists. I did it properly [here](https://github.com/scmbradley/schedule/blob/master/conference.cls) about line 93.

Comment: `\sort_ordered:` and `\sort_reversed:` are deprecated as of 2018-12-31; the right functions are `\sort_return_same:` and `\sort_return_swapped:`