# How to redefine the \\ in a tabular environment?

Tags: tables, macros

I want to redefine the tabular environment, such that each for example

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
AAA&BBB\\
CCC&DDD\\
\end{tabular}
```

would produce (for example)

```
AAA,BBB;CCC,DDD;
```

**Question 1** In order to redefine the `&`, i use the following :

```
\catcode`\&=\active
\gdef&{,}
```

Which works, but i don't know if it is safe. In particular, this works only if i put this outside from the definition of `tabular`, but i would prefer to have it inside, so that this definition vanishes when i quit the `Tabular`.

**Question 2** I don't know how to redefine the `\\`.

Answer (score 8):

If you tack your redefinitions on to the start of the definition of `\tabular` they will just be in scope for the environment because of the group from `\begin` `\end` although catcode changes are never stable mid document, you can make `&` active and your definition will work in a top level `tabular` but will not work if the `tabular` is in a `parbox` or ams alignment or anywhere else where it has been read as a macro argument so already tokenised.  It is better to make the `&` active at the start of the document and `\let` to a normal catcode 4 token so that it still works as an alignment point, then you can `\def` it to `,` in your special environment. The usual tabular definition of `\\` is `\@tabularcr` (which has different definitions depending if `array` is loaded.

so if you want `&` to act as an aligment point most of the time but have a local definition to a comma, do something like the following. Note that the redefinition works even inside the `\fbox` argument and the active `&` works before and after the local redefinition.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



    \let\savedtabular\tabular

    \catcode`&\active
    \catcode`A=4
    \let&A
    \catcode`A=11

\makeatletter
\def\commatable{%
    \def\tabular{\def&{,}\def\@tabularcr{;}\savedtabular}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{tabular}

{\commatable


\begin{tabular}{ll}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{tabular}


\fbox{\begin{tabular}{ll}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{tabular}}

}


\begin{tabular}{ll}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please explain more about "...`\let` to a normal catcode token..." ?

Comment: added code to show active `&` acting as a catcode 4 token (catcode 4 `A` but that doesn't really matter) and then locally switching to be defined to expand to a comma.

Comment: ok, now i understand your code. Actually, you let the old `tabular` act. I would prefer to completely rewrite (and simplify) the definition of `tabular`. At the end I want to be able to pass it into a `\edef` and a `\write`, but maybe it is a different question (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60851/10157)

Comment: well if you redefine tabular not to be "tabular" then the question of redefining `\\ ` in a tabular is moot:-) But still the point remains that its best not to change catcode mod document.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Actually, i needed to redefine \\, not only in tabular, but generally speaking. The point is, i did not know i can do it simply with `\def\\{new def}`...

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\begingroup
\catcode`\&=\active
\gdef&{,}
\endgroup
\newcommand\semikolon{;}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\catcode`\&=\active\let\\\semikolon}c|ccc}
AAA&BBB&CCC&DDD\\    CCC&DDD\\    \end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
AAA&BBB&CCC&DDD\\    CCC&DDD\\    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```