# Redefining \\ within tabu environment to be overlay-aware

Tags: beamer, overlays, tabu

## Background

I would like to "`alert`" each row of a table, one row at a time, using Beamer overlays.  Using [Martin Scharrer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18430/6510) to [Why can't I wrap \rowcolor in \only? (Beamer)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18427/6510), I came up with the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabu}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rowonly}{%
    \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
    \@rowonly
}
\newcommand<>{\@rowonly}[1]{%
    \only#2%
        {\ifnum0=`{\fi}#1{\ifnum0=`}\fi}%
    \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
    \ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\alertrow}{\rowonly{\rowfont{\color{red}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
  \onslide<+->
  \begin{tabu}{ll}
    \rowfont{\itshape\color{structure}}
                 Fruit    & Price \\
    \alertrow<+> Apples   & \$1 \\
    \alertrow<+> Bananas  & \$2 \\
    \alertrow<+> Cherries & \$3
  \end{tabu}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Eventually I'd like to package this kind of table into a custom environment, say `alertedfruitprices`, so that it can be reused cleanly.  In this environment, it might be nice to redefine `\\` to function just as `\\ \alertrow` does above.  That is, it might be nice for the following to behave as the above `tabu` does.

```
\begin{frame}{Example}
  \onslide<+->
  \begin{alertedfruitprices}
    \\<+> Apples   & \$1
    \\<+> Bananas  & \$2
    \\<+> Cherries & \$3
  \end{alertedfruitprices}
\end{frame}
```

## Problem

Unfortunately, I am having trouble getting this to work.  Ignoring the `alertedfruitprices` environment and sticking to a direct use of `tabu` for the moment, I tried to use `\let` and `\def\\` within the first column's preamble, adapting from the answers to [How to redefine the \\ in a tabular environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60935/6510).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabu}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rowonly}{%
    \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
    \@rowonly
}
\newcommand<>{\@rowonly}[1]{%
    \only#2%
        {\ifnum0=`{\fi}#1{\ifnum0=`}\fi}%
    \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
    \ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\alertrow}{\rowonly{\rowfont{\color{red}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
  \onslide<+->
  \begin{tabu}{>{\let\oldcr\\%
                 \def\\{\oldcr\alertrow}}
               ll}
    \rowfont{\itshape\color{structure}}
          Fruit    & Price
    \\<+> Apples   & \$1
    \\<+> Bananas  & \$2
    \\<+> Cherries & \$3
  \end{tabu}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For some reason, this code does not appear to properly redefine `\\`, as evidenced by no overlays and the printing of `<+>` at the beginning of each row:

[image]

## Question

Can someone please explain why the `\def\\` is not in effect within the `tabu`?

Comment: The redefinition of ``\\`` must go in the last column: `\begin{tabu}{l >{\let\oldcr\\\def\\{\oldcr\alertrow}}l}` because table cells form implicit groups.

Comment: @egreg Thanks!  If you want to convert that to an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every cell in a table is enclosed in a group, so your `\def` is performed in the first cell of a row and won't be valid in the second one. So do

```
\begin{tabu}{l >{\let\oldcr\\\def\\{\oldcr\alertrow}}l}
```

Even better, say

```
\newcommand{\beamerbackslash}{\let\oldcr\\\def\\{\oldcr\alertrow}}
```

in the preamble and

```
\begin{tabu}{l >{\beamerbackslash}l}
```

in the document body.