# How can I create a plain text ascii file from a latex document?

Tags: tex-core, text, ascii

I've found some books in *.tex format on Project Gutenberg and I want to create plain text ascii files from them.  How can I do this?

Comment: Adding more information or an example of a book found and the desired test format would be helpful to this question.

Comment: It's an old question, but https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19538/86 might be useful to look at.

Comment: The result may depend on the complexity of the source, so a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) including all the elements that should be converted (tables? image captions? bibliography? glossary? index? only text? ...? ) would be nice to test the accuracy of possible answers. Said that, with `detex mylatexbook.tex`, or using  `pandoc`, you should be able to recover without problems at least the main text.

Comment: Conversely, I like to include TeX fragments in emails, like `\sqrt` or `^\circ`.

Comment: Assuming it is the *Tractatus*, what would be the gain to have a plain text version?