# Where can I find the documentation for `lstdoc`?

Tags: listings, documentation

It appears that the `listings` package provides another package, called `lstdoc`, which in some unknown fashion provides facilities for printing TeX code samples while simultaneously TeXing them into the documentation itself.  Looking at `listings.dtx`, it seems that the samples in `listings.pdf` itself were typeset in this manner.  In fact, most package documentation provides such samples (code side-by-side with its effect) though I don't know how they all do it.  This is actually a tricky thing to get right by hand, so `lstdoc` looks like it would be useful; alas, I cannot find a single documented reference to it, neither in `listings.pdf` itself nor anywhere on CTAN or the Internet in general.

My question, then: how does this package work?  How can I learn about it?  Even a cursory glance at `listings.dtx` tells me nothing other than that it is somewhere in there.

Comment: The `showexpl` package provides this functionality. It is also included in `ydoc` which is however not stable yet.

Comment: @Martin: This looks rather more complete than `lstdoc`.  However, reading the developers' docs for `listings` has alerted me to the `\newdocenvironment` command, which solves a *different* problem that had bothered me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is in `listings.dtx`. Search for:

```
%<*doc>
\ProvidesPackage{lstdoc}
             [\filedate\space\fileversion\space(Carsten Heinz)]
%</doc>
```

It is a useful package, besides its presentational aspects. I use quite often, its sorting routine. See for example [Adding a list of bios to the book class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15330/adding-a-list-of-bios-to-the-book-class/15338#15338).

Comment: I found that line, but it doesn't seem to indicate anything special in the way of documentation.  Where are the publicly-accessible macros in `lstdoc` defined?

Comment: @Ryan Reich To print the developer's guide and all documentation there are instructions at the end of the general guide. You need to create a lstdoc.cfg file. If you just want to read through in the dtx read from line 14905, the macro you looking is `lstxsample`.

Comment: I see; it's good to know how that is done.  Thanks!