# Automatic generation of pages with variable fields

Tags: automation, exam

I need to produce dozens of same pages, except for the part that each page has to have a different person's name on it. Imagine it as an exam, where the content is equal for every page, except that I want to print the student's name in the header of somewhere else on the page.

From my programming perspective, one clue would be to make a list/series (or array in programming terms) of names in the beginning of a document, and invoke it further in the text as, say, `\student[i]`, where `i` is an integer (i.e. number of current page). But I have no idea how to implement it as this is my first touch of this topic.

My current document looks like this:

```
\begin{document}
\newcounter{i} 
\setcounter{i}{1} 
\whiledo{\value{i} < 50}{ 

Lorem ipsum ...
% The place where I need to put a variable string
Lorem ipsum ...

\newpage
\addtocounter{i}{1} 
}

\end{document}
```

This produces 49 equal pages, however, I don't know how to create a series of names in a variable, and then print on every page a different name following the series.

Comment: There's a tool called exceltex that allows you to import the values directly from a Excel spreadsheet cell. http://www.physik.uni-freiburg.de/~doerr/exceltex/index.en.html

Answer (score 12):

You can store the names in a comma delimited list and then iterate over it, using the LaTeX kernel command `\@for`.

So the names are stored as:

```
\def\names{Jon Mac, Yiannis Laz, Filip, Mary}
```

And iteration is achieved as shown in the minimal below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\names{Jon Mac, Yiannis Laz, Filip, Mary}
\@for\next:=\names\do{%
  \textbf{\next}\par\lipsum[1]\pagebreak
}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15338/963 for a bit of a longer explanation as to how to manipulate such lists (including alpha-numeric sorting).

Answer (score 10):

A solution that allows you to specify the list of students in a quite natural way and also the text of the exam between

```
\begin{exam}
<text>
\end{exam}
```

where `\thestudent` expands to the current student's name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\studentlist}{ m }
  {
   \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_exam_student_list_seq { ; } { #1 }
  }
\seq_new:N \l_exam_student_list_seq
\NewEnviron{exam}
  {
   \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_exam_student_list_seq
     {
      \cs_set:Npn \thestudent { ##1 }
      \BODY\newpage
     }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\studentlist{
  Copperfield, David;
  Doe, John;
  Liddell, Alice
}

\begin{exam}

This is the exam for \thestudent

\begin{enumerate}
\item Compute $1+1$
\item Tell if the formula $1+1=10$ is true or false
\end{enumerate}

\end{exam}

\end{document}
```

This will generate three copies of the text, each one with a different name.

Answer (score 8):

You may also consider using the `datatool` package.

You first create a comma separated variable (`.csv`) file like this

```
Number,Name,Subject,Date
PH001,Rajesh,Physics,12.02.2012
PH002,Mahesh,Physics,12.02.2012
PH003,Ganesh,Physics,12.02.2012
```

Name this file as `namelist-1.csv`  (say). Then your `.tex` file will be

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{names}{namelist-1.csv}
%==================================================================
\begin{document}
%
\DTLforeach{names}{
\no=Number,  \name=Name,  \sub=Subject, \date=Date}{%
%
This is the exam for \textbf{\name \, (\no)} in \sub \, held on \date.
%
\begin{enumerate}
\item Compute \(1+1\)
\item Tell if the formula $1+1=10$ is true or false
\end{enumerate}
%
\pagebreak
}
%
%
\end{document}
```

This will generate 3 pages of output corresponding to the three names in the database file `namelist-1.csv`. Here you can mention their Register number, Subject and dates also without much effort.

Answer (score 5):

A `\foreach` loop is provided by the `pgffor` package.  An example follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
    \foreach \x in {John, Mary} {My name is \x.\par}
\end{document}
```

More complex constructions are allowed.  For instance

```
\foreach \x / \y in {John/30, Mary/29} {\x, \y\ years old.\par}
```

Answer (score 4):

The basic idea is to define a macro that takes as parameter the part that varies. Below is a simplistic example. I would need to know more to come up with something that is closer to what you really need. Macros in TeX and LaTeX are a little advanced and I would suggest to read about them in the TeXbook. You can have up to 9 parameters per macro which should give you enough flexibility. A typical application of this outside of exercise sheets would be serial letters. The macro definition is declared as `\long` such that it can span several paragraphs which otherwise would be illegal (to help TeX catch runaway macro expansions).

```
\documentclass{article}

\long\def\exercise#1{%
Lorem ipsum ...
#1
Lorem ipsum ..
\newpage
}


\begin{document}
\exercise{Jane}
\exercise{James}
\exercise{Jim}
\end{document}
```

An advantage over list-based solutions is that there are no special characters (like a comma) that separate list elements and that you would have to avoid in the names and such. On the downside, a little more typing is necessary but could be reduced by picking a shorter name for the macro.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a similar implementation to Yiannis' answer, using the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). It provides `\docsvlist{<CSV list>}` which execute `\do{<item>}` for every `<item>` in `<CSV list>`. A redefinition of `\do` allows you to modify the behaviour of the output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
  \textbf{#1}\par\lipsum[1]\pagebreak}
\docsvlist{Jon Mac, Yiannis Laz, Filip, Mary}
\end{document}
```