# Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables

Tags: tables, conversion, tools, big-list, excel2latex

Manually hacking tables in LaTeX is one of the less funny things when preparing a document. Naturally, there are quite a few tools that promise to simplify this. In fact, I have somewhat lost track of all the tools available, and I'd like to gather your valuable experience into one big post. Some of the tools are mentioned in [Tool for manipulating LaTeX tables (HTML to LaTeX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1801/8057), but I feel there's much more around.

I'd suggest that somebody starts an overview with an alphabetic list (so that I can accept this answer and it stays on top), and that everyone replies with a "community wiki" entry, one reply per tool, and inserts the tool into the list.

Personally, I use Excel2LaTeX, but I'm unhappy with having to fire up Windows in order to generate the LaTeX code. I'm thinking of a rewrite as a standalone Python tool using the `xlrd` library, but I'm not too inclined to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: What, precisely, do you want to achieve with tables? I mean, do you need to format numbers / dates? Do you have repeative tasks in the form of numerical post-processing? Or do you need flexible typesetting (multicolumn/multirow/formatting/typesetting)? What is it that you are missing? auto-alternating colored rows? Or do you need WYSIWYG editing?

Comment: Yes to all questions :-) No, honestly. Anything that will take input data and produce `\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}` with something sensible inside is welcome here. I'm not asking for how to produce this-and-that output in LaTeX, I guess this has been covered enough on TeX.SX and elsewhere.

Comment: Not a tool as such, but it may be worthwhile to consider simpler layouts in general -- lots of difficulty arises from trying to reproduce a particular Excel format, when that format would go against many typographical guidelines (e.g., you really don't want that table with the double vertical rules, the borders around each cell, ...)

Comment: @MikeRenfro: I totally agree, in most cases you want what `booktabs` provides. However, sometimes these *tableaux* (as the `booktabs` documentation calls tables with inter-cell rules) are useful.

Comment: This question has already a very good answer concerning the available table packages: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12672/which-tabular-packages-do-which-tasks-and-which-packages-conflict.

Comment: I use Inlage, a user-friendly LaTeX editor, it allows editing of tables on-the-fly as of beta 5. However it's not freeware. I am sure scripting one's own LaTeX table parser won't take much effort with any programing language. I am interested to know too if there are existing efforts already.

Answer (score 84):

Often, I have the use-case that I want to convert a given data table into a "suitable" LaTeX table.

Typically, my data is of numeric type and requires number formatting, perhaps alignment at a decimal point, and in most cases, it requires elementary post-processing (like quotients, differences, gradients).

Since I needed such stuff very often, I wrote some C++ scripts which generated .tex files. It was useful - but I realized very early that it is insufficient; it is just not flexible enough and -as any external tool- produces unwanted complications due to the many tools involved.

My solution is the LaTeX package [pgfplotstable](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf). It is a LaTeX table *generator*, i.e. it converts input data explicitly by a set of configurable rules into something like `\begin{tabular}....\end{tabular}`.

DISCLAIMER NOTE: I wrote the package.

Among its features are

- separation of data + format
- data in form of external data files (CSV with customizable separators) or inline tables (inside of the `.tex` file)
- central format definition (for example in the preamble or in form of styles)
- format numbers with the full power of LaTeX
- supports simple text columns as well
- simple support for alternating row colors (`colortbl`)
- simple support for standart LaTeX table packages (`booktabs`, `longtable`, `colortbl`, `multirow`, `\multicolumn`,...)
- can produce completely new columns containing postprocessed data, with the powerful `pgf` math engine
- can convert single-column output to two-column output
- is written completely in TeX (no external tools required)
- highly customizable
- has a [manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf) with lots of examples.

You may want to inspect the link mentioned above and its examples to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Quite some time has passed, and the list grows and grows... Could you please add a CW answer that will contain a list of all tools mentioned plus a direct link to the answer? I will accept this answer so it stays on top. A stub will do, I'll add some more content. Danke schön :-)

Comment: Well, someone might change it to a community wikki (I do not know how). But why, precisely do you want to? I mean, there are lots of useful answers and readers of the page get some "community priorization" using the votes. Do you just want to have a "table-of-contents"-answer? IMHO, this is already given by the tex.se answer system here.

Comment: Yes, I would like to have a TOC answer, and I was suggesting that you add a new answer in addition to yours. -- What exactly do you mean by "this is already given by the tex.se answer system here"? Is there a way to display a brief overview of all answers?

Comment: Hm, you are right - there is no TOC as you requested. But whenever I try to find something, I am typically happy if I can browse through the answers of users - to see votes of others, comments, potential problems, examples,... a TOC seems somewhat out-of-place on this site (which is a Q&A site, after all). Perhaps you should take the information and write some short article - a survey about available table packages, including a comparison. On tex.se, I would not want to read a TOC answer unless it is automatically generated of the type `<pos> <number votes> <title>`.

Answer (score 50):

<sup>I was reluctant to publish this humble tool, but here it goes.</sup>

## excel2datatool

`excel2datatool` is a Java application I wrote to help me with a personal project. Since it was useful for me and I do believe it's generic enough for other purposes, I decided to make it publicly available. The repository is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/cereda/excel2datatool).

The whole idea is to read Microsoft Excel formats and generate `.csv` + `.tex` + `datatool`. Some might argue that this app is basically a CSV converter. Well, it is, but since I had to write a complementary `.tex` file with `\DTLloaddb`, I decided to automate steps.

[image: Main screen]

The app does not rely on Microsoft Excel. It supports both `xls` and `xlsx` out of the box. The usage is quite easy, double-click `excel2datatool.jar` in Windows and Mac, or run `java -jar excel2datatool` in Linux. The code is Java 5, 6, 7 and OpenJDK 6 compliant.

### Pros

- There's no need for Microsoft Excel or other office tool.
- It supports both `xls` and `xlsx` formats out of the box.
- Runs on every major operating system.
- The LaTeX file generation is optional, so you can use it as a normal CSV converter.

### Cons

- I wrote the app.
- Since it doesn't rely on external applications, the payload is quite big (9.5Mb).
- The LaTeX file will contain the most basic `datatool` usage, with `\DTLloaddb`. There are no advanced commands.
- No command line interface.
- Some people might not like the drag-and-drop style.
- The application tries its best to parse the Excel file, but there are probably some more complex files which won't be correctly converted.

Comment: Thumbs up for going open source!

Answer (score 42):

## Excel2LaTeX

An Excel add-in that converts parts of a spreadsheet into equivalent LaTeX tables.

Free.

CTAN: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/

Source: https://github.com/krlmlr/Excel2LaTeX

### Pros

- Most Excel formatting is supported.

  - Bold and italic (if applied to the whole cell)
  - Left, right, center, and general alignment (per-cell or per-column)
  - Vertical and horizontal borders (per-cell or per-column, single or double)
  - Font color (using the `xcolor` package)
  - Fill color (using the `colortbl` package)
  - Rotation (using the `rotating` package)
  - Merged cells (using the `multirow` package, if needed)
  - Can convert `\`, `$`, `_`, `^`, `%`, `&`, and `#` to appropriate macros, or leave them in-place
  - Supports `booktabs` package
  - Uses `bigstrut` package when `booktabs` is not available
- Can surround `tabular` environment with `table` environment template
- Copy output to clipboard or export to a `.tex` file for inclusion using `\include`
- Save table specifications to your Excel worksheet, then export all tables at once
- Configurable: Repeatedly convert the same ranges with one click

### Cons

- Requires Windows or OS X, and Excel to do the conversion

Comment: The small package "abstract" states that works up to Excel 2010.  Do you happen to know if this support is also available for Excel 2013?

Comment: I think it should work in Excel 2013, too. If not, please file a bug.

Comment: It works perfectly :)

Comment: I opened the file, but I don't see an "Add-Ins" tab. Any help?

Comment: @Jeff: Which Excel version is it?

Comment: I have Excel 2010

Comment: @Jeff: Macros must be enabled, there can be various reasons why macros don't run for a particular `.xla` file. Two new icons with captions like `Convert ... to LaTeX` must appear in one of the ribbons.

Comment: Throws a bug `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range` on my Excel 2016 Preview, OS X. Not sure how to edit and debug the file here... Normal text editors seem to unable to decipher the content.

Comment: @XiangJi: This is unfortunate, OS X always gives me pain, and I don't have access to Excel 2016 yet. Is a "Debug" button shown? This might take you to the code where the error actually occurs. Also, what's the "On error" setting in your Excel's VBA? (It should be one of "Always stop", "Stop if in class", "Never stop", or something the like.) -- Please consider reporting this issue on Launchpad.

Comment: Yes. I can see the place of error via debug. The line was `Set toolsMenu = myMenubar.Controls(6)` However I couldn't find any way to edit the line and execute again on OS X.

Comment: @XiangJi: Yes, the setup routine is brittle. Where is your `Excel2LaTeX.xla` installed? You might be able to edit the VBA code if you run it from a location where you have write permission.

Comment: @rdhs: What's the use case for more than 1000 cells in a LaTeX table?

Comment: Basically a resignation to tables in LaTeX. I am close to it as well.

Answer (score 38):

## Orgmode

Orgmode is a notes/planning mode for Emacs that has a nice table feature.

http://orgmode.org/

### Pros

- Column widths auto-adjust based on contents
- Behaves as a spreadsheet, including calculations, row/column insert and delete, row/column moves, rectangular selection
- Import and export of TAB or whitespace separated data
- Lots of export options (LaTeX, HTML, PDF)

### Cons

- Requires Emacs which has a significant learning curve if you are not already using it
- Some advanced LaTeX table formatting is still done manually after export

Comment: Great things it can do. How about formating of output? I tried first minor orgtbl-mode and after some troubles all worked ... see details of orgtbl-mode recommended bellow by https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9517/t-verron

Answer (score 24):

## LyX

[LyX](http://www.lyx.org) has a relatively decent table editor. By selecting *View->View Source*, one can directly see the resulting LaTeX code and easily copy&paste (and also **learn**) it from there. Furthermore, it is easy to typeset the result via LaTeX to get an impression on the actual look of the table. Other benefits are built-in support for `booktabs` and `longtable`.

[image]

The immediate representation of the resulting LaTeX source helped me a lot to actually learn the whistles and bells about LaTeX tabulars. Today I am fluent enough to use LyX only very seldom for this purpose.

You can even paste a table copied from e.g. Excel into LyX by following these [instructions](https://nd.psychstat.org/blog/copy_tables_from_excel_to_lyx):

1. In LyX, insert a table with the same dimensions as the one in the excel.
2. Place the mouse cursor in the top left cell of the table.
3. From the menu of LyX, choose `Edit → Paste Special → Plain Text, Join Lines`.

Comment: Very easy to use. Too bad it doesn't support the _combination_ of multirow and multicolumn.

Comment: You can paste into a LyX table from e.g. Excel by following the instructions at https://nd.psychstat.org/blog/copy_tables_from_excel_to_lyx



    1. In LyX, insert a table with the same dimensions as the one in the excel.
    2. Place the mouse cursor in the top left cell of the table.
    3. From the menu of LyX, choose Edit → Paste Special → Plain Text, Join Lines.

Answer (score 23):

## [LaTeX Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/)

Nice online LaTeX tables generator, supports:

- multicolumn;
- multirow;
- visual editing;
- custom borders;
- `booktabs` styles, coloring and various centering.

Comment: Nice pick! Only thing that is missing is a two-way editing mode.

Comment: @Daniel You mean paste TeX code and show interactive table? I'm not a creator of this... So can't help. :D

Comment: This looks very nice, but why on earth didn't they open-source the code to allow self-hosting? "Ein Schelm, wer Böses dabei denkt..."

Comment: @krlmlr First, why you need self-host it? Second, it's pure Javascript, it is open-source, just without a documentation.

Comment: I use it to answer a question here. It´s a good example of how to use the site. link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212593/48991

Answer (score 22):

## R + `xtable` package

R has the package [`xtable`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html) which generates LaTeX output - useful if you want R results in tabular form. This is an easy way if you're working in the R environment anyway.

Free.

### Pros

- At least the following table types can be converted to a nice table out of the box:

  - One-way and two-way cross tabulations
  - Data frames
  - Model estimation results

  (Anyone more familiar with `xtable` please append to this list.)
- Support for `booktabs` and `longtable`
- Optional enclosing in `table` environment with caption
- Formatting of numbers and cell contents can be specified
- Optional filtering ("sanitizing") of TeX special characters
- More flexibility in conjunction with [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/)/[Sweave](http://www.statistik.lmu.de/~leisch/Sweave/): The definition of the table can be "plain" LaTeX code, and the contents can be generated by an R chunk

### Cons

- Requires R, steep learning curve if you are not familiar with R
- No support for `multicolumn` and `multirow` cells
- Any special effects (such as [row and column headers for a contingency table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10703802/946850) require programming)

See also the following question for details on using `xtable`:

[How can I use a table generated by R in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25575/2693)

The [`Hmisc`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) package can also generate tabular output from R.

Comment: I would absolutely recommend this path, but **only** if you already are in the R environment and if you are creating a more or less "standard" table. Feeding data into R just to produce a (complicated) LaTeX table is possible, but then you might want to consider one of the other options listed here.

Answer (score 18):

## Emacs `align-current` and rectangles

OK, this isn't really much of an answer, but if you already have a table in LaTeX and you just want to edit it a bit, it can get a bit messy. If you use emacs then the following tools are super helpful.

First, `align-current` tries to line up your `&`s so that your data is more or less in columns. You can then use emacs' `C-x r k` to cut rectangles out,
and `C-x r y` to paste rectangles back into your table.

Here are some links:

- [Blog post about the above trick](http://babbagefiles.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/latex-table-manipulation-using.html)
- [Another post about rectangles](http://emacsworld.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/graphical-tutorial-of-emacs-rectangle_26.html)
- [Emacs manual on rectangles](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html)

Comment: Not sure if the links cover this (I am on my phone now) but I had to change my font to be monospaced before The tools you mentioned could actually work for me.

Answer (score 17):

## Calc2LaTeX

For the sake of completeness: You know, there is the spreadsheet programm of the OpenOffice / LibreOffice suite, simply called »calc«. It runs on Linux, Windows and probably on Mac, and it imports Excel spreadsheets quite nicely, if you haven't done more than using tables.

From calc to LaTeX there is an add to calc: [calc2Latex](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/Calc2LaTeX)

Works nicely, I've been using it for years.

Answer (score 14):

## LaTable

A visual editor for LaTeX tables for Windows and Macintosh. [It can be downloaded from CTAN.](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latable)

The application provides a spreadsheet-like interface with the ability to insert and delete rows and columns, to edit the cells and to set the borders. Tables can be im- and exported as plain text or CSV files or saved in LaTable's own file format `.latbl`.

A (rather horribly-looking) example:

[image: screenshot of LaTable with an example table]

The code generated for this example table:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|ll|l}
\cline{3-3}
first column & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{second column} & third column & fourth column \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{2} & 3 & 4 \\ 
\cline{3-3}
5 & 6 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{7} & 8 \\ 
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-4}
9 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} & 11 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{12} \\ 
\cline{4-4}
\end{tabular}
```

And this is the compiled LaTeX result for comparison:

[image: typeset LaTeX output for the above table]

Comment: The Mac version seems to fail on Snow Leopard. Did anyone tried it with another OS X?

Comment: Thanks for the app. I will be very more fantastic if it could merge cells on a column too.

Comment: At Mountain Lion, the app doesn't start. Some error message, but crashes before I can read it.

Comment: @trmdttr record your screen with QuickTime and scan through. It might be dependent on Rosetta, which was discontinued with lion. :'(

Comment: There is no way to merge cells column-wise.

Answer (score 14):

## csv2latex

For Mac users there is the script [`csv2latex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csv2latex) which allows you to cut and paste spreadsheet cells from Excel, Number or Calc and paste them into your LaTeX source in a variety of popular table formats.

If you use TeXShop as your editor, this functionality is built into the program: there is a Paste Spreadsheet Cells macro in the Macros menu.  For other Applescript-aware Mac editors, you can install the script manually.

*Disclaimer:* I am the author.

Comment: why only for Mac users?

Comment: @Aradnix Because at the time I wrote it there was no equivalent of the MacOS `pbcopy`, `pbpaste` on other platforms. Whether this has changed, I don't know.

Answer (score 13):

## Direct spreadsheet editing

I've been handling data tables from Excel into LaTeX for lab reports for some while and I have tried several tools. I would like to make the case that unless you consistently require formatting of the same style, then quite often the simplest answer is to direct copy-paste from your spreadsheet into LaTeX with inserted columns including whatever separators you want.

This is particularly useful if you need extra mark-up between columns, such as `$ ... $` signs or extra mathematical stuff such as units and the like.

This is arguably best for producing tableaux rather than formal scientific tables, and it does have the disadvantage that it inextricably links up data and formatting. On the other hand, that gives you a lot of freedom for data-dependent formatting. My most recent use of this was the following table, for my dissertation:

[image]

I can really not think of other ways of doing this - and particularly of ways that would later on enable me to easily change one of the functions displayed. This is of course not a scientific table, but this tableau is I think the clearest such presentation of these functions. (Spreadsheet and source code available on request.)

Comment: Sorry, but I just not understand your approach. Maybe you could clarify how exactly you *direct copy-paste from your spreadsheet into LaTeX*?

Comment: On Excel, simply select all the cells you want and hit ctrl+C, then paste into the LaTeX file. This needs every other column to contain a separator, starting from `&` or fancier if needed. For the table above an example separator is `=CONCATENATE("} & \cellcolor{color",TEXT(L5,"0"),"} \textcolor{text",TEXT(L5,"0"),"}{")`

Comment: That sounds like a really interesting approach! Maybe you could improve your answer by elaborating on this in more detail and provide a complete MWE?

Comment: An off-topic comment: Those "minus" signs in your headers and first columns are dashes, rather than real minus signs (you probably wrote -xxx instead of $-xxx$)... Remember to use the appropriate one for your reports/papers/etc. !

Comment: @YuppieNetworking well caught, you're actually right. I would make the case, on the other hand, that $-xxx$ makes longer dashes in cells where space is at a premium.

Comment: @Daniel, I can provide the code here but it's the spreadsheet that's really valuable, and I don't see how I could post it here.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using this approach for table generation, but using excel as a line-based string-handling tool is a handy trick (creating batch files to apply complex renaming rules for example)

Comment: What tex editor do you use?

Comment: If anyone is still confused about how to use this, here is a simple example of it in action: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156181

Answer (score 10):

## Numbers2LaTeX

A quick hack from long time ago that converts a table in [numbers](http://www.apple.com/de/iwork/numbers/) (for Mac OS X) to a LaTeX table: https://gist.github.com/386384

Answer (score 10):

## Kile

http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/extragear-office/kile/wizard_array.html

[image]

http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/extragear-office/kile/wizard_array.html

> Arrays and tabulars
>
> One of the most boring jobs one can do in LATEX is to write a matrix
>   or a tabular environment. One has to keep track of all the elements,
>   ensure that the environment is well formed, and that all things are
>   where they are supposed to be. Good indentation helps, but there is a
>   ***simpler way***: using **Kile's Wizard → Array or Wizard → Tabular menu**
>   entries. You will then have a matrix-formed input form that you can
>   easily fill in with your entries. This dialog also offers some options
>   to typeset the tabular material.

Comment: It seems buggy though; I prefer exporting the raw table via gnumeric!

Answer (score 9):

**Warning:** what's below is more of a tongue-in-cheek answer, but not without a shred of truth in it!

## `\halign` *&* `\valign`

### Pro

- It's what you'd eventually get with the other packages (most likely) anyways
- format agnostic – it's a TeX primitive
- Once you grok it, you'll be able to produce typographically beautiful tables more easily, and, on the other hand,
- creating typographically ugly tables is difficult

### Contra

- there's a learning curve
- creating typographically ugly tables is difficult `;-)`

---

To expand a little, to think about what one is doing when inputting tabular data is that, if, for example, one is working on a spreadsheet program, what you are mentally doing is that every time you want to express that you want to move on to the next horizontal cell you press `tab`, and every time you want to move to the next row you press `enter`.

Now, if you just input `&` instead of `tab`, and `\cr` instead of `enter`, you can skip all the intermediary steps. That is, converting the spreadsheet program generated chunk into `tabular` (or whatever), and then expanding *that* out to a `\halign`.

Similarly, by the time that you've navigated with your mouse through the various menus in the spreadsheet program to express that you want a particular cell to span, say, three columns (this would almost always mean that you are working on a “header” cell), you would have already written `\multispan3`.

I can already see that I'm writing myself into a corner here, what with the various arguments for cell background colors, cells spanning multiple rows, cells containing vertical mode material, and what have you. So I'm just going to say a sweeping statement about all those things being “bad typography”. `;-)`.

Hold on, there's a lynch mob knocking on my door…

What I mean is that if you find yourself doing any of the above, more often than not, **chances are that you are complicating the information you want to communicate with your table**. And that's basically what the word “bad typography” means.

So one strong argument still remains: to visually see the structure of the table, be it in raw text (like in the `orgmode` answer, `vim`s equivalent, or in the various Markdown extensions), or in graphical programs (like in spreadsheet programs).

This could again be just a `s/<colsepchar>/\&/g` and `s/<rowsepchar>/\\cr/`, in whatever chunk you get out from the program of your choice. Like, not a big deal at all. Or alternatively on the TeX side of things, some `\catcode` madness could take place. **Given that the table is simple enough, i.e., not complicating the information you want to communicate with it**.

So, given this context and background, I hope my initial joke's not lost on anyone and this answer could happily live in this question! `;-)`

Comment: This does not quite answer the question. Perhaps it would better suit here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12672/which-tabular-packages-do-which-tasks-and-which-packages-conflict

Comment: All fair. The `sed` script and the `vim` mode you mentioned each deserve an own answer. -- You forget that usually you not only want to see the structure of the table, but also to edit it so that **it best communicates the information you want to present**. Hacking a table is fast, even in LaTeX. Modifying it later is a PITA, and this is the very reason for the question.

Answer (score 8):

### Orgtbl-minor-mode (for emacs)

This is along the lines of [this answer about `org-mode`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49513/9517). `org-mode` also provides a minor mode designed specifically to typeset tables with the `org` syntax, but in a non-`org` buffer.

`Latex` is supported out of the box, and there is a tutorial in [the org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/A-LaTeX-example.html).

**Pros**

- all those in the answer about `org-mode`
- no need to use a separate buffer or mode, all is done in the latex buffer
- the exporter can be set up on a per-table basis, simply passing parameters to the `#+ORGTBL` line

**Cons**

- the emacs learning curve, mentioned in the answer about `org-mode`
- you do not get a full-featured `org` buffer, which means some keybindings will not be available if they clash with the `latex` keymap
- you will also miss on some features of the `org` swiss-army-knife, for example, the ability to generate the table values *from* the `org` buffer, with embedded scripts or code snippets.

For the impatient, though already familiar with `org-mode` people:

- turn the minor mode on: `M-x` `orgtbl-mode` `RET`
- create the template:  `M-x` `orgtbl-insert-radio-table` `RET`

[image]

- fill the table

[image]

- export the table: `C-c C-c`

[image]

The two approaches (`org` and `orgtbl`) are different in purpose, in my view. `org-mode` is fine if you don't need to change your data a lot, or if you can afford to do the manual tweaking after every export.

On the other hand, with `orgtbl`, you can change your table, reexport and recompile in a few keystrokes. It also provides some ways to "automate" the tweaking, but they are still more or less dirty hacks: it goes from overwriting parameters in the export function (which is fine, I guess) to injecting latex code in the cells (for example additional line space can be added in the first cell of the next line).

Comment: There is a problem with math. Details are here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186605/with-orgtbl-how-to-ensure-that-braces-and-dollars-are-not-escaped . One singleline solution is in the comment there.

Answer (score 7):

## Inlage

Insert → Insert Table (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>T</kbd> ) will open the following window (where I have filled some data):

[image]

Upon pressing insert, the code is inserted in the editor where the cursor is:

[image]

---

## Importing from Excel

Let us say we have an excel table with formulae:

[image]

Select the values and copy:

[image]

Now paste in the inlage editor (directly). The Insert Table window will appear as shown below:

[image]

Press the Insert button after editing if any. Values will be converted in to LaTeX code as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## Cals

[The CALS table model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CALS_Table_Model) is the historic precursor of the HTML table model. It is easier in use and offers more capabilities than `tabularx`.

By employing the `cals` package, tables in LaTeX can be directly defined in [CALS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CALS_%28DOD%29) syntax.

Here is the documentation:

- http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cals (demo & doc)
- http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-2/tb101parashchenko.pdf (user's manual)

and an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

%text symbols
\usepackage{textcomp}

%table
\usepackage{cals}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{12mm}{18mm}{18mm}{12mm}{15mm}}
\def\cals@cs@width{0pt} %no vertical lines
\setlength{\cals@paddingT}{3pt}
\setlength{\cals@paddingB}{2pt}
\alignC
\thead{\brow \cell{sectie} \cell{$D_{out}$\,(m)} \cell{$D_{in}$\,(m)} \cell{$\ell$\,(m)} \cell{$A$\,(m\texttwosuperior)} \erow}
\brow \cell{1} \cell{0,060} \cell{0,056} \cell{1,80} \cell{0,66} \erow
\brow \cell{2} \cell{0,055} \cell{0,051} \cell{1,80} \cell{0,60} \erow
\brow \cell{3} \cell{0,050} \cell{0,046} \cell{1,80} \cell{0,54} \erow
\brow \cell{4} \cell{0,045} \cell{0,041} \cell{1,80} \cell{0,49} \erow
\brow \cell{5} \cell{0,040} \cell{0,036} \cell{1,80} \cell{0,43} \erow
\brow \cell{6} \cell{0,035} \cell{0,031} \cell{1,80} \cell{0,37} \erow
\tfoot{\brow \alignR \nullcell{ltb} \nullcell{tb} \nullcell{tb} \nullcell{tbr} \spancontent{Totaal:} \alignC \cell{3,09} \erow}
\end{calstable}
\makeatother
De totale oppervlakte bedraagt 3,09\,m\texttwosuperior.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: From the manual of the `cals` package: "The TeX code for tables is supposed to be generated automatically." Which tools generate TeX code in this particular syntax?

Comment: erm... isn't this about XML-style CALS?

Comment: @krlmlr The so far only tool which generates TeX in this syntax by interpreting XML CALS tables is unfortunately not released to public. Perfectionism is sometimes bad.

Comment: @olpa: Thanks for the cals package, it looks like a sweet option. Why don't you also push your tool to GitHub, in whatever state it is? Then we'd only have to find a way to convert spreadsheet or R tables to XML CALS...

Comment: @krlmlr A part of the tool [is here](https://github.com/olpa/tex/tree/master/cals/python). `cals.py` splits multirow and multicolumn cells to simple cells with annotations, which make xslt code very easy. I'll try to commit the xslt part in a few days.

Answer (score 5):

### [LaTeX-tables](https://www.latex-tables.com/)

With this new interface it is possible to create quickly a table: there are many options as from this image:

[image]

It is very easy and there are the options: *Import from LaTeX* and *Load from Excel*.

Answer (score 4):

## AppleScript Excel2Latex

I wrote this AppleScript to help me convert my selection in Microsoft Excel 2011 Mac to LateX code. I have it configured to export into a `longtabu`table, but it can easily be configured to accommodate other needs.

Limitations: Script ignores bold or italicized words

```
(*
Must have \usepackage{longtable} and \usepackage{tabu} in preamble.
Export is saved to Desktop as "Excel Table Export.tex"
written in 2013 by Jonathan Komar
*)

set target_file to (((path to desktop folder) as text) & "Excel Table Export.tex")
my write_to_file("", target_file, false)

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set mySel to selection
    tell selection to set {rowCount, columnCount} to {count rows, count columns}

    set columnsList to {}
    repeat columnCount times
        set end of columnsList to "X[m] "
    end repeat

    set myList to {}

    set writeThis to "\\begin{longtabu}{ " & (columnsList as string) & "}\n\\tabucline[.4mm,black]1\n"
    my write_to_file(writeThis, target_file, true)
    repeat with rowStep from 1 to (rowCount)
        repeat with columnStep from 1 to (columnCount)
            set currentValue to value of cell columnStep of row rowStep of mySel
            if columnStep is equal to columnCount and rowStep is 1 then
                set writeThis to currentValue & "\\\\\n\\tabucline[.05mm,black]1\n"
                my write_to_file(writeThis, target_file, true)
            else
                if columnStep is not equal to columnCount then
                    set writeThis to currentValue & " & "
                    my write_to_file(writeThis, target_file, true)
                else
                    set writeThis to currentValue & "\\\\\n"
                    my write_to_file(writeThis, target_file, true)
                end if
            end if
            if rowStep is equal to rowCount and columnStep is columnCount then
                set writeThis to "\\tabucline[.4mm,black]1\n\\end{longtabu}"
                my write_to_file(writeThis, target_file, true)
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell

return myList as string



on write_to_file(this_data, target_file, append_data) -- (string, file path as string, boolean)
    try
        set the target_file to the target_file as text
        set the open_target_file to ¬
            open for access file target_file with write permission
        if append_data is false then ¬
            set eof of the open_target_file to 0
        write this_data to the open_target_file starting at eof as «class utf8»
        close access the open_target_file
        return true
    on error
        try
            close access file target_file
        end try
        return false
    end try
end write_to_file
```

## AppleScript Numbers2LateX

This is a template script for iWork Numbers. It has issues: You need to set the rows and columns in the script manually or by adjusting the table to fit your content. I am not sure how to get a row and column count of a selection in Numbers. Warning: This script does not seem to work as well as the excel script. It must be improved!

```
(*
Must have \usepackage{longtable} in preamble.
Export is saved to Desktop as "Numbers Table Export.tex"
written in 2013 by Jonathan Komar
*)

set target_file to (((path to desktop folder) as text) & "Numbers Table Export.tex")
my write_to_file("", target_file, false)

tell application "Numbers"
    set rowCount to (get row count of table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1)
    set columnCount to (get row count of table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1)

    tell front document
        tell table 1 of sheet 1
            set columnsList to {}
            repeat columnCount times
                set end of columnsList to "X[m] "
            end repeat

            set myList to {}
            set writeThis to "\\begin{longtabu}{ " & (columnsList as string) & "}\n\\tabucline[.4mm,black]1\n"
            my write_to_file(writeThis, target_file, true)
            repeat with rowStep from 1 to rowCount
                repeat with columnStep from 1 to (columnCount - 1)
                    set currentValue to value of cell rowStep of column columnStep
                    if columnStep is equal to columnCount and rowStep is 1 then
                        set writeThis to currentValue & "\\\\\n\\tabucline[.05mm,black]1\n"
                        my write_to_file(writeThis, target_file, true)
                    else
                        if columnStep is not equal to columnCount then
                            set writeThis to currentValue & " & "
                            my write_to_file(writeThis, target_file, true)
                        else
                            set writeThis to currentValue & "\\\\\n"
                            my write_to_file(writeThis, target_file, true)
                        end if
                    end if
                    if rowStep is equal to rowCount and columnStep is columnCount then
                        set writeThis to "\\tabucline[.4mm,black]1\n\\end{longtabu}"
                        my write_to_file(writeThis, target_file, true)
                    end if
                end repeat
            end repeat
            get value of cell 1 of column 2

        end tell
    end tell
end tell



on write_to_file(this_data, target_file, append_data) -- (string, file path as string, boolean)
    try
        set the target_file to the target_file as text
        set the open_target_file to ¬
            open for access file target_file with write permission
        if append_data is false then ¬
            set eof of the open_target_file to 0
        write this_data to the open_target_file starting at eof as «class utf8»
        close access the open_target_file
        return true
    on error
        try
            close access file target_file
        end try
        return false
    end try
end write_to_file
```

Answer (score 4):

### Creating LaTeX Table from Excel Worksheet

Save the contents of the excel sheet as `csv` file and use it in the `LaTeX` code.
Here is an example:

[image]
The above is an excel sheet. Saving it in `csv` format as `contents.csv`.

```
natural,two,three
1,2,3
2,4,6
3,6,9
4,8,12
5,10,15
6,12,18
7,14,21
8,16,24
9,18,27
10,20,30
```

Now, the following code illustrates an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    columns/natural/.style={column name=natural, column type={|l}},
    columns/two/.style={column name=two, column type={|l}},
    columns/three/.style={column name=three, column type={|c|}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    ]{contents.csv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The top answer covers pgfplotstable quite good, i think?

Comment: @Johannes_B can you be a bit more clear?

Answer (score 3):

As you know you can also get a snapshot of your table  and add the image file to your file.
OK, OK! you are right this is not a good solution for all cases but use it as last resort. In such situation http://getgreenshot.org/ is your assistant.

Comment: If screenshots are your thing (which they shouldn't be, ew `;)`) the default snipping tool in windows is easier to use. (At the time of writing, the linked seems to be a windows-only tool.)

Comment: You'd have to be desperate.  If you have a vector image file (pdf) there are better ways than that, it's really only suitable when you only have an image of the table, then I would say retype it.

Answer (score 3):

### [excel2latex.js](http://ericwood.org/excel2latex/)

An online tool that converts `.xlsx` files (but no `.xls` files) to LaTeX tables. JavaScript based. The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/eric-wood/excel2latex). Haven't tested it yet, just found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102033/8057).

Answer (score 3):

**CSV + `R` editor (RStudio or TexStudio) + sweave + knitr**

Even better if you write your `Latex` document directly as a `Rnw` document and sweave it with TexStudio or RStudio.

The steps would be :

1. Create CSV containing data
2. Import the csv as a data frame in an R chunck
3. Create table with kable or xtable (highly customizable)
4. Knit the Rnw document with the option to keep the `tex` file (so you can eventually fine tune the result)
5. Enjoy a dynamic document with the power of `Latex` and `R`

Answer (score 2):

I use a simple VBA for Excel function called ConcateMe to generate the rows of a table in a text cell in your excel file.

You will have to set up the main environment of the table yourself, but the script below is very handy in that it creates the table rows in a cell.

Use the function for each table row separately. Then copy the contents of the cell and paste into LaTex. Presto.

Nothing fancy, but very fast, and because it is a function, it is always up to date.

```
Function ConcatMe(Rng As Range) As String
Dim cl As Range
   ConcatMe = ""
   countr = 0
   For Each cl In Rng
   countr = countr + 1
      pasty = cl.Text
      If pasty = vbNullString Then pasty = " "
      If countr = 1 Then ConcatMe = ConcatMe & pasty Else ConcatMe = ConcatMe & " & " & Trim(pasty)
   Next cl
   ConcatMe = ConcatMe & " \\"
End Function
```

Comment: So if the range spans multiple lines, how do you manage that? Can you show a screenshot of your use-case?

Comment: See for example, this link (https://db.tt/TqD89ylF)

Answer (score 1):

**Python Macro LibreCalc2Latex**

I've found this macro [calc2booktab](https://github.com/schober-ch/calc2booktab) and tested it on LibreCalc 6.3. It works really nice. It has a couple of options. So far I've tried it out also on Overleaf and it also works as intendend.