# Boxing some cells in tabular environment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I would like to make a table in LaTeX, where I box some of the cells within my table.
And I would like to be able to nest boxes so that I can have a box in a box.
Here I have an example of what I mean:

[image]

I have searched for this problem for some time, and I doesn't seem like I am capable of finding a solution to this problem, and I don't know how to attack the problem, since I'm pretty new to LaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are perhaps many ways of doing this, depending on how you may want to extend this. I've used an `array` since the arrangement in your question looks pretty `tabular`-like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{l|cclc|l}
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.} & \quad & & \forall x\forall y : P(x,y) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\quad} & \mbox{premise} \\ \cline{2-5}
  2. & & u_0 & \forall y : P(u_0,y) && \forall e \\ \cline{3-4}
  3. & & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{v_0} & P(u_0,v_0) & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \forall e \\ \cline{3-4}
  4. & & & \forall v : P(u_0,v) && \forall i \\ \cline{2-5}
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{5.} & & & \forall u\forall v : P(u,v) &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \forall i
\end{array}\]
\end{document}​
```

Columns 2 and 5 are just place-holders, specified as `c`entred; they only contain the entry `\quad` for spacing purposes.

---

`tabular` creation in LaTeX is tedious for large constructions. There are a couple of GUIs that could be of help:

1. [`excel2latex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex)

   [image]

   The default is to include `\bigstrut`s, which requires the [`bigstrut` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bigstrut). Also, you may want to modify the default `tabular` output to `array`, and wrap it inside a display math environment `\[`...`\]`.
2. [Gnumeric](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/) which allows [exporting spreadsheet-like constructions to LaTeX](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/doc/file-format-latex.shtml).
3. ...see more at [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49414/5764).

Comment: Thanks.. But this is going to explode, if you want more nesting, isn't it? If I want eg. 10 nested boxes, I will need about 20 placeholders, won't I? Is there a "better" way, so that I don't need empty cells?

Comment: @user1712876: I've added some `tabular` creation aids.

Comment: @Werner There is [calc2latex](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/Calc2LaTeX) for OpenOffice/LibreOffice.

Comment: @Werner Isn't `\text{}` more appropriate than `\mbox{}`?

Comment: @azetina: In a mathematical context where you may switch between different styles (`\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, ...), yes. However, in this instance, not so much.

Comment: @Werner Ohhhhhhhh ok. I stick to one so yeah. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks guys.. I'll look into that calc2latex in the future.. I looks like it can realy help with large tables..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do that with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. This environment is similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of `array`) but adds PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns. It's possible to use those nodes to draw whatever you want after the construction of the array with Tikz in the `\CodeAfter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{NiceArray}{lcclcl}
  1. & \quad & & \forall x\forall y : P(x,y) & \quad & \mbox{premise} \\ 
  2. & & u_0 & \forall y : P(u_0,y) && \forall e \\ 
  3. & & v_0 & P(u_0,v_0) & & \forall e \\ 
  4. & & & \forall v : P(u_0,v) && \forall i \\ 
  5. & & & \forall u\forall v : P(u,v) &  & \forall i
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (2-|2) rectangle (5-|6) (3-|3) rectangle (4-|5) ;
\end{NiceArray}\]

\end{document}​
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

In fact, in your case, it's also possible to use the built-in command `\Block` with the key `draw` in the cells which correspond to the upper-left corners. You don't have to use Tikz explicitely.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{NiceArray}{lcclcl}
  1. & \quad & & \forall x\forall y : P(x,y) & \quad & \mbox{premise} \\ 
  2. & \Block[draw]{3-4}{} & u_0 & \forall y : P(u_0,y) && \forall e \\ 
  3. & & \Block[draw]{1-2}{} v_0 & P(u_0,v_0) & & \forall e \\ 
  4. & & & \forall v : P(u_0,v) && \forall i \\ 
  5. & & & \forall u\forall v : P(u,v) &  & \forall i
\end{NiceArray}\]

\end{document}​
```

The output is the same.