# Boxes within boxes and line numbering

Tags: boxes

How can I create framed boxes with two columns, where there is a line numbering on every row where there is something written? (if hard or possible then a number for every line in general)

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: You should look at http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/.

Comment: Related: [Boxing some cells in `tabular` environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75023/5764)

Comment: Normally, you don't box the premises or the final conclusion but only sub-proofs. If this is based on a system from a book, which book?

Comment: @cfr Yes sorry, I've updated my question, but the sort of idea is that I wanted boxes inside boxes for some proofs (premises should be excluded yes). Also the latex-for-logicians is very nice but it's now how my lecturers format their proofs, and since this is for an assignment that they would mark I would prefer actual boxes

Comment: @Werner That looks very promising I will have an attempt at it

Comment: If you read through the different options, you will find that one of the styles on that page ***is*** the way your lecturers do it, assuming they format them in the style of the image you've posted! That site is a repository for information about typesetting logic for both teaching and research in all manner of styles. While obviously some things might be too esoteric for coverage, that is unlikely for any standard textbook system studied in introductory logic - especially if you are studying a natural deduction system ;).

Comment: You never said which book...

Comment: @cfr Well I'm actually not aware from which book is that format because there are a couple recommended logic books, and I'm not sure which one the lecturer is using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a ***lot*** easier to produce the corrected image! Please do bear this in mind when posting future questions. (I came up with a solution for the original even though it made no sense to me to do it that way!)

Boxes are no problem. The page I directed you to includes information about typesetting proofs with boxed sub-proofs in at least three different styles. You should try this one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{logicproof}

\begin{document}

  \begin{logicproof}{1}
    P \lor Q & premise\\
    Z & premise\\
    \begin{subproof}
      P & [assume]\\
        [\dots] &\\
          &
    \end{subproof}
    \begin{subproof}
        Q & [assume]\\
        [\dots] &\\
          &
    \end{subproof}
    (P \lor Q) \land Z & el 3--4 5--6
  \end{logicproof}

\end{document}
```

[image: boxed proofs]

Incidentally, you ought not need sub-proofs at all for this particular question, but you know that, right?

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, yes I just typed random letters to give you the idea :) I am a bit curious however for your solution to the original and why was it that much harder

Comment: @Panayiotis The package doesn't allow the final conclusion to be in a sub-proof. (It automatically adds an additional numbered line.) You can, however, box the entire proof ***after*** constructing it. I did this using the `tikzmark` library to mark points in the proof and the `fit` library to construct a TiKZ node around the proof, overlaying the picture on top of the proof itself. But this is a bit fiddly ;).

Comment: Ah, thank you! it's seems a really fiddly way to go, and the logic package makes everything much easier

Comment: @Panayiotis I still used the package. I just used all that stuff to draw the outer box!