# Visual editor for multi-column table layout

Tags: tables, tabularx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49414/comprehensive-list-of-tools-that-simplify-the-generation-of-latex-tables)

Is there a visual tool which can generate tex code for more complex tables as shown? The idea is to drawn them and generate the latex code as shown:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Excel supports merged cells, and you can convert a table to LaTeX using the
[Excel2LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex) add-in (this works for multirow and multicolumn cells). However, you would have to manually change the generated code if you want to use the `tabularx` environment.

See also: [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49414/8057).