# What is a short command for bold face and emph at the same time in a table cell?

Tags: tables, bold, emphasis

I need a short command to replace **\textbf{\emph{...}}**. Especially, in entering tables in the text editor, this would help me to keep the structure of table uniform and easy to edit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would be more normal to use `\textit` rather than `\emph` in a table cell, as it isn't normally free text that requires emphasis,

You can make commands as short as you like, also the table cell automatically scopes the font change so you can use the declaration form rather than the form that takes an argument.

After

```
\newcommand\z{\bfseries\itshape}
```

You can use

```
.... &\z this is bold italic & this is not bold italic & ...\\
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not define it yourself:

```
\newcommand{\bfem}[1]{\textbf{\emph{#1}}}
```

After that you can use it just like the predefined commands `\textbf` and `\emph`.

See also the [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49414/8057) to make life even simpler.

Comment: Thanks. Usually, I generate the Latex tables directly from the simulator. However, there are a few tables that I have to type in.