# How to keep tables readable in code

Tags: tables, best-practices, code

What is the best practice for creating and updating tables in Latex? I am using Texmaker but I find it hard to update a table like adding entries or adding a column. I have to count entries which is kind of tedious. 
Is it better to first create a table in an excel type program and import it when finished? 
Example:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
Study & Year & Method & • & • & • & • & • & o & Result num. & Result \\ 
\hline 
 • & • & autor & autor et al & autor. & autor & autor\cite{autor} &
```

Comment: Texmaker have a tabular wizard function that makes creating table easier, if this is what you are asking.

Comment: Sort of related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49414/comprehensive-list-of-tools-that-simplify-the-generation-of-latex-tables

Comment: @Francis, thanks I know that one. But I think it cannot change existing tables. I am searching in literature and if I find a new result I want to add it to an existing table. So I have to add new rows and columns.

Comment: @Lennart, a good text editor is able to align text on specific characters. I use vim with the Align-plugin and align tables on the &-character and quite happy with that. Others may have even easier solutions.

Answer (score 9):

I write my tables always in a pretty printed form to be able to recognize colums and rows in the LaTeX code.

My best practice is:

- I write one row in one line of my code (and if I need 200 characters)
- I write all `&` below each other so that I can see in the code the columns of my table. I keeo this structure even if I have to use the macros `\multirow` or `\multicolumn`.
- I write the end of a row (`\\`) below each other.
- I keep the table in my TeX document

An example:

```
\begin{tabular}{r@{:}l*{5}c}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}    &       & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Node ID}                                                          \\ 
\cmidrule{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Date | Time} & 25             & 28             & 29             & 31              & 32              \\
\midrule
9/29/2007 00            &00     & \ding{108}     & \ding{108}     & \ding{108}     & \ding{108}      & \ding{108}      \\
9/29/2007 01            &00     & \ding{109}     & \ding{109}     & \ding{109}     & \ding{109}      & \ding{109}      \\
9/29/2007 23            &00     & \ding{108}     & \ding{108}     & \ding{109}     & \ding{108}      & \ding{109}      \\
\midrule
9/29/2007 23            &00     & \textbullet    & \textbullet    & \textbullet    & \textopenbullet & \textopenbullet \\
\midrule
9/29/2007 23            &00     & $\blacksquare$ & $\blacksquare$ & $\blacksquare$ & $\square$       & $\square$       \\
Columns: 1              & 2     & 3              & 4              & 5              & 6               & 7               \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Writing your table in this way allows you to change rows or columns better. 
With a little practice you will see it is usable ...

I write all my tables in this way.

Answer (score 7):

This is my code style for tables with many columns.

- Put the table in a separate file as follows. It can be either not-compilable file (without using `standalone` class) or compilable file (using `standalone` class). Advantages: (1) you can reuse your table for many projects, (2) your main input file will be more compact, easy to maintain, (3) when using `standalone` class, you can convert each table as a PDF that can be imported from within the main input file as an image with `\includegraphics` (don't forget use `\usepackage{graphicx}`), etc.

```
% not-compilable-table.tex
\begin{tabular}{|*{11}{c|}}
\hline 
    Study
& Year
& Method
& % 4
& % 5
& % 6
& % 7
& % 8
& % 9
& Result num. 
& Result
\\\hline %------- Row End ---------
  \LaTeX %Study
& 2012 %Year
& Brute Force %Method
& % 4
& % 5
& % 6
& % 7
& % 8
& % 9
& 99 
& Good
\\\hline %------- Row End ---------
\end{tabular}
```

or

```
% compilable-table.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{11}{c|}}
\hline 
    Study
& Year
& Method
& % 4
& % 5
& % 6
& % 7
& % 8
& % 9
& Result num. 
& Result
\\\hline %------- Row End ---------
  \LaTeX %Study
& 2012 %Year
& Brute Force %Method
& % 4
& % 5
& % 6
& % 7
& % 8
& % 9
& 99 
& Good
\\\hline %------- Row End ---------
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

- Arrange each entry prefixed with `&` (except for the first entry in each row, it is not prefixed with `&`) in a single line to ease data entry. At least, you no longer need horizontal scrolling. Adding column number or column name as a comment (`%2`, `%3`, `%Study`, `%Year`, etc, for example) for each entry will also ease inserting, editing data.
- Import the the table file using `\input` withing the main input file as follows.

```
% main-input-file.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
\input{<table-filename>}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you have any suggestion, please drop a comment.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to store large tables as CSV files and typescript them using pgfplotstable. There is a nice introduction to this package, and the simpler csvsimple, here: http://texblog.org/2012/05/30/generate-latex-tables-from-csv-files-excel/

Comment: While this is good practice for some types of tables, it's not really what the asker needed.  One should note that, when storing a table externally as CSV data, it's next to impossible to customize the format of the table (and forget merged cells).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer aligning cells horizontally. I use a function in ViM (Vi Improved) called **tabular**. It can be found on github.

https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular

In my `.vimrc` I just add the following code to assign it to the F8 key and make it use the ampersand as a delimiter:

```
function! Tabularize( delim )
endfunction
map <F8> :call Tabularize( '/&' )
```

There is a nice video demonstration too:

http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/

---

You can also use Github's Atom from [www.atom.io](http://www.atom.io) and install the `atom-alignment` package.

I set mine up like this:

[image]

Select the lines of the table and press `ctrl alt a` to execute on Windows or `ctrl cmd a` on MacOS.