# WYSIWYG LaTeX table editor

Tags: tables, tools, wysiwyg

Are there any WYSIWYG LaTeX table editors that you recommend for creating LaTeX tables?

Comment: No WYSIWYG, but very useful: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49414/comprehensive-list-of-tools-that-simplify-the-generation-of-latex-tables

Comment: Please put a little more effort into finding out if your questions have already been asked here, if they work along the guidelines on the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page, and, in many cases, if you’ve put together a proper [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). The situation right now must be unsatisfactory to you as well as to users answering questions here – with more than half of your questions here having been closed.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really worked with it intensively, but [`org-mode`](http://orgmode.org/) has a table editor and it also handles exporting to LaTeX. So you can edit your table inside `emacs` and then export it.