# I am having trouble importing a big excel table into latex

Tags: tables, excel

I have an excel file including the following table. How should I create something similar to it? Is it better to use the table code in latex or make a figure from it and import it to latex (I did this but the quality of picture was so bad).

If I have to create a table, how should I automatically import those values to latex, because the values are too much to be written without any automatic routine.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Some tools for converting tables from Excel to LaTeX are listed in [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49414/comprehensive-list-of-tools-that-simplify-the-generation-of-latex-tables).

Comment: @tohecz thank you. I did very easily imported my table by use of [excel2latex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/) add on introduced in the answer you gave me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should help you.
Save the contents of your excel sheet as `csv` file and use it in the `LaTeX` code.
Here is an example:

[image]
The above is an excel sheet. Saving it in `csv` format as `contents.csv`.

```
natural,two,three
1,2,3
2,4,6
3,6,9
4,8,12
5,10,15
6,12,18
7,14,21
8,16,24
9,18,27
10,20,30
```

Now, the following code illustrates an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    columns/natural/.style={column name=natural, column type={|l}},
    columns/two/.style={column name=two, column type={|l}},
    columns/three/.style={column name=three, column type={|c|}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    ]{contents.csv}
\end{document}
```

[image]