# What online tool is suggested for the picture package in LaTeX?

Tags: packages, diagrams

As you know there are online tools for drawing tables for LaTeX.

Is there any online tool which can be used to generate the pictures (any geometrical graphics and shapes) easily?

That means we don't need to manipulate the codes in LaTeX to get the desired graphics. Instead, we can generate the graphics in the tool and then copy and paste the corresponding codes into the LaTeX file.

Comment: Related: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597/2417](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597/2417)

Comment: ... and for tables: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49414/2417](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49414/2417)

Comment: Do these tools create the latex codes? That's what I need.

Comment: Some of them do. Follow the links for the details.