# Need help to make a table

Tags: tables

I need to make a table which looks like [image: this].

I have written my code below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

`\usepackage{latexsym}`

```
\usepackage{amsmath, times, amsfonts, mathrsfs, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{\small Comparison results}
\small
\centering
\hline
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c }
\hline
$\beta$ & step & $ \|A^{(2)}_{T,S} - X_k\|_2 $ & $ \|X_k - X_{k-1} \|_2 $  & $ \|A^{(2)}_{T,S} - X_k\|_2 $ & $ \|X_k - X_{k-1} \|_2 $ \\
\hline
&   &      &      &  &\\[1ex]




\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:nonlin}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I am finding it difficult to draw horizontal lines for $t =1$ and $t = 2$`, which should be similar to the attached image file. I need help to draw this table. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`booktabs` makes this easier here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, mathrsfs, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% times is deprecated
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{\small Comparison results}
    \small
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ *{8}{c} }
      \toprule
      $\beta$ & step & $ \|A^{(2)}_{T,S} - X_k\|_2 $ & $ \|X_k - X_{k-1} \|_2 $  & $ \|A^{(2)}_{T,S} - X_k\|_2 $ & $ \|X_k - X_{k-1} \|_2 $ \\\cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
      &   &      &      &  &\\[1ex]
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:nonlin}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: booktabs rules]

Note that `times` is deprecated and ought not be used.

Comment: @srijan You are welcome. But Mico's answer might suit your needs better and is more comprehensive. (The method to get the horizontal lines, which is the focus of your question, is the same, but Mico also uses `array` which might be a better option.) However, that is a matter for your judgement - only you can say which answer you find most helpful ;).

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you do the following:

- Since almost all of the table's material should be typeset in math mode, use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. This will save you from having to type lots and lots of `$` symbols (one pair per cell).
- Load the `booktabs` package and use its macros to obtain well-spaced horizontal lines. Use the `\cmidrule` macro (with optional left-hand and right-hand trimming) for the intermediate lines.
- If you want the caption as well as the remainder of the table to be set in "small", load the `caption` package and issue the command `\captionsetup{font=small}`. You can do this either at the start of the table, if the sizing command should pertain to only that table, or globally in the preamble if all figure and table captions of the document should be set in "small" size.
- Load the `mathtools` package and define a macro named `\norm`. This will save you a lot of typing of `\|` directives.
- As others have already pointed out, the `times` package is deprecated. Load either the `mathptmx` package or (my preference) the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage{latexsym} %% latexsym is really ancient
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsfonts, mathrsfs, amssymb}

\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath, provides extra macros
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % times is deprecated

\usepackage{caption} % to influence size of caption
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \captionsetup{font=small}
    \caption{Results for Example 4.1 using the iteration (3) for $t=1,2$}
    \label{table:nonlin}
    \centering
    $\begin{array}{ @{} ll *{4}{c} @{}}
      \toprule
      \beta & \text{Step} 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{t=1} 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{t=2} \\
      \cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}
      & & {\norm{A^{(2)}_{T,S} - X_k}_2} 
        & {\norm{X_k - X_{k-1}}_2}   
        & {\norm{A^{(2)}_{T,S} - X_k}_2}
        & {\norm{X_k - X_{k-1}}_2} \\
      \midrule
      0.9 & k=31 & 6.1424{e-}008 & 5.0256{e-}008\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{array}$
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also use tools like http://truben.no/table/ or http://www.tablesgenerator.com to make almost all the boring work. :-)

Comment: @Smarzaro - Will tablegenerator.com know to use an `array` instead of a `tabular` environment?

Comment: No. It uses tabular. But it can make easy to merge cells and put the borders the way he wants. It does not do all the work, but it's a good start... Very useful.

Comment: @Smarzaro - As the OP's table has no borders (vertical bars) to begin with, he/she doesn't need help in that regard, right? The OP's main question was about getting the two short horizontal lines; does tablegenerator.com know about `\cmidrule` and, in particular, how to perform left- and right-trimming of such rules?

Comment: Sorry, with "borders" I mean all the lines, including the horizontal ones. Yes, it uses the booktabs and cmidrule. As one of the difficuties pointed by the question, I think it worthed mention this kind of tool.

Comment: @Smarzaro - I would like to suggest you post an independent answer showing how `tablegenerator.com` (or some similar tool) might be useful in meeting the OP's needs.

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much for the answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

As suggested here how you can use the [`tablesgenerator`](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/) to build the initial structure for the table.

1. Create the new table (`file->new`)

[image]

2. Merge the cells on the header

[image]

3. Do some typing of the contents (I put `f1` to `f4`to speed up, and it´s easier do it on LaTeX editor)

[image]

4. Set the alignment.

[image]

5. Set the table to use booktabs style

[image]

6. Activate custom grid edit to add or remove some borders

[image]

7. Click generate to refresh the code.

[image]

8. The result can be seen below. The original result from tablesgenerator is the top image, and the bottom is the result after some adjust. As I said the services like tables generator does not do all the work, but it helps.

[image]

The code

```
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath, times, amsfonts, mathrsfs, amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}cccccc@{}}
        \toprule
        &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{t = 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{t = 2} \\ \cmidrule(l){3-6} 
        \beta & Step & f1 & f2 & f3 & f4 \\ \midrule
        0.9 & k=31 & 6.1424e-008 & 5.0256e-008 & 8.1170e-016 & 1.3257e-015 \\
        & k=32 & 3.3783e-008 & 2.7641e-008 & 7.0439e-016 & 3.1839e-016 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

% Table after some adjustments
% 1 - Split \cmidrule in two
% 2 - Change tabular to array to avoid put $ on the math
% 3 - Replace the f1-4 with the actual math
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Comparison results}
    \label{table:nonlin}
    \begin{array}{@{}cccccc@{}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{t = 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{t = 2} \\ \cmidrule(l){3-4} \cmidrule(l){5-6}
        \beta & Step                  & \|A^{(2)}_{T,S} - X_k\|_2           & \|X_k - X_{k-1} \|_2          & \|A^{(2)}_{T,S} - X_k\|_2           & \|X_k - X_{k-1} \|_2          \\ \midrule
        0.9   & k=31                  & 6.1424e-008  & 5.0256e-008 & 8.1170e-016  & 1.3257e-015 \\
        & k=32                  & 3.3783e-008  & 2.7641e-008 & 7.0439e-016  & 3.1839e-016\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{array}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An other possibility where math mode for the table is used and `mystrut` is defined for the padding of the cell title.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{siunitx,array}
\usepackage{amsmath, times, amsfonts, mathrsfs, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mystrut}{\vrule height 15pt depth 10pt width 0pt }
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{\small Comparison results}
\small
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{$} l <{$} *6{>{$} c <{$}}}\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\mystrut $t=1$} & &\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\mystrut t=2$}\\\cline{3-4}\cline{6-7}
\mystrut \beta & \text{Step} &  \|A^{(2)}_{T,S} - X_k\|_2  &  \|X_k - X_{k-1} \|_2   & &  \|A^{(2)}_{T,S} - X_k\|_2  &  \|X_k - X_{k-1} \|_2  \\ \hline 
0.9 &  k=31 &  6.1424e-008    &  5.0256e-008   &  & 8.1170e-016 &  1.3257e-015\\
 &  k=32 &  3.3783e-008    &  2.7641e-008   &  & 7.0439e-016 & 3.1839e-016 \\
\end{tabular}
\label{table:nonlin}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```