# how to add table from word to texstudio using macro?

Tags: macros, texstudio

i have a table of 3 pages in the word document, and it will be very time consuming to copy and paste the individual entities from word to texstudio, please guide me any short cut to manage all these stuff.

Comment: can't you just save it as (say) html then a couple of minutes in any editor you just need to change `</td><td>` to `&` and  `</tr>` to `\\ ` and you are 90% of the way to having the table in tex syntax.

Comment: I'd suggest [Excel > LaTeX](http://ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex) (see [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49414/5764)) and then use a [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable).

Answer (score 1):

A basic solution within TeXstudio is this macro:

```
%SCRIPT
text = app.clipboard
text = text.replace(/\t/g, " & ")
text = text.replace(/\n/g, " \\\\\n")
cursor.insertText(text)
```

Of course, you could extend it to add the surrounding tabular environment if required.

Answer (score 0):

1. Export it into Excel.
2. Then import it into Lyx.
3. Export the result to LaTeX.

   Then edit the table to get the desired result.