# Export Excel tables to Overleaf

Tags: tables, excel

Good morning everyone,

I have been trying to export Excel tables to my Overleaf file. I have succeeded to some extent using `\includegraphics` command, but the problem with that is that the font size is not editable on Overleaf. The attached is done using the command.

[image]

I have also tried to convert Excel to a `.tex` file using an add-in `excel2latex` but it did not work very well on Overleaf.

Could you please provide more tips or advice?

Comment: Why do you cover the table by black rectangle? If you don't want to show us the information, you can type in each cell A, B, C, or something like that.

Comment: Have you seen [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49414/21344)?

Comment: When I want to retain the exact formatting, I usually save the sheet as pdf and then include as graphics in latex.

Answer (score 9):

One possible solution I can think of from the top of my head is to load the excel table with the python module pandas and than use the export as tex file function in pandas.

```
#As example:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file.xlsx)
df.to_latex(output.tex)
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a solution. Unfortunately, I have not used Python before.

Comment: Thank you! The only fix is that pandas does not interpret xlsx, only xls. But it is a great solution!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried saving the excel file as a CSV and importing it to:

https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

You will have to do the formatting again but you can get it exactly how you want it and fairly quickly

Comment: I've used this before, but this site seems to be broken now: it dumps all the table's data into just the first column.

Comment: works for me real good.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late answer, but I hope that future users would be able to take advantage of this. [Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) now gives the possibility of generating a LaTeX table directly from copy-paste a table from Excel. Just create the table in Excel, copy it, than on Tables Generator click File -> Paste table data. It is also possible to paste with formatting. The only feature you will lose is the border widths.

Comment: This is cool! Just what is needed.. fast, simple, loads of features! Thanks for finding and sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Generate your data as a CSV file. Use the datatool package to load and display the data.

```
\document{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{data}{myfile.csv}
\begin{document}
\DTLdisplaydb{data}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

By now you can also input your data as text in [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/) and ask it to "Please return the LaTeX code of the below table for me".

[Examplary table code]

It will produce a basic table you can then adjust.