# What to use in latex to create graphs, charts, tables?

Tags: tables, graphs, charts

I made my research and I found out that you can do this customly by giving commands in Latex. Since I'm new to this environment, is there any good online tools that could be used, and allow this easily to happen. Or any good tutorial explaning how to create any sort of graph/table/chart?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is this special online tool called search engine which will present you with many examples from this site when searching for the type of chart you want ;)

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou For tabels, you can have a look into https://www.tablesgenerator.com/. You could you create a vast majority of tables and even customise them with this tool.

Comment: [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49414/134144) might also be interesting. However, most of the automatically generated code needs some manual finetuning.