# How to create a table with merged columns and rows, and wrapped text, like in MS Word?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, columns, multirow, multicolumn

[image: table]

The above can easily be created in MS word, but how can I create something like this in latex?  Basically changing the columns for specific cells, merging a bunch of cells together, wrapping text in a cell?

Comment: No offense but the reason it can be replicated in Word is because Word has no consciousness about what you are doing :P

Comment: What do you mean?  I have no other choice than to create it like this.

Comment: I think you answered your own question quite well. Add the multirow package (`\usepackage{multirow})`. Starting with a regular grid of cells, use `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` to define the cells you need. See e.g., http://www.andrewjpage.com/?archives/43-Multirow-and-multicolumn-spanning-with-latex-tables.html.

Comment: Hmm, what about wrapping and resizing individual cells?

Comment: Try creating something similar in Excel, and then use [`excel2latex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/)

Comment: @percusse I would be astounded if Word, or LaTeX to that matter, will ever have any consciousness about anything at all. :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To merge columns, you can use the `\multicolumn` command; to merge rows, you can use `\multirow` (from the [`multirow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) package); to have text wrapping, you can use columns of `p{<length>}` type; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newlength\Colwd
\setlength\Colwd{1.2cm}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{| p{\Colwd} | p{0.5\Colwd} | p{0.5\Colwd} *{7}{|p{\Colwd}} |}
\hline
& & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5\Colwd}|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{p{2\Colwd}|}{\multirow{3}{*}{}} & & & & \\
\cline{1-4}\cline{7-10}
& & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5\Colwd}|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{p{2\Colwd}|}{} & & & & \\
\cline{1-4}\cline{7-10}
& & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5\Colwd}|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{p{2\Colwd}|}{} & & & & \\
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{p{\Colwd}|}{} & & \multicolumn{6}{p{2\Colwd}|}{} \\
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{p{\Colwd}|}{} & & \multicolumn{6}{p{2\Colwd}|}{} \\
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{p{\Colwd}|}{} & & & & & & & \\
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{p{\Colwd}|}{} & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|p{3\Colwd}|}{\multirow{5}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{3}{p{3\Colwd}|}{\multirow{5}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{3}{p{3\Colwd}|}{\multirow{5}{*}{}} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|p{3\Colwd}|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{p{3\Colwd}|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{p{3\Colwd}|}{} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|p{3\Colwd}|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{p{3\Colwd}|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{p{3\Colwd}|}{} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|p{3\Colwd}|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{p{3\Colwd}|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{p{3\Colwd}|}{} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|p{3\Colwd}|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{p{3\Colwd}|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{p{3\Colwd}|}{} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since there was no definitive information about the real content for the cells, I set every one of them to be of `p{...}` type (paragraph-type); it's well known this kind of column is not very suitable for long texts. Narrow columns would be better set of type `l`, `r`, or `c`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how long does it take you to whip up an example like this?

Comment: @Ricardo I wouldn't know exactly how long, but I'd say no more than 15 minutes?

Comment: Thanks. That seemed like it would take me about 20 minutes and more pain than warranted. So many lines!

Comment: @Ricardo Actually with a serious editor (nvi user here) and help of some scripting language (I use mostly combination of sed, AWK, and ksh) such table can be cooked in surprisingly little time.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac, could I entice you into working the example above as an answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46487/3731)? Not the final result, but the workflow. I use a combination of `org-mode`in Emacs, "Save as CSV" in Excel and `pgfplotstable`, but when it comes to multirows and multicolumns I  get sad, sigh in resignation and just go at it by hand after creating an initial template.