# Working with clist indices in LaTeX3

Tags: latex3, expl3

Friends, I'm trying to port [an old code of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34593/3094) to a LaTeX3 implementation. Thanks to egreg, Joseph and David, I made a good progress! But then, I got stuck.

From the link above, I'm porting my songbook project. As you know, I have several indices for my songs, and I used to hardcode all of them beforehand. The code is not extensible without the need of adding more and more conditionals.

My idea: have a list (a comma separated list, or in L3 jargon, a `clist`) holding the index name and another list holding the abbreviation name. If I want to add, say, the word `Hello world` to an index with `F` as an abbreviation, I search the abbreviations list for the position of my item, then check its name counterpart.

<sup>From now on, the word **index** will be used to refer to an integer pointer that identifies an element of an array, and not the list of information we have in typography.</sup>

As usual, egreg saved the day and helped me with a L3 code to look for an item in a `clist` and return its index `i`. The code has the following approach:

- `i > 0` : the first occurrence of the item in the `clist`. It's important to note that `clist`'s indices start with `1` .
- `i = 0` : the item is not found in the list.

I'm struggling with using the value from this lookup code in order to get the item from the other list, with `\clist_item:Nn`. Let's see some code:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: on }
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l_vozes_extensions_clist
\clist_new:N \l_vozes_abbreviations_clist
\int_new:N \l_vozes_index_step_int
\bool_new:N \l_vozes_index_found_bool

\cs_new:Npn \vozes_getitemindex:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_vozes_index_step_int
  \bool_set_false:N \l_vozes_index_found_bool
  \clist_map_inline:Nn #1
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_vozes_index_step_int
    \tl_if_eq:nnT { #2 } { ##1 }
    { \clist_map_break:n {  \bool_set_true:N \l_vozes_index_found_bool } }
   }
   \bool_if:NTF{ \l_vozes_index_found_bool }{ \int_to_arabic:n { \l_vozes_index_step_int } }{ 0 }
}

\cs_new:Npn \vozes_newthematicindex:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
{
   \clist_put_right:Nn  \l_vozes_extensions_clist { #1 }
   \clist_put_right:Nn \l_vozes_abbreviations_clist { #3 }
   \makeindex[name=#1,title=#2,columns=#4]
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newthematicindex}{ m m m m }{
   \vozes_newthematicindex:nnnn { #1 }{ #2 }{ #3 }{ #4 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\thematicindex}{ m m }{
   %\clist_item:Nn \l_vozes_extensions_clist {
   % \vozes_getitemindex:Nn \l_vozes_abbreviations_clist { #1 }
   %}
   \index[ \clist_item:Nn \l_vozes_extensions_clist { 1 } ]{ #2 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printthematicindex}{ m }{
   %\clist_item:Nn \l_vozes_extensions_clist {
   % \vozes_getitemindex:Nn \l_vozes_abbreviations_clist { #1 }
   %}
   \printindex[ \clist_item:Nn \l_vozes_extensions_clist { 1 } ]
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newthematicindex{ifoo}{The list of Foo}{F}{2}
\newthematicindex{ibar}{Bar is cool}{B}{2}
\newthematicindex{ifb}{Foo and Bar}{FB}{2}

\begin{document}

Hello.

\thematicindex{F}{Hello Foo}
\thematicindex{B}{Hello Bar}
\thematicindex{FB}{Hello Foobar}

\printthematicindex{F}
\printthematicindex{B}
\printthematicindex{FB}

\end{document}
```

Of course, this code doesn't work. `:)` The offending part is in the commented parts:

```
%\clist_item:Nn \l_vozes_extensions_clist {
% \vozes_getitemindex:Nn \l_vozes_abbreviations_clist { #1 }
%}
```

I'm lost with integer values. `:(` And speaking of which, I wonder how can I save the return of a command to a variable, should I use `\def`?

One last question: Is it good practice to mix L2 and L3? Should I `\ExplSyntaxOff` every time I have a L2 code, or there isn't any side effect?

Any enlightenment is appreciated. `:)`

Comment: You still thinking Java:) There is an easier solution with ONLY one list and can even be sorted see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15338/963 Use the power of TeX!

Comment: @Yiannis: forgive me, my friend, for I have sinned! `:)` I was *not* thinking on a `HashMap`. `:P`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\clist_item:Nn` expects a number designation in its second argument, which `\vozes_getitemindex:Nn` doesn't provide, being it a set of instruction for providing an integer.

Here's a way out: you compute the integer and feed it to `\clist_item:Nn`. However, there's the glitch that `\clist_item:Nn` is not expandable; so sequences seem to be a better choice.

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: on }
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_vozes_extensions_seq
\seq_new:N \g_vozes_abbreviations_seq
\int_new:N \l_vozes_index_step_int
\bool_new:N \l_vozes_index_found_bool

\cs_new_protected:Npn \vozes_getitemindex:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_vozes_index_step_int
  \bool_set_false:N \l_vozes_index_found_bool
  \seq_map_inline:Nn #1
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_vozes_index_step_int
    \tl_if_eq:nnT { #2 } { ##1 }
    { \seq_map_break:n {  \bool_set_true:N \l_vozes_index_found_bool } }
   }
   \bool_if:NF{ \l_vozes_index_found_bool }{ \int_zero:N \l_vozes_index_step_int } 
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \vozes_newthematicindex:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
{
   \seq_gput_right:Nn  \g_vozes_extensions_seq { #1 }
   \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_vozes_abbreviations_seq { #3 }
   \makeindex[name=#1,title=#2,columns=#4]
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\getitemindex}{mm}
 {
  \vozes_getitemindex:Nn #1 { #2 }
  \int_to_arabic:n { \l_vozes_index_step_int }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\newthematicindex}{ m m m m }{
   \vozes_newthematicindex:nnnn { #1 }{ #2 }{ #3 }{ #4 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\thematicindex}{ m m }{
   \vozes_getitemindex:Nn \g_vozes_abbreviations_seq { #1 }
   \index[ \seq_item:Nn \g_vozes_extensions_seq { \l_vozes_index_step_int } ] { #2 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printthematicindex}{ m }{
   \vozes_getitemindex:Nn \g_vozes_abbreviations_seq { #1 }
   \printindex[ \seq_item:Nn \g_vozes_extensions_seq { \l_vozes_index_step_int } ]
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newthematicindex{ifoo}{The list of Foo}{F}{2}
\newthematicindex{ibar}{Bar is cool}{B}{2}
\newthematicindex{ifb}{Foo and Bar}{FB}{2}

\begin{document}

Hello.

\thematicindex{F}{Hello Foo}
\thematicindex{B}{Hello Bar}
\thematicindex{FB}{Hello Foobar}

\printthematicindex{F}
\printthematicindex{B}
\printthematicindex{FB}

\end{document}
```

---

A more efficient implementation with property lists:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_vozes_abbreviations_prop

\cs_new_protected:Npn \vozes_newthematicindex:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
{
 \prop_gput:Nnn \g_vozes_abbreviations_prop { #3 } { #1 }
 \makeindex[name=#1,title=#2,columns=#4]
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newthematicindex}{ m m m m }
 {
  \vozes_newthematicindex:nnnn { #1 }{ #2 }{ #3 }{ #4 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\thematicindex}{ m m }
 {
  \index[ \prop_get:Nn \g_vozes_abbreviations_prop { #1 } ] { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printthematicindex}{ m }
 {
  \printindex[ \prop_get:Nn \g_vozes_abbreviations_prop { #1 } ]
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newthematicindex{ifoo}{The list of Foo}{F}{2}
\newthematicindex{ibar}{Bar is cool}{B}{2}
\newthematicindex{ifb}{Foo and Bar}{FB}{2}

\begin{document}

Hello.

\thematicindex{F}{Hello Foo}
\thematicindex{B}{Hello Bar}
\thematicindex{FB}{Hello Foobar}

\printthematicindex{F}
\printthematicindex{B}
\printthematicindex{FB}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looking at the code, `\clist_item:Nn` is expandable, which is what I'd expect. I'll fix the description to reflect that.

Comment: @JosephWright It is, but there's something puzzling: in that context I get `\seq_item:Nn` working, whereas `\clist_item:Nn` doesn't. I'll try again.

Comment: Could be: these are 'experimental'. A demo would be handy (chat, LaTeX-L, etc.)

Comment: @JosephWright and egreg: What do you think about the `prob` solution? I think this solution reflects best the issue of Paulo.

Comment: Grazie mille, Enrico! `:)`

Comment: @egreg: Did the issue with `\clist_item:Nn` get resolved?  I tried replacing all `seq` by `clist`, and didn't seem to get an error.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch It seems so: if I change every `seq` into `clist` it works. However, I don't think working with a `clist` is better, in this case.

Comment: Note that as of September 2014, `\prop_get:Nn` has been renamed to `\prop_item:Nn`