# How to render some macro content twice?

Tags: macros

I am looking for a three-column layout, in which two columns contain two seperate lists, and the third column a summary of the two lists.

[image: Mockup]

I am under the impression that there is no "native" way to do this in LaTeX (and haven't found a package that appears to do the trick), so in a first step I have prepared a custom environment and a custom item entry macro:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newenvironment{MyList}[1]{
    \subsection{#1}
    \begin{enumerate}
}{
    \end{enumerate}
}
\newcommand{\myEntry}[2]{\item \textbf{#1} -- #2}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{MyList}{ListOne}
\myEntry{OneOne}{Some text regarding item OneOne}
\myEntry{OneTwo}{Some text regarding item OneTwo}
\end{MyList}
\columnbreak
\begin{MyList}{ListTwo}
\myEntry{TwoOne}{Some text regarding item TwoOne}
\myEntry{TwoTwo}{Some text regarding item TwoTwo}
\end{MyList}
\columnbreak
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

But that does not even take me half of the way. I need to render the contents of my macros *twice*: Once in the summary column, once in the individual list column. Not only that, but on the opposite page I would have to do it *the other way around* (i.e., individual column first, summary column second). It's pretty clear that no simple replace-this-with-that transformation can do that, and that some "programming" is required, but I have no idea **if** there is some way to do this in LaTeX.

I could probably write some Perl script to do it via a preprocessing step, but *boy* does *that* feel hack-ish...

If there *is* a way to do this in LaTeX, could someone please give me some pointers what to look for?

Comment: One way to repeat stuff is to save it as a macro. So change your `\myEntry` to include `\def\tempmacro{#1}` so later you can use `\tempmacro` to repeat the stuff. This won't work because you want to repeat it _after_ having gone through the whole list. So you'd need to namespace all your macros properly. If you could do things as a tabular instead, then this method would be easier.

Comment: Otherwise, you can write things to an [auxiliary file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10919/what-is-the-basic-mechanism-for-writing-something-to-an-aux-file) and print that back out as the third column.

Comment: @Seamus: Would you care to turn this into an answer? I think this is the right way to go but would have to play Q&A for a round or two on this (and would like to give it the "checkmark of thanks" if it floats my boat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do this with a new auxiliary file:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newenvironment{MyList}[1]{
  \addtostream{summary}{\noexpand\paragraph{#1}%
  \noexpand\begin{enumerate}
  }
    \subsection{#1}
    \begin{enumerate}
}{
    \end{enumerate}
    \addtostream{summary}{\noexpand\end{enumerate}}
}

\newcommand{\myEntry}[2]{%
  \addtostream{summary}{\noexpand\item \noexpand\textbf{#1}}%
  \item \textbf{#1} -- #2
}


\usepackage{newfile} 
\newoutputstream{summary}
\newcommand\dosummary{%
\closeoutputstream{summary}
\subsection{Summary}
\input{\jobname.sum}
}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.sum}{summary}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{MyList}{ListOne}
\myEntry{OneOne}{Some text regarding item OneOne}
\myEntry{OneTwo}{Some text regarding item OneTwo}
\end{MyList}
\columnbreak
\begin{MyList}{ListTwo}
\myEntry{TwoOne}{Some text regarding item TwoOne}
\myEntry{TwoTwo}{Some text regarding item TwoTwo}
\end{MyList}
\columnbreak
\dosummary
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

The important stuff is the `newfile` package which makes writing to files easier, and the `\addtostream` command which actually adds stuff to the auxiliary file. You have to be careful about macros being expanded when writing things to files, hence the `\noexpand`s in front of the `\item`s.

I've modified the `MyList` environment and the `\myEntry` macro to write the relevant things to the auxiliary file which is then printed out by the `\dosummary` macro. [Find out more about auxiliary files here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10919/what-is-the-basic-mechanism-for-writing-something-to-an-aux-file)

Comment: Might need compiling twice, by the way.

Comment: That's definitely the hint I've been looking for. It will need some additional tinkering (as my example was much dumbed down for simplicity's sake), but I can "see the path" now (even without additional Q&A). Thanks (again)!

Comment: One question though: Will this auxiliary file be included in the same pass it is created? I.e., could this process be repeated (and the `summary` output stream be "recycled"), or would I have to create a new output stream (possibly numbered with help of `\thesubsection` or somesuch) for every instance of `MyList`?

Comment: Nevermind. Tested it, it works just fine.