# Repeat a Theorem

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, theorems

For my thesis I have to repeat my theorems, not just the number but the exact wording of the Theorems.
I found the question [How to repeat the content of a quote (e.g. introduction+conclusion) without violating DRY](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45257), however, this does not answer the problem I have.

The theorems have been defined by

```
\begin{WP}\label{WP:wp2}
some working proposition that i have declared
\end{WP}
```

The option of declare a new command is not the direction I'd like to go.
Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Hi! Please, compose a full [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) since we can't have any slightest idea what `{WP}` is. Having asked 13 questions before, you might know that MWEs are essential. As well, does [How do I repeat a theorem number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422) help? I don't see any significant difference between your question and this one. Please, try to be a bit more specific, show what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: you could try the `standalone` package/documentclass for this