# How can I synchronize page-breaking text across columns?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, cross-referencing, page-breaking, memoir, columns

**tl;dr**: Like footnotes, but on the side (easy part). These *notes* must be on the same page as their reference points, so the "main text" needs to break whenever the notes break.

I'm trying to produce something like this:

[image: sample scan]

I've been using `memoir`. Here's an idea I had. My understanding is that `\footnote` creates a float that tries to place itself at the bottom of the nearest page. Would it be possible to place the "footnote anchor" elsewhere? For example, with some interesting page geometry, something like this:

[image: handwritten idea]

The difficult part is in the question title: ensuring that page breaks respect the column-column alignment.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% geometry stuff here

\begin{document}
Blind Text

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \columnnote{This is the first ``footnote.''}

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. \columnnote{This is the second ``footnote.''}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69517/34721

Comment: I'm also thinking about [`paracol`](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/paracol-man.pdf), but that still leaves the page breaks to be dealt with.

Comment: BTW, do you want these numbers to reset every page?

Comment: @JohnKormylo, no. They are reset by chapter.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, the only thing that's left is the "alignment" and the special breaking.

Comment: At the moment, `memoir`'s `sidebar` has the vertical alignment right, but it doesn't create page breaks that keep the `\sidebar` command's context and the actual sidebar on the same page.

Comment: When you run out of room on the right column, you are already too far in the left column.  But if you number the paragraphs (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10513/automatically-assign-a-number-to-every-paragraph)  and write the last good paragraph number to the aux file, then the next run you can force a page break after that many paragraphs on that page.  Or possibly force a page break before shipping the current paragraph off.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, do you mean hooking the shipout to mark the last good paragraph so that it breaks at the next compilation? I've actually done [something similar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252063/34721), except using source lines.

Comment: I'm not sure what is most important for the document --- the main text or the notes. From your example the notes seem to have the priority.

Comment: @PeterWilson, if you mean that I will tolerate awkward page breaks in the main text to respect the positioning of unbreakable individual notes, then yes.

Comment: My earlier comment seems to have been delivered before I had finished. I had added that a combination of memoir's code for `\sidefootnote` and `\sidebar` might do the trick except for the page breaking requirement which I think is possible but devily hard.

Comment: @PeterWilson: I've been working with `\sidebar`. So far I think the most viable solution will be to require a double compilation in which the first compilation hooks shipouts to determine ideal break points (viz. with a per-sidebar incrementing counter)---definitely not impossible ...

Comment: @PeterWilson et al.: the hard part (which makes this task much harder than [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252063/34721)) is that we have to know not only on which page the note command was called but on which page it ends up typeset.

Comment: This might be useful to you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244853/reflowing-marginpars-typeset-using-pdfsavepos/245215#245215

Comment: Your handwriting is worthy of a font!  Not because it is perfect, but because it is distinctive.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: thank you! It's more or less perfect (mostly *less*) when I try to make it better, but this is my note-taking script ... it gets the words through. I at least pretend to follow some kind of Spencerian Business Script.

Answer (score 5):

This will write notes from top to bottom using the entire right column.  Page breaking is done using the aux file and `\everypar`.

Needless to say, this approach will conflict with any package which uses `\everypar` (within the `paracol` environment).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\darkmark}[1]% #1 = text to write white on black background
{\rlap{\rule[-.2\baselineskip]{\bibindent}{\baselineskip}}%
 \makebox[\bibindent]{\color{white}#1}}

% global registers

\newcounter{abortparagraph}% incremet for every aborted paragraph
\newcounter{columnnote}[chapter]
\globalcounter{columnnote}% synchronized across columns
\newlength{\columnheight}% space used for column notes
\newlength{\columnroom}% available space for column notes
\newif\ifparagraphaborted% ignore extra everypar after abort
\newcommand{\leftcolumnpage}{}% reserve global names
\newcommand{\rightcolumnpage}{}% for page synchronization

% move current paragraph to next page

\newcommand{\newabortparagraph}[1]% #1 = \theparagraph, #2 = \thepage
{\stepcounter{abortparagraph}%
 \global\expandafter\def\csname abortparagraph\arabic{abortparagraph}\endcsname{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\abortparagraph}% \everypar
{\ifparagraphaborted% ignore extra everypar after abort
  \global\paragraphabortedfalse
\else
  \global\edef\leftcolumnpage{\arabic{page}}%
  \stepcounter{paragraph}%
  \bgroup% in case \tempa and \tempb previously used
    \@ifundefined{abortparagraph\arabic{abortparagraph}}{}%
    {\edef\tempa{\csname abortparagraph\arabic{abortparagraph}\endcsname}%
     \edef\tempb{\theparagraph}%
     \ifx\tempa\tempb% compare strings
       \strut\newpage
       \stepcounter{abortparagraph}%
       \global\paragraphabortedtrue
     \fi}%
  \egroup
\fi}

% synchronize pages

\newcommand{\columnnotepage}[2]% #1 = label, #2 = \thepage
{\global\expandafter\def\csname columnnotepage#1\endcsname{#2}}

% redefine paracol environment start

\let\oldparacol=\paracol

\renewcommand{\paracol}[1]{\oldparacol{#1}%
  \everypar{\abortparagraph}%
  \setlength{\columnheight}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\columnroom}{\@colroom}%
  \global\edef\leftcolumnpage{\arabic{page}}%
  \global\edef\rightcolumnpage{\arabic{page}}%
}

% write notes in right column

\newcommand{\columnnote}[1]% #1 = text for second column
{\refstepcounter{columnnote}%
 \darkmark{\thecolumnnote}%
 \@ifundefined{columnnotepage\thechapter.\thecolumnnote}{}%
   {\def\leftcolumnpage{\csname columnnotepage\thechapter.\thecolumnnote\endcsname}}%
 \ifnum\rightcolumnpage<\leftcolumnpage\relax% synchronize pages
   \global\columnroom=\textheight
   \global\columnheight=0pt
   \switchcolumn[1]%
     \loop\ifnum\c@page<\leftcolumnpage \strut\newpage\repeat
     \global\edef\rightcolumnpage{\arabic{page}}%
   \switchcolumn[0]%
 \fi
 \bgroup% compute size of note
   \setbox0=\hbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \columnwidth-\bibindent}#1\end{minipage}}%
   \global\advance\columnheight by \dimexpr \baselineskip + \ht0 + \dp0\relax
 \egroup
 \ifdim\columnheight>\columnroom\relax% time to break page
   \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\newabortparagraph {\theparagraph}}%
   \switchcolumn[1]%
     \strut\newpage%
     \global\edef\rightcolumnpage{\arabic{page}}
   \switchcolumn[0]%
   \global\columnroom=\textheight
   \bgroup% re-compute size of note
     \setbox0=\hbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \columnwidth-\bibindent}#1\end{minipage}}%
     \global\columnheight=\dimexpr \baselineskip + \ht0 + \dp0\relax
   \egroup
 \else
   \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\columnnotepage {\thechapter.\thecolumnnote}{\thepage}}%
 \fi
 \switchcolumn[1]%
   \noindent\hspace{\bibindent}%
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \columnwidth-\bibindent}%
     \mbox{\llap{\darkmark{\thecolumnnote}}%
       \color{lightgray}\rule[-0.2\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{\baselineskip}}%
     \linebreak#1\end{minipage}%
   \linebreak\vspace{\marginparpush}%
 \switchcolumn[0]%
 \global\advance\columnheight by \marginparpush%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{abortparagraph}{1}% reuse counter after aux file read
\chapter{One}
\begin{paracol}{2}
Blind text.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \columnnote{This is the first ``footnote.''}

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. \columnnote{This is the second ``footnote.''}

Too big for the page.  \columnnote{\rule{1pt}{.9\textheight}}

Next paragraph.
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image: test page 1]

It should be noted that `\switchcolumn` doesn't synchronize the pages either.  That had to be done separately.  Note that `\thepage` is not reliable when paragraphs are split over two pages, so are saved to the aux file instead.  Also, one must be careful to NOT synchronize the aborted paragraphs as they NEED to fail the test every time.

Comment: I already have the number layout done with TikZ. The real hard part is still the vertical alignment, since `marginpar` is a long way off from the intended alignment.

MWE coming.

Comment: Have you looked at the `sidenote` package, together with `marginfix` ? Appart from the shape of numbers  (which you can probably redefine), I think it looks like what you are searching for.

Comment: @mvienney `memoir`'s `sidebar` looks hopeful.

Comment: By the way, OP stands for *Original Post*, I think.

Comment: I just replaced the entire answer, so old comments are now out of context.

Comment: @SimonKuang You mention the alignment issues with `\marginpar`.  Forgetting the appearance for the moment, is the ability to adjust vertical alignment as in my answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120224/create-a-framed-environment-for-a-margin-note/120266#120266 at all helpful in adapting `\marginpar` to your needs, do you think?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you refer to using `stackengine`'s functionality to shift the box up and down? By vertical alignment, I meant gluing the first note box of each page to the vertical placement of the text block. My former comment has been obsolete ever since JohnKormylo edited his answer.

Comment: I make some more improvements.  Specifically, if you start paracol in the middle of a page (like after \chapter) the notes are now even with the left column, not the top of the text area.  BTW, use \flushpage instead of \newpage.

Comment: This version does not use everypage at all.

Comment: Thank you! One more thing though: if you replace the contents of `paracol` with `\newcommand{\longtext}{\lipsum[1] Hello. \columnnote{This columnnote is really long: \lipsum[3-4] end}\lipsum[2]} \longtext\par\longtext` (retaining the `\everypar` etc.), the second `\longtext` breaks in the wrong place, and the reference is not on the same page as the note.

Comment: I think it is fixed now.  I was switching columns when I didn't need to.