# \write18 pass % through to shell

Tags: pdftex, shell-escape

This has sort of been touched on in some other postings, but for path reasons I would like to avoid using a shell script and just use ImageMagick's (IM) convert command line executable directly from a `\immediate\write18{...}` in a macro command, but in my IM convert instructions I need to pass the `%` (ASCII 37) as part of a macro.

However I try to conceive of making a `%` - and I have tried numerous ways(!) I always end up getting the Latex code I am using for the % passed through to the command line.

The obvious one, `\%` goes to the shell as `\%` directly and that is the pattern followed by all other options.

What I obviously seem to need is some way to generate the ASCII or unicode for `%` and get that to the shell from LaTeX via `\write18` or other.

Or have some sort of temporary suspension on the LaTeX usage of `%` so that it can be part of a `\write18{}` and not break the command as a comment starter, and so be passed with out needing to be LaTeX escaped first.

Comment: Did you try `\makeatletter \immediate\write18{...\@percentchar ..}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Is there a macro for `#`? I have tried `\@sharpchar` but it does not exists.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `\@percentchar` instead of `%`. You need to say `\makeatletter` before the `\write` and `\makeatother` after it to allow for the `@` in the macro name if the code isn't located in a package or class or already inside a `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` block.

There are also `\@backslashchar` for `\` and also `\@charlb` and `\@charrb` for `{` and `}`. The are listed as "String constants" in my [`macros2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/macros2e) document as mentioned in [Documentation reference for LaTeX internal commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands/10465#10465)

You can also now easily define new string macros for any set of characters with the new version of the [`newverbs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newverbs) package.
E.g. to define a macro for the ampersand use:

```
\usepackage{newverbs}[2011/07/24]
\Verbdef\amp{&}
```

Note that spaces behind macros are removed also in a `\write` statement, so you might need to manually insert one using `\space`.

Comment: Thanks  very much Martin, From comp.text.tex there are some very useful concepts I just found before I got notification of your post.

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/49a5d6379303896e/97a7ee6a5bd6afa8?lnk=gst&q=%5Cwrite18+%25+percent#97a7ee6a5bd6afa8

Things like creating temporary batch files form within LaTeX directly
where necessary 'difficult' characters can be written directly, and
use of \string& and  \@percentchar (with (See
http://arf1.de/wordpress/?p=436).

Comment: @Martin Scharrer Hi I've had login in problems and only just got back, but I can not see a tick symbol on this page at all Martin - nearly sent post then found it not on the right bit on the left-went crazy trying to work out where it was on the upper right! thanks, Paul

Comment: @PaulANormanNZ: Sorry, I meant upper left. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my two cents about writing percent characters to file:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%
\newwrite\tmpfile
%
\begingroup\lccode`\S=`\%\relax\lowercase{\endgroup\def\mypercent{S}}%
\newcommand\mysecondoftwo[2]{#2}%
%
\immediate\openout\tmpfile test.txt
\immediate\write\tmpfile{Approach 1: Some text and a percent sign\mypercent}%
\immediate\write\tmpfile{Approach 2: Some text and a percent sign\expandafter\mysecondoftwo\string\%}%
\immediate\write\tmpfile{Approach 3: Some text and a percent sign\csname @percentchar\endcsname}%    
\immediate\write\tmpfile{Approach 4: Some text and a percent sign\csname @secondoftwo\expandafter\endcsname\string\%}%        
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\tmpfile{Approach 5: Some text and a percent sign\@percentchar}%
\immediate\write\tmpfile{Approach 6: Some text and a percent sign\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string\%}%
\makeatother
\begingroup
\def\textmacro{Approach 7: Some text and a percent sign}%
\lccode`\S=`\%%
\lowercase{\immediate\write\tmpfile{\textmacro S}}%
\endgroup
\immediate\closeout\tmpfile

\begin{document}
\verbatiminput{test.txt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I need to run the command `wolframscript & echo %ERRORLEVEL% > latexalpha2_check.tmp` on Windows PC, what changes should be done to `\immediate\write18{wolframscript & echo %ERRORLEVEL% > latexalpha2_check.tmp}`?

Comment: @Diaa  In LaTeX 2e: `\immediate\write18{wolframscript \string& echo \csname@percentchar\endcsname ERRORLEVEL\csname@percentchar\endcsname\space> latexalpha2\string_check.tmp}`. Perhaps better: `\NewDocumentCommand\ReadVerbatimAndImmediateWriteEighteen{v}{\immediate\write18{\detokenize{#1}}}`...`\ReadVerbatimAndImmediateWriteEighteen|wolframscript & echo %ERRORLEVEL% > latexalpha2_check.tmp|`