# Arrange 6 pdf pages on one side

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, technical-drawing

I have 5 different pdf files/pages, of which two are in A3-format (landscape) and the remaining 4 are in A4-format (portrait).

Now I want to arrange them on one A1-page in the following order:

```
 _________ _________  
|         |         |  
|   A3    |   A3    |  
|_________|_________|  
|    |    |    |    |  
| A4 | A4 | A4 | A4 |  
|____|____|____|____|
```

I already tried to use the `pdfpages` package. 
With the following code, I was able to arrange the A1-pages as well as the A4 pages. But the A4-pages are always on a seperate page.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\geometry{a1paper, landscape, margin=0mm}

\begin{document}
    \includepdfmerge[nup=2x1]{zeichnung1.pdf, zeichnung2.pdf}
    \includepdfmerge[nup=4x1]{zeichnung3.pdf, zeichnung4.pdf, zeichnung5.pdf, zeichnung6.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Another point is, that I don't want any margins between the pages or on the side edges. I have to arrange technical drawings and therefore they have to fit perfectly.

Thanks in advance!
Frieder

Comment: With `pgfpages` you can define whatever layout you want. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370284/36296 for an example.

Comment: i can't test, so this is just a guess.  try adding `\noindent` before the first inclusion.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `tabular` environment for adjusting figures like the following:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{a1paper, landscape, margin=0mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{@{}c@{}}}
    \includegraphics{zeichnung1.pdf} & \includegraphics{zeichnung2.pdf} \\
    \includegraphics{zeichnung3.pdf}\includegraphics{zeichnung4.pdf} & 
    \includegraphics{zeichnung5.pdf}\includegraphics{zeichnung6.pdf} \\
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! 
It works great, but unfortunately I get a very small gap between my left side edge and between the two rows. I tried to use the `minimal` class, but it didn't change anything. 
Do you have any ideas, how I can prevent that from happening?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Wulle: **Don't** use the `minimal` class!

Comment: Even if/When I use the common `article` class, I get those margins. 
Only thing that worked, was to set the vertical/horizontal offsets by hand afterwards. But thats far from being satisfactory.

Comment: @Wulle You're right, there is some internal margin in the cell.

Use `standalone` class instead of `minimal`. In this case, there is no need to set the margin and it will be fit to the context.

Answer (score 1):

I want to thank javadr for the answer, which was helpful. Only think that didn't work as expected was the margin between the pages.

But I think I found a solution.
I use TikZ. I am not an expert with TikZ (but who could call himself an expert with such a massive package?)

The following Code worked fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \tikzstyle{node}=[inner sep=0pt, anchor=north west]

\geometry{a1paper, landscape, margin=0mm}%, left=-7mm}% 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, x=1mm, y=1mm]
    \coordinate (N) at (current page.north);
    \coordinate (NW) at (current page.north west);
    \coordinate (NE) at (current page.north east);
    \coordinate (E) at (current page.east);
    \coordinate (S) at (current page.south);
    \coordinate (SW) at (current page.south west);
    \coordinate (SE) at (current page.south east);
    \coordinate (W) at (current page.west);
    \coordinate (C) at (current page.center);
    \coordinate (WC) at ($(W)!0.5!(C)$);
    \coordinate (SWC) at ($(SW)!0.5!(S)$);
    \coordinate (EC) at ($(E)!0.5!(C)$);
    \coordinate (SEC) at ($(SE)!0.5!(S)$);

    \node[node] at (NW) {\includegraphics{zeichnung1.pdf}};
    \node[node] at (N)  {\includegraphics{zeichnung2.pdf}};
    \node[node] at (W)  {\includegraphics{zeichnung3.pdf}};
    \node[node] at (WC) {\includegraphics{zeichnung4.pdf}};
    \node[node] at (C)  {\includegraphics{zeichnung5.pdf}};
    \node[node] at (EC) {\includegraphics{zeichnung6.pdf}};

    \draw[line width=0.5mm] 
        (N) -- (S)
        (W) -- (E)
        (WC) -- (SWC)
        (EC) -- (SEC);

    \draw[line width=0.7mm] 
        ($(NW) + (5,-5)$) rectangle ($(C) + (-5,5)$) 
        ($(N) + (5,-5)$) rectangle ($(E) + (-5,5)$)
        ($(W) + (5,-5)$) rectangle ($(SWC) + (-5,5)$)
        ($(WC) + (5,-5)$) rectangle ($(S) + (-5,5)$)
        ($(C) + (5,-5)$) rectangle ($(SEC) + (-5,5)$)
        ($(EC) + (5,-5)$) rectangle ($(SE) + (-5,5)$); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(In this code I added some frame-lines that I need too)

Wish you all the best!
Frieder

Comment: The `tikz` package is an excellent one, and it can handle many cases, but in the last answer, I wanted to answer it as simple as possible. 
Therefore I think it's better to choose your answer as the best one.