# Testing for consecutive calls to an environment

Tags: counters

I use beamer to make slides for my statistics class and have a very nice setup now that generates output similar to powerpoint (see question: [Use Beamer to put 3 slides per page with notes beside (like powerpoint)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370271/use-beamer-to-put-3-slides-per-page-with-notes-beside-like-powerpoint)).

For this system to work, I need a definition for the notes associated with a slide for each slide or the notes will become out-of-sync with slides.  There is probably a better way to define a "default" note definition for a slide so that they can never get out of sync, but this is way beyond my ability in latex, and the environment is sufficiently complicated that posting an MWE for that would be hard (for me).

Instead, I want to at least catch the error that no notes have been defined for a slide.  The easiest way I can think to do that has been reduced to an MWE shown below:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\newcounter{mypagecount}
\setcounter{mypagecount}{1}

\newcommand\incpagecount{
  \stepcounter{mypagecount}
}
\newcommand\getpagecount{
  \themypagecount
}

\newenvironment{mypage}[1]{%
Parameter: #1 Expected: \getpagecount Body :}{ \incpagecount \\ }

\begin{document}

\begin{mypage}{1} foo \end{mypage}
\begin{mypage}{2} foo \end{mypage}
\begin{mypage}{4} foo \end{mypage}
\begin{mypage}{5} foo \end{mypage}

\end{document}
```

QUESTION:  How do I make latex throw an error when it detects that there was no call for mypage {3}?  For c programmers, showing how to use a c-style assert that the parameter does not equal the expected value would be great!

Thanks all.

Comment: Note that you are introducing lots of probably spurious spaces. `\incpagecount` and `\getpagecount` both include 2 (which will normally get treated as 1 in the output, of course). You probably don't want these macros to do this. (Personally, `\incpagecount` strikes me as pointless obfuscation: it would be clearer to just use `\stepcounter{mypagecount}`. But maybe that's just me.)

Comment: Its my pesky programming background -- I want to indent body of a "function".

Comment: The indentation isn't a problem. It is the uncommented new lines which are problematic.

Comment: Never understood those.  Now I do.

Comment: I've suggested a different approach, which allows you to omit slides in the handout. However, if you never wish to omit them, it would be easy to make it give an error in that case. I just think it is easier to keep the notes and the slides in a single file. But maybe that's just me - no doubt you're better at keeping track of things ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No assert.  Not even a `!=`.  There is also `\if`, `\ifdim`, `\ifx`, `\ifcase`, `\@ifundefined`, `\@ifl@aded`, etc.  See the TeXbook (Knuth) and source2e.pdf (CTAN).

Note, local definitions will not be available outside an environment.  Fortunately, the counter operations use global versions.  `\global\let` and `\xdef` can be used, but `\setlength` and `\renewcommand` cannot.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\newcounter{mypagecount}
\setcounter{mypagecount}{1}

\newcommand\incpagecount{%
  \stepcounter{mypagecount}%
}
\newcommand\getpagecount{% redundant
  \themypagecount
}

\newenvironment{mypage}[1]{%
\ifnum\value{mypagecount}=#1\relax
\else
  \errmessage{Parameter: #1 Expected: \getpagecount}%
  \setcounter{mypagecount}{#1}%
\fi
\noindent Body :}%
{ \incpagecount \\ }

\begin{document}

\begin{mypage}{1} foo \end{mypage}
\begin{mypage}{2} foo \end{mypage}
\begin{mypage}{4} foo \end{mypage}
\begin{mypage}{5} foo \end{mypage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `\\ ` be `\par`?

Comment: @cfr - Not sure.  I only added the \noindent to get the first line even with the others.  (I guess my OCD is acting up again ;-)

Comment: I more meant: won't that give bad boxes, but maybe it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a different solution. This is currently a proof-of-concept. In particular, it will fail if you pass any options other than `label` to the `frame` environment. This can be fixed, I think, but it would complicate matters.

The idea is to include the slides into the handout in a different way. This makes use of Beamer's `beamerarticle` package, the `label` option for `frame` environments and the `\includeslide` macro. It also uses `xcoffins` (because I got too frustrated messing around with `minipage`s and the like) and `environ`.

Workflow:

- 3 files, 2 of which are extremely simple wrappers which input the third.
- The third file contains no `\documentclass`, but both slides and notes. Suppose this is `<main file name>.tex`.
- The slides go in `frame` environments, as usual. These are labelled using the `label` option.
- The notes go in `annot` environments. These require an argument giving the label for the corresponding slide. (If you were referring to the slide normally, this is the argument you'd give `\ref{}`.) An optional argument can be used to override the settings used when including the slide.
- The first wrapper is compiled to produce the slides. I called this `<main file name>-beamer.tex`. The content of this file should be

  ```
  \pdfminorversion=7% comment this out if not using pdftex
  \documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
  \input{<main file name>}% substitute appropriately here
  ```

  This should be compiled **first**.
- The second wrapper is compiled to produce the handouts. I called this `<main file name>-article.tex` because I used the `article` class and Beamer's `article` mode. The content of this file should be

  ```
  \pdfminorversion=7% comment this out if not using pdftex
  \documentclass{article}% adjust if you prefer a different class
  \usepackage{beamerarticle,graphicx}
  \setjobnamebeamerversion{<main file name>-beamer}% substitute appropriately here
  \input{<main file name>}% substitute appropriately here
  ```

  This should be compiled **second**.

Then in `<main file name>.tex`, you put the rest of your preamble and the `document` body. I put most of the custom stuff in the preamble here, restricting it to Beamer's `article` mode, but you could move this to the handout wrapper if you preferred.

```
% \jobname.tex = <main file name>.tex
\mode<article>
{
```

This will only be executed in `article` mode.

```
  \usepackage{xcoffins,environ,geometry,calc,pgf}
```

`xcoffins`, `environ`, `pgf` and `calc` are required. `geometry` just got rid of the bad boxes.

First, a couple of new lengths which we need later.

```
  \newlength\annotsep
  \setlength\annotsep{.5em}% set the horizontal separation of frames and annotations
  \newlength\frmwd
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \setlength\frmwd{.5\linewidth-.5\annotsep-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
  }
```

And a couple of coffins.

```
  \NewCoffin\AnnotCoffin
  \NewCoffin\FrameCoffin
```

Now we define the `annot` environment, but we use `\NewEnviron` rather than `\newenvironment` because we want to put the entire content into a coffin and this seemed easiest. (I was trying to avoid `expl3` syntax` here.)

```
  \NewEnviron{annot}[2][]{%
    \edef\tempa{\extractedref}\edef\tempb{#2}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb\relax
    \else\outputempty\fi\xdef\extractedref{}%
```

This checks if there are any frames which we've not put a slide in for, other than the one for this annotation. If there's been a labelled `frame` which this set of notes does not correspond to, we assume that frame has no notes and we output it with a blank space on the right instead.

Now we set up our first coffin, `\FrameCoffin`, with a framed copy of the relevant slide (i.e. the one we referenced using the `annot` environment's mandatory argument).

```
    \SetVerticalCoffin\FrameCoffin{.5\linewidth-.5\annotsep}{%
      \fbox{\includeslide[width=\frmwd,#1]{#2}}% depending on theme, remove frame if not required
    }%
```

Now we set up our second coffin, `\AnnotCoffin` for the notes.

```
    \SetVerticalCoffin\AnnotCoffin{.5\linewidth-.5\annotsep}{%
      \BODY
    }%
```

We join the coffins at the top, pushing the nodes across and down a little.

```
    \JoinCoffins\FrameCoffin[t,r]\AnnotCoffin[t,l](\annotsep,-.5\baselineskip)
```

Typeset our coffins and leave some flexible vertical space so that our slides get evenly spaced on the page.

```
    \TypesetCoffin\FrameCoffin
    \medskip\vfill\par
  }
  \usepackage{kantlipsum}
```

This package is just for the example. Don't load this in your real document unless you're typesetting the relevant excerpts from Kant and don't mind the probably outdated translation.

A couple of new commands.

```
  \newcommand\extractref{}
  \newcommand\extractedref{}
```

Define one of them as a helper macro.

```
  \def\extractref label=#1\null{#1}
```

This changes the definition of `frame` in `article` mode. Normally, Beamer typesets the `frame` content in all modes. However, here we don't want that. We define it to take a single optional argument. Everything else will disappear. But, if there's an optional first argument and it is not empty, we'll assume it is a `label=<key for label>` and we'll extract this reference.

```
  \RenewEnviron{frame}[1][]{%
    \edef\tempa{#1}\edef\tempb{}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb\relax
    \else
      \outputempty
```

If the macro keeping trac, `\extractedref` is not empty, then there's been a slide without a corresponding set of notes, so we assume that slide has no notes and output that slide with a blank set of notes on the right.

```
      \xdef\extractedref{\extractref #1\null}%
```

For the current `frame`, we don't typeset anything. We just extract and store the reference in `\extractedref`.

```
    \fi
  }
```

Now for the macro which outputs `frame`s without annotations. This is used by the redefined `frame` and the `annot` environments.

```
  \newcommand\outputempty{%
    \edef\tempb{}%
    \edef\tempa{\extractedref}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb\relax
    \else
```

No need for coffins here, but we output the slide using the default configuration and put the same vertical space in, to keep the slides evenly spread on the page.

```
      \fbox{\includeslide[width=\frmwd]{\extractedref}}%
      \medskip\vfill\par
    \fi
  }
}
```

I guess you don't want paragraph indentation here. You might consider using the `parskip` package, but this may not matter, depending on the content of your notes.

```
  \setlength\parindent{0pt}
```

If the last `frame` is labelled but noteless, we need to make sure it gets into the handout. One more `\outputempty` should do it.

```
  \AtEndDocument{\outputempty}
```

That's the configuration. Now for the document.

```
\begin{document}
```

here's a frame, labelled `frame-a`.

```
\begin{frame}[label=frame-a]{A Frame}%
  \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
\end{frame}
```

Here are the notes for `frame-a`.

```
\begin{annot}{frame-a}
  Not much to say about image A.
\end{annot}
```

Similarly, for `frame-b` and `frame-c`.

```
\begin{frame}[label=frame-b]{B Frame}%
  \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
\end{frame}
\begin{annot}{frame-b}
  Not much to say about image b.
\end{annot}

\begin{frame}[label=frame-c]{C Frame}%
  \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}
\end{frame}
\begin{annot}{frame-c}
  Not much to say about image C.
\end{annot}
```

This makes a page with `geometry`'s default layout.

Here's `frame-another`. This one lacks notes, so there's no `annot` following.

```
\begin{frame}[label=frame-another]{Another Frame}%
  \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\end{frame}
```

In `article` mode, the next frame will cause `frame-another` to be output, because we'll assume no notes exist for that `frame`. I ran out, and got bored of, MWE's images, so here's a roaring alternative.

```
\begin{frame}[label=frame-tiger]{Tiger Frame}%
  \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{tiger}
\end{frame}
\begin{annot}{frame-tiger}
  This frame shows a large, wild cat.
  Well, what it actually shows is a small picture of a wild cat, but you are meant to infer that it represents a larger reality.
\end{annot}
```

The next `frame` has a very long note, so will end up on its own page. Bit less of a roar here, but safety in numbers, perhaps.

```
\begin{frame}[label=frame-cats]{Cats Frame}%
  \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{cathod}
\end{frame}
\begin{annot}{frame-cats}
  \kant[1-2]
\end{annot}

\begin{frame}[label=frame-which]{Which Frame?}%
 \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{cauldron}
\end{frame}
\begin{annot}{frame-which}
  This frame includes a pun, a cauldron and a question.
  More accurately, it includes a pun, a depiction of a cauldron and a question mark.
\end{annot}
```

And a last, noteless `frame`, to make sure the final `\outputempty` does the trick.

```
\begin{frame}[label=frame-gadael]
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{cath-gadael-chartref}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Slides:

[image: slides]

Handout / notes:

[image: handout with notes]

Complete code (needs substitution for file names where indicated):

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-beamer.tex}
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\input{<main file name>}% substitute \jobname or whatever here
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-article.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle,graphicx}
\setjobnamebeamerversion{<main file name>-beamer}% substitute \jobname or whatever here
\input{<main file name>}% substitute \jobname or whatever here
\end{filecontents}

% \jobname.tex = <main file name>.tex
\mode<article>
{
  \usepackage{xcoffins,environ,geometry,calc,pgf}
  \newlength\annotsep
  \setlength\annotsep{.5em}% set the horizontal separation of frames and annotations
  \newlength\frmwd
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \setlength\frmwd{.5\linewidth-.5\annotsep-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
  }
  \NewCoffin\AnnotCoffin
  \NewCoffin\FrameCoffin
  \NewEnviron{annot}[2][]{%
    \edef\tempa{\extractedref}\edef\tempb{#2}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb\relax
    \else\outputempty\fi\xdef\extractedref{}%
    \SetVerticalCoffin\FrameCoffin{.5\linewidth-.5\annotsep}{%
      \fbox{\includeslide[width=\frmwd,#1]{#2}}% depending on theme, remove frame if not required
    }%
    \SetVerticalCoffin\AnnotCoffin{.5\linewidth-.5\annotsep}{%
      \BODY
    }%
    \JoinCoffins\FrameCoffin[t,r]\AnnotCoffin[t,l](\annotsep,-.5\baselineskip)
    \TypesetCoffin\FrameCoffin
    \medskip\vfill\par
  }
  \usepackage{kantlipsum}
  \newcommand\extractref{}
  \newcommand\extractedref{}
  \def\extractref label=#1\null{#1}
  \RenewEnviron{frame}[1][]{%
    \edef\tempa{#1}\edef\tempb{}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb\relax
    \else
      \outputempty
      \xdef\extractedref{\extractref #1\null}%
    \fi
  }
  \newcommand\outputempty{%
    \edef\tempb{}%
    \edef\tempa{\extractedref}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb\relax
    \else
      \fbox{\includeslide[width=\frmwd]{\extractedref}}%
      \medskip\vfill\par
    \fi
  }
  \setlength\parindent{0pt}
  \AtEndDocument{\outputempty}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=frame-a]{A Frame}%
  \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
\end{frame}
\begin{annot}{frame-a}
  Not much to say about image A.
\end{annot}

\begin{frame}[label=frame-b]{B Frame}%
  \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
\end{frame}
\begin{annot}{frame-b}
  Not much to say about image b.
\end{annot}

\begin{frame}[label=frame-c]{C Frame}%
  \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}
\end{frame}
\begin{annot}{frame-c}
  Not much to say about image C.
\end{annot}

\begin{frame}[label=frame-another]{Another Frame}%
  \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=frame-tiger]{Tiger Frame}%
  \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{tiger}
\end{frame}
\begin{annot}{frame-tiger}
  This frame shows a large, wild cat.
  Well, what it actually shows is a small picture of a wild cat, but you are meant to infer that it represents a larger reality.
\end{annot}

\begin{frame}[label=frame-cats]{Cats Frame}%
  \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{cathod}
\end{frame}
\begin{annot}{frame-cats}
  \kant[1-2]
\end{annot}

\begin{frame}[label=frame-which]{Which Frame?}%
 \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{cauldron}
\end{frame}
\begin{annot}{frame-which}
  This frame includes a pun, a cauldron and a question.
  More accurately, it includes a pun, a depiction of a cauldron and a question mark.
\end{annot}

\begin{frame}[label=frame-gadael]
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{cath-gadael-chartref}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Admittedly, this doesn't give an error .... If you want to never omit slides (rather than omitting unlabelled ones), you can add a conditional error into the redefinition of `frame` to get an error in `article` mode.

Comment: Wow.  Thank you for the thought that went into posting this.  This looks like a more general solution to the problem of generating powerpoint like output from beamer (which was the subject of the earlier post I referenced).  I am currently in the middle of my semester, and can't try this change to my workflow, but I will look into it in more detail at the end of the semester.

Comment: @ChristopherDonham I just think it is easier if the slides and notes are in one file. At least, I prefer this kind of workflow. I haven't used this layout, but I got the general wrapper trick from UK TUG courtesy of Joseph Wright. The layout you want is trickier, because you have to get rid of the contents of the `frame`s and I've probably not done that in the most elegant way. But the keeping-it-all-in-one principle I find makes it easier to see what I'm doing.