# If \@percentchar represents %, is there a macro for #?

Tags: macros, characters

If `\@percentchar` represents `%`, is there a macro for `#`? I have tried `\@sharpchar` and `\@numberchar` but both do not exist. Do you have any idea what is the correct macro name for `#`?

Comment: why not `\#`  and `\%` or do you want to expand to a character rather than just typeset it in which case `\edef\zzz{\string#}`

Comment: Future note. `\c_hash_str`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. If all you need is to *print* a `#` then `\#` is good; but `\#` is unexpandable, so in a `\write` it will be passed as `\#`. In a `\write18` it will be the shell's duty to interpret it correctly. For instance, on a Unix system you can't do

```
\write18{echo # foo}
```

(probably a more useful command would be passed), because the shell wouldn't see `foo` as `#` is a comment character. Doing

```
\write18{echo \# foo}
```

will echo `# foo`. On the other hand,

```
\write18{echo '# foo'}
```

would echo `## foo`, because of the peculiar TeX's habit of doubling hash marks in token lists when `#` has, as usual, category code 6. But

```
\write18{echo '\# foo'}
```

would echo `\# foo`.

So a good strategy is to have a control sequence that expands to a category code 12 hash mark in all cases, given that TeX expands token lists in a `\write`:

```
\edef\hashmark{\string#}
```

Thus

```
\write 18{echo '\hashmark\space foo'}
```

will echo `# foo`.

Unfortunately, different shells tend to have their own idiosyncrasies and with special characters it's always a pain getting equal behavior on all of them on every operating system. Some need quotes around the commands, some don't want them (I guess that Windows has very different conventions than Unix).

Answer (score 13):

To typeset `#` you can use `\#` but to have a macro that expands to a catcode 12 (normal character) `#` use `\zzz` defined by

```
\edef\zzz{\string#}
```

or some other macro name of your choice.

Comment: Which is recommended, `\immediate\write18{ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages\#/None}` or `\edef\hms{\string#}\immediate\write18{ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages\hms/None}` ?

Comment: @Marienplatz it's not a matter of recommended it's what you want, one produces `\#` and the other produces `#`

Comment: I am a bit confused. So what does `ps2pdf` receive if I use `\immediate\write18{ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages\#/None}` instead of `\edef\hms{\string#}\immediate\write18{ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages\hms/None}`?

Comment: @Marienplatz replace `\immediate\write18{` by `\immediate\write20{` and you'll see what is output.

Comment: OK. I am trying...

Comment: The point is that your shell very likely unescapes `\#` so `ps2pdf` recieves only `#` either case.