# How to include a listing with `#` in the filename?

Tags: listings

Given the following files:

### `book.tex`

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings
\chapter{Hello, world!}
\lstinputlisting{C\#/hello.cs}
\end{document}
```

## `C#/hello.cs`

```
using System;

class Hello {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

What is the correct syntax to include file `C#/hello.cs` as a listing in `book.tex`?

I tried these variants, both fail:

- `\lstinputlisting{C#/hello.cs}`
- `\lstinputlisting{C\#/hello.cs}`

When I try the first variant, `\lstinputlisting{C#/hello.cs}`, I get the following error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
<to be read again> 
/
l.7 \lstinputlisting{C#/hello.cs}
                               
?
```

When I try the second variant, `\lstinputlisting{C\#/hello.cs}`, I get the following error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
#
l.7 \lstinputlisting{C\#/hello.cs}
                                
?
```

I get the same behavior with (almost) identical error messages in `lualatex`, `pdflatex`, and `xelatex`.

I've tried to find a solution by reading the documetnation of the listings package https://mirror.mwt.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf. Alas, in vain.

What is the correct way to use the *listings* package to include a file that has a `#`-character in its pathname? (As a workaround, I could of course rename the directory from `C#` to `Csharp`, but I'd like to *solve* the problem, not *avoid* it.)

Comment: Potentially  helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616206/218142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the author of `listings` probably didn't account for this case, so there isn't really a "correct" solution.

I think there are two ways, if you insist.

### Method 1. Patch `\lstinputlisting` to allow `\#`

You could do this...

```
\let\oldlstinputlisting\lstinputlisting
\def\lstinputlisting#1{%
    \begingroup
    \escapechar=-1
    \expandafter \endgroup
    \expandafter \oldlstinputlisting
    \expandafter {\detokenize{#1}}%
}
```

then do something like...

```
\lstinputlisting{\#.txt}
```

but one possible disadvantage is that code like `\def\filename{myfile.txt}\lstinputlistings{\filename}`, which would work before the patch, now wouldn't. (it might break other things as well, I don't know.)

### Method 2. Inject a catcode-other `#` in

Ref. [characters - If \@percentchar represents %, is there a macro for #? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142428/if-percentchar-represents-is-there-a-macro-for)

```
\edef\hashchar{\string#}

\lstinputlisting{\hashchar.txt}
```

Use a `\hashchar` everywhere you want a `#`.

(this method does implicitly rely on `\lstinputlisting` "fully expands" the arguments, but this is more likely than not since the primitive `\input` etc. does for file names. Otherwise putting a catcode-other-token `#` into the argument itself is possible, but a bit harder)

Comment: There are `\@charlb \@charrb \@backslashchar \space` by the way, but you need `\makeatletter` for the first 3.

Answer (score 2):

Method 3: Use `\string##` instead `\#`, i.e.:

```
\lstinputlisting{C\string##/hello.cs}
```

Comment: Ah right, I didn't test this one. Although it depends quite a lot on the specific implementation of the macro doing `\def` once (which converts it to a single #) followed by "full expansion".