# Debugging in LaTeX: debugging walkthrough with specific example

Tags: beamer, debugging

I am not new to LaTeX, but I have never really written an actual LaTeX script and so I have trouble debugging the one I have. I will post the specific problem, so there is something I can grab unto, but I actually want to understand and solve the specific problem AND understand how this can be usually done. So the problem itself:

I am using `beamer` and am trying to use the package `pdfpcnotes` to increase the functionality of the `note` command (this is the git repo: https://github.com/cebe/pdfpc-latex-notes/blob/master/pdfpcnotes.sty)

Here's my mwe:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{pdfpcnotes}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\frametitle{1. frame}
}
\pnote{first note}

\frame{
\frametitle{2. frame}
}
\pnote{second note}
\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex` on this produces the following output into `mwe.pdfpc`:

```
[notes]
### 1
first note
second note
```

but really it should be

```
[notes]
### 1
first note
### 2
second note
```

The problem itself is going to be around the if-else part of the script. Could somebody post a walkthrough on how such a problem could be solved? I find it extremely hard to wrap my head around how LaTeX works and how you can get internal information out of it.

Comment: So, to clarify, do you mean the `if` statement on lines 27-33 of `pdfpcnotes.sty`?

Comment: @ArunDebray Yes, I think that is where the problem should be, since based on the output, line 31 in `pdfpcnotes.sty` only get called once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in

```
\let\lastframenumber\theframenumber
```

because `\theframenumber` is `\@arabic\c@framenumber` and not the value directly.

To see this add `\show\theframenumber` after `begin{document}` and compile from terminal. Execution will stop at this and display

```
> \theframenumber=macro:
->\@arabic \c@framenumber .
l.5 \show\theframenumber

?
```

Pressing enter will resume execution.

Solution: `\edef\lastframenumber{\theframenumber}`

Full example (package code in the document):

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
%\usepackage{pdfpcnotes}

\makeatletter
% create a new file handle
\newwrite\pdfpcnotesfile

% open file on \begin{document}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \immediate\openout\pdfpcnotesfile\jobname.pdfpc\relax
  \immediate\write\pdfpcnotesfile{[notes]}%
}
% define a # http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37757/10327
\begingroup
\catcode`\#=12
\gdef\three@hashchars@space{###\space}%
\endgroup

\def\lastframenumber{0}

% define command \pnote{} that works like note but
% additionally writes notes to file in pdfpc readable format
\newcommand{\pnote}[1]{%
  % keep normal notes working
  \note{#1}%
  % if frame changed - write a new header
  \ifdim\theframenumber pt>\lastframenumber pt
    \edef\lastframenumber{\theframenumber}%
    \immediate\write\pdfpcnotesfile{\three@hashchars@space\theframenumber}%
  \fi
  % write note to file
  \immediate\write\pdfpcnotesfile{\unexpanded{#1}}%
}
% close file on \begin{document}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\closeout\pdfpcnotesfile
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frame{
\frametitle{1. frame}
}
\pnote{first note}

\frame{
\frametitle{2. frame}
}
\pnote{second note}
\end{document}
```

Output file:

```
[notes]
### 1
first note
### 2
second note
```

Comment: Thank you for the fix! Could you please explain how you got to this solution? How did you figure out that `\theframenumber` is already define somewhere and is `\@arabic\c@framenumber`, how did you access the value of these variables during the runtime? (I checked the difference between `\edef` and `\let` there's a good answer to that on the site :)

Comment: @fbence I checked the definition of `\theframenumber` and that was it. `;-)`

Comment: :D Okay, so I really don't know how to do that: what is the exact command that can pull this information into say the logs or stdout? Or did you just `grep` the beamer source files?

Comment: @fbence Add `\show\theframenumber` to the document, after `\begin{document}`. Compile from a terminal and see.

Comment: I was too fast to mark your answer accepted:) Changed the `pdfpcnotes.sty` at line 28 to `\edef\lastframenumber\theframenumber`. This now complains that `[1{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]! Extra \endgroup.` and `! Use of \lastframenumber doesn't match its definition`

Comment: @fbence You are missing the braces, I think: `\edef\lastframenumber{\theframenumber}%`

Comment: and I was ... sorry ...

Answer (score 1):

Your document should be better structured with beamer, however I do not know if it'll resolve your troubles

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}
\pnote{my note}
\end{frame}
```

Since `\pnote` acts like `\note`, it should be inside the frames.

Comment: actually, placing `\note` outside the frame makes sense. From the manual: " `\note[⟨options⟩]{⟨note text⟩}` Outside frames, this command creates a note page."

Comment: Placing the `\pnote` inside the frame actually does make it work as it should (but messes up the `[notes]` option of beamer, because `\pnote[item]` is not implemented), thanks for that! But I would still like to understand how I would debug this, see in some comprehensible why, where and how the variables change.