# Using a batch script in latex \immediate\write18 env

Tags: overleaf, shell-escape, texcount, immediate

I am trying to write a script that using texcount will output only the number of characters including spaces. I made a batch script which works, no problems there.

The problem is trying to run it in latex shell escape in overleaf using the \immediate\write18 environment. The problems seems mostly to be with how latex handles the special characters used in the batchscript. The script/latex code is as follows:

```
\newcommand{\quickcharcount}[1]{%
\immediate\write18{
texcount -1 -sum -merge -char -q main.tex > chars.txt
texcount -1 -sum -merge -q main.tex > spaces.txt
for /f "skip=1" %%G IN (spaces.txt) DO if not defined line set "nSpace=%%G"
for /f "skip=1" %%G IN (chars.txt) DO if not defined line set "nChar=%%G"
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%G in ('findstr /n "^" spaces.txt') do if %%G equ 2 set "nSpace=%%H"
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%G in ('findstr /n "^" chars.txt') do if %%G equ 2 set "nChar=%%H"
set /a "sum=nChar+nSpace"
echo %sum% > count.sum
}%
\input{count.sum} 
}
```

Does anyone have experience with this, and know how to solve the problem?

EDIT:

I was told it was not possible with a bat script, so I have now written it as a shell script. But I am still struggling with getting it to work inside latex. You said it was somewhat restrictive with overleaf, so could this also be the reason here?

```
#!/bin/bash
char=$(texcount -1 -sum -merge -char -q main.tex)
space=$(texcount -1 -sum -merge -q main.tex)
nChar=${char%(*}
nSpace=${space%(*}
sum=$((nChar + nSpace))
echo $sum > count.sum
```

Comment: @cabohah I have now written it as a shell script and updated it in the original post. But it still poses a problem with latex. Would it be possible to just call a .sh file instead of inserting the text manually?

Comment: I believe this should work out of the box, but escaping the `%` character may be a bit difficult, so just put it in a separate `.sh` file and use `ShellEscape` which should work -- if it doesn't then you need to make a MWE somehow. Try also `2> error.txt` then `\VerbatimInput{error.txt}` (or just download `error.txt` within the generated files) to see if it prints any error message. // @cabohah as far as I can see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534049/pythontex-not-working-on-current-overleaf-compiler is on-topic here so this question should also be.

Comment: @cabohah there is nothing overleaf  specfic about this question

Comment: you have defined `\quickcharcount` to have 1 argument you don't use???

Comment: @cabohah Unless the question e.g. shows only an Overleaf link and not a MWE inside the question itself, it should be suitable for the site, just like how questions about TeXStudio or any other editor is.

Comment: See also: [pdftex - \write18 pass % through to shell - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17462/write18-pass-through-to-shell)

Comment: @cabohah  The OP provided  a bash version with the same (no line ends) issue. The original version  with just bat/cmd could be said to be linux specfic,  but even that wasn't overleaf specific, you would have the same error in any linux tex. I tested my answer on a local installation (on this windows laptop) not overleaf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So because you think, that trying to use a bat with overlead is not overleaf specific, I've removed my corresponding comments. But IMHO in this case, the overleaf tag should also be removed. And IMHO in this case, the question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17462/write18-pass-through-to-shell and still should be closed.

Comment: `%` is a duplicate but that doesn't cover line ends being written as spaces  (but that must be a duplicate of something:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You have defined `\quickcharcount` to have 1 argument you don't use so I defined it with no arguments.

A newline in the source is a space so all your script is on one line.
You could use `^^J` to write a newline but here I just use the bash command
separator `;` You also need `\@percentchar` as `%` is a comment.

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\quickcharcount}{%no argument
\immediate\write18{
char=$(texcount -1 -sum -merge -char -q main.tex);
space=$(texcount -1 -sum -merge -q main.tex);
nChar=${char\@percentchar(*};
nSpace=${space\@percentchar(*};
sum=$((nChar + nSpace));
echo $sum > count.sum
}%
\input{count.sum}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
abc xyz

\quickcharcount
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works! But just to clarify, the reason there was a unused argument was that it was used to input the name of the "main" tex file. So it would be "#1.tex". I had just removed it during troubleshooting.