# What is the default \parskip in memoir?

Tags: memoir, latex-base, parskip

Everywhere the usual word is that it is 0. But that is clearly wrong, it is 0 + some rubber length. But how is that rubber length defined?

In my search I found the following definition in the memoir source:

```
\setlength\parskip{0\p@ \@plus \p@}
```

Now what does that actually mean? How can I for example scale it down so the rubber length is half the size? Half of what by the way? There is no number there just a `\p@` is that a length?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`\p@` is a LaTeX2e kernel dimension, equal to 1 pt. It is used as this saves some tokens in the kernel, and also makes it possible to write thinks like `0\pt`, which TeX interprets as 0 times 1 pt. So written out 'long hand' the definition is '1pt'. (That token-saving was really important when LaTeX2e was written: `\p@` is one token, `1pt` is three. Today, it is more confusing than anything else.)

Comment: It may seem mostly confusing, but it comes in handy [if you want to use an alternate definition of `pt`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34024/4012).

Answer (score 18):

Use the `\showthe` Tex primative to show the value + rubber if you are unsure what all the tokens mean

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\showthe\parskip
\end{document}
```

and the output in the log file

```
> 0.0pt plus 1.0pt.
l.3     \showthe\parskip
```

You can use these values to set a length

Comment: Can you comment on what `l.3` means in this context?

Comment: 1.3 is file 1, line number 3

Comment: Actually that's an `l` (for `line`), not a `1`, in case that helps to remember what it means :)

Answer (score 11):

You can get such settings very easily using [`(la)texdef`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texdef). (TeXLive doens't install the `latexdef` symlink at the moment, so you have to use `texdef -t latex` instead)

```
$ texdef -t latex -c memoir -v parskip

\the\parskip:
0.0pt plus 1.0pt


$ texdef -t latex p@ @plus

\p@:
\dimen11


\the\p@:
1.0pt


\@plus:
macro:->plus
```

The `\p@` is a dimension with 1pt and can be also used to add the `pt` unit behind numbers. The `\@plus` simply stands for the string `plus`. This is done to save token space (`\p@` is one token, `pt` are two), which was important in earlier (La)TeX versions. So `0\p@` is `0x1pt` = `0pt`. The `plus 1.0pt` is a positive stretch amount. So the parskip is normally 0pt but can stretch till 0+1pt=1pt if required.

Such macros are also explained by [Documentation reference for LaTeX internal commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands/10465#10465).

Comment: Have you considered uploading a package to [TLcontrib](http://tlcontrib.metatex.org) that does contain the symlink?

Comment: @Sharpie: I got in contact with the TeXLive maintainers and got told that the didn't included a `latexdef` symlink in order to keep the number or new executable short and to not favor it before e.g. `contextdef` (which is also supported).

Comment: Fair enough, pretty easy to write a bash alias or wrapper. Thanks for such a great tool!