# Setting a document in MS Word-12pt (12bp)

Tags: fontsize, msword, unit-of-measure

### Warning

If you're looking for advice how to **make your document look like it's been written in Word**, this is most likely **not the question you're looking for**. This question is mostly of theoretical nature, as it results in tiny differences, which will most likely not be noticed by someone who doesn't allow the use of LaTeX.

Questions that might be more helpful for this matter are:

- [Making a LaTeX document appear as though it were typeset in MS Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39544/4012)
- [LaTeX optimal settings for MS Word-like document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35892/4012)
- [Make a LaTeX document look like it was written in Microsoft Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47865/4012)
- [Change section fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10138/4012)

---

### Question

I learned that MS Word uses a slightly different version of the unit "point" (pt) than TeX does:

> The 12 point of Word will be PostScript point, which in TeX would be called 12bp. A TeX `pt` is slightly smaller: it's 1/72.27 inch, while a `bp`/PostScript point is 1/72 inch. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29

([Martin Schröder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5763/martin-schroder) in [Latex commands for a specific page format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/latex-commands-for-a-specific-page-format/20215#20215))

I'm writing a paper that would usually be expected to be "typeset" in MS Word, thus I want to use the same font size as Word would.

**How do I set a document e.g. in the "12pt" font size that MS Word would use?**

In case it matters, I'm using the `article` document class, Latin Modern (`lmodern`) as a font with the T1 font encoding and compile with pdfLaTeX, but input on different set-ups is more than welcome.

Comment: Bonus question: Which "point" is preferable if I have a too high / too low page requirement to fulfill? `;)`

Comment: The MWE `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{12bp}{14bp}\selectfont foo
\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont foo
\end{document}​` produces a document with 2 different font sizes for `foo`: the first is `12bp` and the second is `12pt`. `lmodern` has this modification by default. Is this what you're after?

Comment: @CountZero: Not that using Latin Modern (or any particular font instead of Times New "old 'n' boring" Roman) and TeX's hyphenation wouldn't make a bigger difference than the font sizes ... It's more a theoretical question. I've actually come up with an answer already, I'm just curious if the pros here would do the same; I'll add it in a couple days if it hasn't appeared yet. Plus this whole thing might be helpful if someone's really doing a "Use LaTeX but must be just like Word".

Comment: @Werner: I assume the way I worded my question, it is. If there were strict requirements regarding the font sizes of section titles, block quotes etc., I could just always use `bp`. What I actually had in mind (i.e. how I solved it) is telling LaTeX to always use Word's point instead of its own.

Comment: No, it's not possible to tell LaTeX to use `bp` instead of `pt`. But I don't think the difference can be appreciated by the naked eye. An "A" at 12pt is 8.13588pt high, while it is 8.1664pt at 12bp. The difference is 0.01 millimeters.

Comment: @egreg: Are you referring to `\makeatletter
\p@=1bp
\makeatother` in the document preamble?

Comment: @Werner: That's about what I did, I used `\setlength{\p@}{1bp}`. It does end up in a few different hyphenations, but it'd be a coincidence if they added up to an extra line or the like.

Comment: @Werner That might work, but not all lengths are expressed in terms of `\p@`. What I was saying is that it's almost impossible that somebody can spot the difference between 12pt and 12bp size. Particularly if they require MS Word documents. :)

Comment: @egreg: I agree that the difference is negligible. So you're saying there are other dimensions not expressed in terms of `\p@` but chosen relative to `12pt` that would "get out of relation" (on a negligible scale as well) if we redefined `\p@` only?

Comment: LaTeX tries hard to define things in terms of multiples of `\p@` and not of `pt`. But one never knows. Remember, on the contrary, that 17 point size is, for LaTeX, 17.28. I wouldn't worry at all.

Comment: @egreg: I had thought of these slightly off sizes as well, yes; my question remains mainly hypothetical. In the end, all the interesting (relative) definitions can be found in `size12.clo`, right? If a dimension isn't altered because of the `12pt` option, it won't need altering if we use `bp` instead of `pt`. I looked into that file but I don't understand all of it.

Comment: @doncherry: In agreeance with @ egreg, a definition like `\p@=1bp` relies on anything other than the document class to use `\p@` rather than `pt`. Even [`ltplain`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/ltplain.dtx) specifies the use of `\p@` as an "abbreviation" for `1pt` (or more specifically, "this saves macro space and time"). Perhaps it's enough to assume that the cases where some other package uses `pt` instead of `p@` is negligible.

Comment: @Werner: And there's no way of redefining `pt` directly? Then I guess if one of you guys wants to, you could write up an answer with our gathered findings.

Comment: A related question is this one: [Globally redefining 1 pt to 1/72 in (PostScript point) and other similar changes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21758/2693).

Comment: Plain `TeX` has a command `\magnification`, which was disabled in `LaTeX`. The magnification produced this way is not really a 'typographically correct' resizing of the font, but for such subtle differences, it should do a perfect job. Other than that, I think nobody would guess it is not a `12bp` font, unless an actual `12bp` font is placed next to it. (This may happen in documents where some pages are typeset with `LaTeX` and others in MS Word... but then again, probably other features/elemets will differ much more spectacularly.) :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per the discussion, one way of achieving this goal is to redefine the "shorthand" length dimension used throughout the standard document classes. Here's an extract of the relevant code snippets from [`ltxplain.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/ltplain.dtx) containing the abbreviated definition:

```
\newdimen\p@ \p@=1pt % this saves macro space and time
```

As such, issuing

```
\makeatletter\p@=1bp\makeatother% or \setlength{\p@}{1bp}
```

modifies the default `1pt` reference to `1bp`. Looking at [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) (although other document classes are similar), many related lengths are set using `\p@`. Here's an excerpt:

```
\setlength\lineskip{1\p@}
\setlength\normallineskip{1\p@}
...
\setlength\parskip{0\p@ \@plus \p@}
...
\setlength\arraycolsep{5\p@}
\setlength\tabcolsep{6\p@}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4\p@}
\setlength\doublerulesep{2\p@}
...
\setlength\fboxsep{3\p@}
\setlength\fboxrule{.4\p@}
...
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{10\p@}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{0\p@}
...
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern-3\p@
  \hrule\@width.4\columnwidth
  \kern2.6\p@}
...
\setlength\columnsep{10\p@}
\setlength\columnseprule{0\p@}
```

including some macros like `\maketitle` and things associated with indexing. So, issue the size change *before* `\documentclass` in order to let the effect filter through. You would still "miss" some `\p@`-related definitions though, as may be seen by viewing [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx).

As a quick way to check the difference in the default `pt` and modified `bp` measurements (in [`lmodern`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lm)) is using [`printlen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/printlen). Here's a brief example with focus on the character `X`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lmodern
\usepackage{printlen}% http://ctan.org/pkg/printlen
\begin{document}
\uselengthunit{pt} \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
\setbox0=\hbox{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont X}% pt measurement
\setbox1=\hbox{\fontsize{12bp}{14pt}\selectfont X}% bp measurement
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  X & width & height \\ \hline
  \verb!pt! & \printlength{\wd0} & \printlength{\ht0} \\
  \verb!bp! & \printlength{\wd1} & \printlength{\ht1} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The difference in width is around `0.04pt` and `0.03pt` in height, which translates to about `0.01mm` - a roughly 0.3% increase (~ 72.27/72-1). This is virtually negligible to the naked eye at regular font sizes.

Paragraph construction is altered using `12bp` rather than `12pt`, and therefore also hyphenation. Here's an example showing the effect:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lmodern
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
\begin{tabular}{p{0.4\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}}
  \verb!12pt! font & \verb!12bp! font \\ \hline
  %\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont% pt measurement
  \lipsum[1] &
  \fontsize{12bp}{14pt}\selectfont% bp measurement
  \lipsum[1]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you resize in `bp`, it is better to keep the ratio to baseline the same i.e., \fontsize{12bp}{14bp}. Loading babel with `[english,latin]{babel}` will improve the examples. The real word will be much longer due to bad hyphenation.

Comment: Thanks; I wanted to keep the baseline reference the same across the examples to highlight the effect of `12bp` over `12pt`, hence the use of `\fontsize{12bp}{14pt}`.

Comment: With Latin hyphenation on the two paragraphs are typeset in exactly the same way. If **microtype** is loaded, there are some differences, but the number of lines is the same.

Comment: @egreg Now try and hyphenate Latin using Word:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Well, Italian would give the same result.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Word has patterns for Latin, but is not easy to be set as a language. Tried the example, it does not look too bad actually.

Comment: Changing a such generic command `\p@` has severe side effects. `\p@` is also used in calculations completely independent from font size/spacing stuff. For example, `\usepackage[pdftex]{color}...\textcolor[RGB]{255,0,0}{...}` will break with an error message, because 255/255 is now 1.00374 and larger than the allowed maximum value 1.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352580/package-color-error-argument-1-01125-no-in-range-0-1 for a case where changing the value of `\p@` makes for spectacular failure.

Comment: Werener it would be best to delete the suggestion to redefine `\p@` (I already have problems wih some journal classes doing this), it completly breaks any packages such as graphicx using tex dimen arithmetic

Answer (score 15):

Every [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) class has build in support for every font size you want. If you don't like to switch to a KOMA-Script class, this feature is one of the features KOMA-Script package scrextend provides for other classes:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12bp]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{scrextend}% provides several KOMA-Script features to other classes
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

You need a scalable font or a font with support for this font size. Latin Modern is a scalable font.

Comment: Does this change e.g. the title font size to 17bp? (To be precise, it's 17.28pt/bp, cf. egreg's comment to the question.)

Comment: @doncherry: It changes all font commands (and several lengths), e.g., `\huge`, `\LARGE`, `\Large` relative to 12bp/10bp. Example: At 10pt (predefined font size at article) `\LARGE` is `\@xviipt`, that is 17.28pt. With scrextend and `fontsize=12bp` it will be 17.28pt*12bp/10pt = 17,28*1,2bp=20.736bp=20.8137pt (try `\LARGE\csname f@size\endcsname` to see this). Alternative: You may define your own font size file scrsize12bp.clo. In this case this file will be used instead of calculated sizes by scrextend. Use scrsize12pt.clo as template and simply change all lengths from pt to bp.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I'm a little bit confused there. I always used KOMA-Script with `pt`. I tried using `fontsize=12bp` and got less pages than with `fontsize=12pt`. Should't it be opposite according to @Werner's answer?

Comment: @Thorsten: 1in = 72bp = 72,27pt. So a pt is smaller than a bp, but: With a4paper there's a `DIV` default for 12pt but not for 12bp. So `DIV=calc` will be used with 12bp. If I try a document with `DIV=9` and `\lipsum[1-100]` almost nothing changes if I use `fontsize=12bp` instead of `fontsize=12pt`. Additionally remember: There's a file `scrsize12pt.clo` with optimized (not only horizontal) lengths. KOMA-Script may use an optimized `scrsize12bp.clo` too, but it does not provide it.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Ah, that's a good point. I didn't think of `DIV`. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: With your MWE, I get a warning `Package scrextend Warning: Using fallback calculation to setup font sizes for basic size `12bp' on input line 12.` -- what's that telling me?

Comment: @doncherry: scrextend tries to use font size files for every wanted font size. I've already explained how to use the font size file `scrsize12pt.clo` to write such a file `scrsize12bp.clo` (see my comment to Thorsten). If is does not find a font size file, is it able to calculate all font size depending sizes from internally 10pt template. The result should be acceptable but maybe is not optimal (but at least as good as the results of Word). To tell you, that the calculation instead of a file has been used, you get the warning.

Answer (score 5):

There is a package / style by Juergen Fenn which addresses this situation in whole (rather than in part by adjusting the font size): [`wordlike`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wordlike)

I never used it, so I can't speak to its usefulness & friendliness with other classes, packages etc. A first glance at the documentation, however, looks «promising». If you can't get away with «only» the font size adjustment, it may be worth a try.

Comment: Since my goal right now isn't imitating the entire Word set-up as closely as possible but just the font size, I don't think this solves the problem. The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wordlike/wordlike.pdf) says: "No attempt is made to set the default font size to `12pt` because this is typically done when loading a document class. So, font size is left to the users’ preferences. If you use `article.cls` your preamble should start like this: `\documentclass[12pt]{article} \usepackage{wordlike}`"

Comment: What I meant to say with above comment, the package `wordlike` doesn't seem to deal with the `pt` vs `bp` difference (nonwithstanding its other potential benefits).