# LaTeX font-size vs. word font-size

Tags: fontsize

I need to write an assignment, and my professor told me that I had to use MS Word with the "font-size 12". I assume, he means this number:

[image: Example MS-Word-Picture]

He is not a technical person, so he doesn't really know what this number represants and he cannot tell me.

I myself have never used MS Word, I am a linux-user and I'm writing my assignment with LaTex (which he actually allows me to do), because that's just my workflow and the results look way better.

Whatever, my question is, when he tells me to use "font-size 12" (in MS-Word), which is it?
Is it 12pt, 12mm, 12px, 12em, ..?

Which font-size should I specify in my documentclass to (kind of) fit his requirements?

Comment: Does [Setting a document in MS Word-12pt (12bp)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34024/35864) help you? But one could argue that 1/1606 inches are not really visible and just go with `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`.

Comment: I think Word font-sizes are point sizes. So it's probably just a question of specifying 12pt size in your documentclass declaration.

Comment: The big question is whether he expects a paper or a file.