# Increasing font size proportionately

Tags: fontsize

Configuration: report document class, Times New Roman text @12pt with footnote number and text @10pt.

Problem: My institution requires a Times New Roman size 12pt based on Word's, but Times New Roman 12pt in Latex is smaller by about 2pt, and the same goes for footnote number and text size.

Question: How can I increase these proportionately by 2pt or just about? I tried some global packages but they modified my line and paragraph spacing and the result actually made it worse. Looked at several threads but could not find a practical solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Setting a document in MS Word-12pt (12bp)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34024/5764)

Comment: @Werner thanks for the link but some answers in the thread there are too technical in nature, involving a smaller degree of spacing. Packages Wordlike did not work so far. I will keep looking.

Comment: The accepted answer suggests adding `\makeatletter\p@=1bp\makeatother` to your preamble. Is this not sufficient?

Comment: I think I got this right now. I read it again, and realized I had to put it above the documentclass, not after.

Comment: Another factor that may impinge on this problem is printer configuration. If printer is set to print in shrink mode rather than actual size then it will magnify the all fonts.