# Is font size in latex comparable to font size in word?

Tags: fontsize, msword, times

I need to hand in my master thesis soon and the guidelines state that it's highly recommended to take font size 12. However, when I use

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{times}
```

this seems to match the font size for example in ms word quite well. When I use `12pt` in the command above, it is quite huge. I would really appreciate some help

Comment: ,@patrickBalada Check out [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc) to learn more about font sizes in LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe [Setting a document in MS Word-12pt (12bp)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34024/35864) and all its related questions can help you.