# Package color Error: Argument `1.01125' not in range [0,1]

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I have been writing a paper and used tikz for some of my figures. Then when we decided to submit to a particular conference, and used the style file they provided, the figure broke (failed to compile). I dissected their style file and found that the line "\p@=1bp" is responsible for the problem, but I do not know what that line is and how to work around it. Simply removing the line is not a solution since I have no control over the style file they will use for the final publishable version.

This version works correctly:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [blue!25] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This version generates the error mentioned in the title:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter
\p@=1bp
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [blue!25] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Curiously, it works again when I remove the "!25" after "blue":

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter
\p@=1bp
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [blue] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am using pdflatex: pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/MacPorts 2016_4).

I am looking for a way to specify the color "blue!25" without modifying the style file. That is, with the following snippet present in the preamable:

```
\makeatletter
\p@=1bp
\makeatother
```

Thank you.

Comment: For the interested, the style file is dgruyter_NEW.sty: [2013/10/15 v0.87 Walter de Gruyter layout].

Comment: `\makeatletter
\p@=1bp
\makeatother` will completely break latex arithmetic and lead to errors such as the one you show.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle could you elaborate a bit on this? What is this parameter for, why is it defined to be 1pt (see gernot's answer) and why does it break latex arithmetic?

Comment: @pschulz Latex does not have floating point numbers so to work with (for example) 0.5 typical thing is to use `\dimen@=0.5\p@` which is `0.5pt` then to get back to 0.5 you can use `\the\dimen@` but if you change the value of `\p@` all the values are multiplied by 72.27/27 ....

Comment: @M.Alaggan Write to De Gruyter and tell them they can do better than breaking everything in LaTeX.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Didn't you mean: multiplied by 72.27/72?

Comment: @PeterWilson oops yes:-)

Comment: I have reported this to the feedback email addressees given for dgruyter and le-tex who maintain this package, so hopefully it will get fixed.

Comment: Congratulations to your investigative abilities. Finding out that the culprit is this particular line of the style file must have been tricky.

Comment: @gernot Thanks, but it wasn't really difficult. I generated a MWE first of my .tex file, then kept deleting statements from the .sty file from the end (assuming they won't affect earlier statements), and tried to compile. I'd stop when the compilation succeeded. The culprit was actually the very first line of the .sty file!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\p@` is originally defined as `1.0pt`. After `\p@=1bp` it has the value `1.00374pt`. I suggest to add the lines

```
\makeatletter
\p@=1pt
\makeatother
```

to the preamble after loading `dgruyter_NEW.sty`.

**Edit:** The issue is still present in the most recent version of [de Gruyter's LaTeX package](https://www.degruyter.com/fileasset/pdfs/AUTH_DG_LaTeX-Template.zip). One of the first lines in `dgruyter.sty` (identifying itself as `2016/09/28 v1.82 De Gruyter layout`) still reads `\p@=1bp\relax`, which leads to the error described in the original post.

Comment: @M.Alaggan  You should accept this (which is what you should do). In my answer I rather concentrated on why the class is wrong Hopefully the maintainers of the class will see this question and fix it...

Comment: Just as info: `2017/09/19 v2.00 De Gruyter layout` still has this wonderful feature...

Answer (score 12):

Actually I get no error on the supplied test file however

```
\makeatletter
\p@=1bp
\makeatother
```

is spectacularly wrong and will break almost all latex arithmetic, not only `color`, but the `graphics` package, arithmetic by the `calc` package, `tabularx`, .....

To see why note that latex has no floating point registers, only lengths or integers so if for example you are mixing colours and need to multiply .3 by 2 the usual way is to go via lengths

```
\dimen@=.3\p@
```

now `\dimen@` is .3pt

```
\dimen@=2\dimen@
```

now it is .6pt

```
\edef\result{\strip@pt\dimen@}
\show\result
```

removes the `pt`

```
> \result=macro:
->0.6.
```

But now redefine `\p@` to be `1bp` the same calculation ends up with

```
> \result=macro:
->0.60223.
```

so even the simplest arithmetic operation gives an incorrect result.

Comment: To complete the story: One might wonder why the packages use `0.3\p@` instead of `0.3pt`. LaTeX defines several macros like `\p@` and `\z@` (see lines 465ff of `latex.ltx`) as *abbreviations* for `1pt` and `0pt`, for *efficiency reasons*. Redefining these macros is equivalent to changing the semantics of LaTeX.

Comment: @gernot where "changing the semantics of" is polite for "utterly completely breaking" :-)