# DGruyter package & polyglossia

Tags: babel, polyglossia, greek

I was recently granted access to DGruyter package, as I am finalising a book for this publishing house. Before, I was compiling the TeX through XeLaTeX, using `reledmac` & `polyglossia` for Polytonic Greek.

However, DGruyter package already loads babel package as default and I should define after `\documentclass` the languages used in the book. Since I was compiling with `polyglossia`, now I have a huge problem with the use of `\textgreek{}` which is massive in my .tex to allow syllabation.

Any idea to cope with this problem?

An example follows:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = it_IT
% !TeX root = book.tex
% !BIB TS-program = biber

\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{latin,greek}
        \setkeys{greek}{variant=polytonic}

\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\Xarrangement[A,B,C]{paragraph}
\Xbeforenotes[A,B,C]{2em plus.4em minus.4em} 
\Xafternote[A,B,C]{2em plus.4em minus.4em} 
\Xnotenumfont{\bfseries}
\Xnumberonlyfirstinline[A,B,C]
\Xnumberonlyfirstintwolines[A,B,C]
\Xlemmaseparator[A,B,C]{]}
\Xbeforelemmaseparator[A,B,C]{0.1em}
\Xafterrule[A,B,C]{1em}
\setmsdataposition{regular-msdata}
\setmsdataseries{A,B,C}
\Xstanza[A,B,C]
\Xstanzaseparator[A,B,C]{.}
\Xinplaceofnumber{0pt}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{ἀγαθός}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use greek (and define \textgreek) also with babel. Be aware that the dgruyter.sty I know sets `\p@=1bp` in the sty and this break various things in latex, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352590/2388

Comment: Thanks! However, if I put greek.ancient to use babel, then \textgreek is said to be an “undefined control sequence” after processing the file

Comment: well then define \textgreek to switch to greek. Look up `\babeltags` in the babel documentation.

Comment: So: it seems that \babeltags does not work with dgruyter, nor \languageattribute{greek}{ancient} or \languageattribute{greek}{polutoniko} do. greek.ancient and greek.polutoniko are not defined.

I found a solution to cope with the error by putting \documentclass[openany,ngerman,greek]{book} and \newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{%
\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}#1\end{otherlanguage*}}, but although the Tex is now processed, the Greek text eventually do not appear in the pdf...

Comment: well in your example greek doesn't work neither (even if one remove dgruyter), so your document is probably doing things you didn't told yet. In any case the following works fine for me: `\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[greek.polutonico,ngerman]{babel}
\babeltags{greek=greek}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}{Arial}
\begin{document}
some text \textgreek{ἀγαθός}
\end{document}`.