# Undefined control sequence when using algorithm environment with dgruyter.sty

Tags: errors, templates, algorithms

I need to write a document using the dgruyter template. When I include an algorithm environment I get the following error.

```
Undefined control sequence.

<write> ...\protect \numberline {\plist@algorithm 
                                                  1}{\ignorespaces Alg\relax... l.32 \end{document}
                    The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g.,
`\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[USenglish]{article}  

\usepackage[big,online]{dgruyter}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Alg}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Test
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

An overleaf project with the files can be found here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/gnrtmsvxbsgt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sigh, you should moan to the publishers, they should fix this

https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/twiki/view/CrySP/LaTeXSnippets

discusses several errors in this file including this one.

This works

```
\documentclass[USenglish]{article}  

\usepackage[big,online]{dgruyter}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\def\plist@algorithm{Alg.\space}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Alg}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Test
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The package _still_ has `\p@=1bp\relax`  after all these years and multiple reports so it basically breaks latex arithmetic.

Comment: I once complained about that. Answer: "_Most LaTeX experts say that's OK_."

Comment: I have complained more than once and I didn't say it was OK:-) @campa

Comment: It seems not OK if it breaks a basic package :'( I'll try to find out where to file a bug report. And thank you very much!

Comment: @AlexbGoode the `1bp` thing isn't the cause of this error, but it does break `\includegraphics`, `tabularx`, ....

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352590/1090

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375063/1090