# Problem with linespace and parskip and font size

Tags: line-spacing, parskip, baseline

I am writing a thesis template with properties like word template.

> in MS Wors: Font size=14pt, linespace=1.2, space before chapter/section/subsection title = 30pt/27pt/20pt.

What I have done so far is:

> - After loading `extbook.cls` with `fontsize=14pt` I set `\setlength{\p@}{1bp}`. (like 14pt in word)
> - Then, in the end of template I set `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.23429}` (=1.2 in word)
> - Then I changed `\parskip` to a bit more than `\baselinestretch` (I don't know the exact value of `\parskip` in word but it seems it is a bit more than `\baselinestretch`).

I am sure (mostly) that the second change of `\baselinestretch` is exactly equal to its analogous in word. (by comparing its outputs). But

> **Q1:** why after setting `\setlength{\p@}{1bp}`, `\baselinestretch{1.2}` isn't equal to its analogous in word?
>
> **Q2:** How to prevent other changes (except paragraph skip) that has been defined by old `parskip` like space after `sections`?

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\p@}{1bp}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parskip}{1.2\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.23429}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter} \pagebreak
\section{First Section} 
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{First Subsection}
\chapter{Second Chapter} \pagebreak
\section{Second Section} 
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `\setlength{\p@}{1bp}` will completely break LaTeX arithmetic and could lead to quite unexpected errors (especially when handling pictures). _Don't do that!_

Comment: I just followed [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34060). Can you provide a link or example that shows the _unexpected errors_?

Comment: Look e.g. at the last two comments on the post you linked.

Comment: If you redefine p@ then any output you get from latex is by luck not by design. The system will be fundamentaly  broken

Comment: It is rather odd to set parskip without setting parindent to 0pt perhaps you could look at the parskip package

Comment: So, What is the best way for converting `pt` to `bp`? just computing `x*72/72.27 pt= 14 bp`? or I should involve `\baselineskip`?

Comment: Or Is this a good way that I create a file like `\input{bk1\@ptsize.clo}` using `bp` dim and the use it instead of `\input{bk1\@ptsize.clo}`?

Comment: The difference between 14bp and 14pt is a tad less than 0.02mm. I don't think any secretary will notice the difference with their ruler. For 30bp and 30pt the difference is still less than 0.04mm.