# What font size corresponds to 14pt in Microsoft Word?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, paragraphs, msword

I have seen many questions related to this but I didn't understand what to do and what command I have to use exactly.

My department has asked me to use 14pt font size for the paragraphs and 16pt font size for the sections' titles with MS Word.

They said it's ok to use any font type and I would like to keep LaTeX's font, but it looks pretty thin compared to other fonts. I am afraid they might reject it, is there any way to make it look thicker?

Comment: 14bp is Tex for Word 14pt but if using a different font you may as well use 14pt. the difference between 14bp and 14pt is less than the difference in size you might get from choosing two different fonts each at a nominal size of 14pt

Comment: See this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/setting-a-document-in-ms-word-12pt-12bp

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the font looks much smaller when using 14bp, btw I am using extarticle document class

Comment: @Naseebah that is a length not a package option, use 14pt as a declared option.

Comment: Latin Modern (the default font in lualatex) is derived from Computer Modern and is brutally thin, but that is its design, it doesn't really make sense to say you want to keep the font but change is core design feaure. Why not pick a different font?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't get the "that is a length not a package option, use 14pt as a declared option" part can you give me an example

Comment: `\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}` is what you want the `14pt`there is a class option, you can not use arbitrary lengths there. `14bp` would not work, neither would `14.5pt` or `3cm` or any other length

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you, so you are suggesting me to keep 14pt but change the font type to get the desired size

Comment: No. I mean just use 14pt. that is the desired size within the accuracy needed. It is out by a factor of 72/72.27  but fonts that claim to be "14pt" differ by more than that, a font size isn't a measured number it is an arbitrary label added by the font designer. So if you want to use exactly the same font as Word you could use Times New Roman at 14bp, but if you are changing fonts the difference between 14pt and 14bp really doesn't matter.

Comment: Just compare fonts in https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/seriffonts.html and pick one where the example phrase ("The quick brown fox ..")  spread more that Computer Mordern, e.g., IBM Plex Serif Medium probably is much thicker that you see in Word, but maybe Deja Vu is fine ... On the other hand, using xelatex or lualatex most probably you can just use the font used in Word, as these engines support TTF and OTF fonts, so the result must be exactly the same.