# Is font size 12 in MS Word same as [12pt]?

Tags: fontsize

Is a Times New Roman font of 12 size in MS Word, same as doing a `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}`?

Edit: To be clear, the question is if Word with a 12 font and `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}` are the same things, or similar enough?
[The suggested link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/setting-a-document-in-ms-word-12pt-12bp) has lots of information and "solutions" but nowhere it is clearly concluded if the above two are the same, or not...

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/setting-a-document-in-ms-word-12pt-12bp and references therein

Comment: @Rmano [This comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/setting-a-document-in-ms-word-12pt-12bp#comment67406_34024) says no difference, but if I replace `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}` with `\documentclass[12bp,a4paper]{article}`, it is very different in my PDF...

Comment: @ZeroTwo `12bp` is not a valid option to `\documentclass{article}`, so it *does not* set the font to 12bp, but the default font size (which is 10pt) will be used. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5339/47927

Comment: @JasperHabicht
Thank you for clearing that up. The template I have for my article is in Word with a `12` font, and I am just wondering if I use `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}`, is that same, or similar enough? The links have lots of information and "solutions" but nowhere it is clearly concluded if the above two are the same, or not, unless am missing something obvious.

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}` is not the same as size 12 in word. You have to decide yourself if it is similar enough....

Comment: @ZeroTwo Well, the in the question of the very first link in the comments, Wikipedia is cited with "The 12 point of Word will be PostScript point, which in TeX would be called 12bp. A TeX pt is slightly smaller: it's 1/72.27 inch, while a bp/PostScript point is 1/72 inch." So, there you have your answer: It is different, but really not much.