Inline math font size significantly smaller (or larger) than surrounding text font size when using uarial
I'm having trouble with the font size of (inline) math compared to the standard text size. The mathematical expressions have a font size that is visibly smaller than the surrounding text's size. Here is a minimal example:
\documentclass[a4paper,ngerman,11pt]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%\DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{11.3}{7.7}{5.5}
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
         \question Test $xy$ Test
    \end{questions}
\end{document}

As you can see, I am using the exam class and also the uarial font. Unfortunately, I need to use uarial though the issue is much less striking with the default font.
Here is how it looks like:

I tried using the \DeclareMathSizes command but, depending on the value in the second argument, it has either no effect on the maths font size or it makes them too big...
Here is how it looks like with 13.3 or more as second argument:

On the other hand, with 13.2 or less the math font size is too small. There seems to be no value which exactly matches the text font size.
Is there anything I can do about this problem? Thanks for any hints!

Unrelated to your size problem, but have you considered a different combination of fonts, maybe some which are more similar in weight?

Thanks for the proposal! I need to mimic Arial as main text font, what would be a suiting math font?

If you need Arial for the main text, I'd switch to an unicode-aware engine like lualatex and then use the fontspec package to actually use Arial as text font. Do you want the math to be serif or sans serif?

I prefer a serif font to make it more distinguishable from the main text. Unfortunately, I have no experience with switching the LaTeX engine and expect difficulties popping up when using it for the very first time, which I won't have time to deal with as of now. But I'll keep it in mind for next time!

OK, then pdflatex fonts only :) Instead of uarial, you could try \usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}. This allows you to scale the text font. For math, maybe try \usepackage[notext]{stix2}?

It looks very similar and actually solves the original issue as well! Thanks for the idea! I just need to adjust it because some spacings changed a bit and I need to exactly match a Word template. :)

My sincere condolence for having to match a word template :P

Yeah, it's a major PITA... I can do whatever I want with my other teaching material but exams need to be standardized and, since the majority of my colleagues use Word, the standard is a Word template.
The document looks even more ugly now with stix2 as math font, but at the same time more similar to the Word version. So it's a good thing, I guess...

Depending on how horrible your Word template is you might want to use mathastext to use Arial (or Helvetica -- most people don't see the difference anyway) as your math font as well (yes, I speak from painful experience here).

No no, that's fine, luckily inline math is allowed to be a different font in my case. What matters is the text font and also the header. I reproduced the header, sitting with a ruler and a printout from last year's exam... Now things shifted a bit, but it shouldn't be too difficult to fix.

I would suggest to use a math font which has a more similar weight to the text font. If you need to stay with pdflatex, the choice isn't as large as with an unicode-aware engine, but there are still plenty of combinations. As a side effect, you could choose fonts which you can scale and thus avoid the height mismatch.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{exam}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[notext]{stix2}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
         \question Test $xy$ Test
    \end{questions}
\end{document}



You are using scale 0.95 here and scale 0.9 in your original comment for the Helvetica font. Do you possibly know, which one is to be expected to better match an 11pt Arial Word document?

@Photon the 0.9 was just a quick guess to write the comment. Actually trying it, I thought it looked a bit too small compared to the math. But you can also do it the other way round and scale the math. (be careful, word uses different lengths, let me see if I can find an old question about this)

@Photon https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/setting-a-document-in-ms-word-12pt-12bp

Thanks! It's really exciting that such subtle things can be adjusted to make it look even closer! Actually, I had another font size issue, some parts of the header I need to reproduce are 14pt, some are 11pt and some are even 9pt. While 11pt is the font size throughout the rest of the document, I approximated the other sizes with \Large and \footnotesize but there are slight differences. This pt vs. bp conversion won't help here as well though, I fear?

@Photon you can use \fontsize{14pt}{16.3pt}\selectfont to use 14pt.

If you want you could even change the sizes \Large and friends use to values that match your template.

Niceeee! How would I go about 9pt? Like, how did you calculate the 16.3pt value in the 14pt case?

@Photon If you  reply to Skillmon, you should ping him by adding @Skillmon to your comment

Right, didn't think about it, thanks!

@Skillmon, would be great if you could have a quick look at my previous comment!

@Photon 16.3 is just a rough estimate for the baseline skip, I calculated it using <old-baselineskip>/<old-size> * <new-size>, so in your case since you're using 12pt fontsize and 14pt baseline skip I used 14 / 12 * 14 and 16.3 is rounded to the first decimal place.

@Skillmon I'm actually using 11pt font size. :) So the formula is new²/old? That would give me 14²/11 and 9²/11 for font sizes 14 and 9 in an 11pt document, is this correct?

@Photon The ration of fontsize and baselineskip is matter of taste and a design descension for your document. Factors in the range of 1.2 to 1.4 are probably the most common ones.

@Photon no, the formula is not new²/old, I explicitly stated the formula :) It's <old-baselineskip>/<old-size> * <new-size>. And that's only to give a uniform factor across font sizes, see samcarter's comment above this one.

@Skillmon I didn't know the meaning of the term baselineskip and assumed that, whatever it is, it can be set equal to the new size because that's what the values you used suggested. But now I looked it up and to be honest I don't quite understand why it is 14 in your example... Sorry, I'm somewhat swamped by these measures of size and spacing as I've never needed them yet.

@Photon A bit simplified: \fontsize{<size of the font>}{<distance between lines>}. To get some space between the lines, the second argument should be a bit bigger than the font size.

Ah, I see, so this second argument which we are calculating is the new baselineskip and we need to scale the estimated old baselineskip with the font size ratio. As long as the font size itself is correct, it should be easy to find the correct value by comparing with the template. Also, only single lines in the header require non-default font size, so I can move them around with \vspace in worst case, as long as the font size itself is correct. Thanks for the explanation to both of you!

Load uarial with the option scaled=1 (the default is scaled=0.95). Then add in the document
\sbox0{x}\the\ht0

\sbox0{$x$}\the\ht0

You'll get two lines with

5.57901pt
4.71457pt

Now fire up your calculator and compute the quotient 4.71457/5.57901, that approximates to 0.84505.
Now you know the scaling factor you want:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{exam}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[scaled=0.84505]{uarial}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{x}\the\ht0

\sbox0{$x$}\the\ht0

\begin{questions}
  \question Test $xy$ Test
\end{questions}

\end{document}


The difference of 0.00005pt is negligible.
You might want to try a sans serif math font:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{exam}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[scaled=0.88321]{uarial}
\usepackage{newtxsf}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{x}\the\ht0

\sbox0{$x$}\the\ht0

\begin{questions}
  \question Test $xy$ Test
  \[
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx
  \]
\end{questions}

\end{document}

The scaling factor has been computed in the same way as before.

