# Where can I find an online manual for low-level LaTeX commands?

Tags: macros, online, documentation, latex-base

Is there an online manual for low-level LaTeX commands I can download?

I am looking for something which would have, for example:

```
\newif\ifportrait
\newif\ifcustomsize
\newif\ifdebug

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{theindex}
  {\if@twocolumn
      \@restonecolfalse
   \else
      \@restonecoltrue
   \fi
   \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
   \setlength{\columnsep}{35pt}
   \begin{multicols}{3}[\section*{\indexname}]
   \markboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
            {\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
   \thispagestyle{plain}
   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
   \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.3pt}
   \relax
   \let\item\@idxitem}%
  {\end{multicols}\if@restonecol\onecolumn\else\clearpage\fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: With "online manual" you mean "manual I can download online" or "manual which pops up by itself when an error appears"? Do you mean low-level **LaTeX** commands or **plainTeX** macros and primitives?

Comment: Related: [Documentation reference for LaTeX internal commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands).

Comment: low-level LaTeX, not plainTeX.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The LaTeX2e kernel macros are documented in [`source2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e). An unfinished [`macros2e`](http://www.scharrer-online.de/wiki/LaTeX/Docs/macros2e) document lists all of its macros which are deemed directly useful for package authors.

If you need help with the underlying plainTeX macros and primitives (which lie even deeper than the LaTeX kernel) then I suggest the free books *[TeX for the impatient](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/impatient)* and *[TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic)* which are freely available on CTAN.

Comment: IOW `texdoc source2e`, `texdoc impatient`. I would also add `texdoc texbytopic`.

Comment: @przemoc: Thanks for mentioning it. I don't like to constantly repeat that it can also be accessed by `texdoc`. If it is on CTAN then it should be also accessible that way, but some people might not know `texdoc`.

Comment: Martin Scharrer, i see your macros2e, but where did you learn what is there?

Comment: @Martin: Sure, understandable. The thing is I believe that a lot of people is still unaware of `texdoc`. I'm think that way, because I myself haven't known about this for a few years since I started LaTeX never-ending journey...

Comment: @xport: I was going to answer, but then I read that it's for iPad, so I stopped... :) EDIT: was only joking, use link provided by Martin, it's there linked as `CTAN directory`. In Linux it's here: `/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc-en/plain/impatient`

Comment: @Regis: I was studying `source2e` and the `latex.ltx` file.

Comment: @przemoc: You are right, I just learned about it two years ago. Way too late! (I wonder how long it is around)

Comment: @xport: The sources should be on CTAN too: ftp://tug.org/tex/impatient/, see also the homepage: http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/teximpatient

Comment: Calling a 400 page manual “for the impatient” is a rather strange definition of “impatient”.

Comment: @xport: Yes, or maybe you need to use `etex.exe` if it uses eTeX. I never compiled it by myself.

Comment: @Caramdir: I sense a disturbance in the Force. The boy has no patience. _The LaTeX Companions Third Revised Boxed Set: A Complete Guide and Reference for Preparing, Illustrating and Publishing Technical Documents (3rd Edition)_ has 3300+ pages. What it is, mere 400 pages?

Comment: @przemoc: Psst! Don't remind me! I bought it a few years ago and never really read it. I also bought now Knuth's box set and have to read *The TeXBook* again, but more detailed this time.

Comment: @przemoc: Compared to that, `lshort` really does seem short.

Comment: @You: Obviously, `lshort2e` is just a brochure with basics of the basics of the basics... If you have some luck, you may not need anything more to complete your current paper at visually acceptable level.

Answer (score 8):

here is a list of the LaTeX commands in different formats:

http://home.gna.org/latexrefman/

Comment: Seems to be the same as [latex2e-help-texinfo](http://ctan.org/pkg/latex2e-help-texinfo).