# Which books can I read via texdoc?

Tags: documentation, books, texdoc

For years, I was faithfully downloading a copy of *TeX by Topic* whenever I reinstalled my computer.  Then I learnt about `texdoc texbytopic` and my life got just that smidgen easier.  I've just returned from a foray in cyberspace where I wanted to learn about the `\mathpalette` command and found *TeX for the impatient*.  One of the exotic fruits I found on that foray was [Where can I find an online manual for low-level LaTeX commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22883/where-can-i-find-an-online-manual-for-low-level-latex-commands/22886#22886) where Martin suggested `texdoc impatient`.

On the basis that a book in `texdoc` is

1. free,
2. on my system, and
3. at least vaguely approved by the TeX community

if I found myself at a loose end one evening and wanted to curl up with a good book on TeX, the ones in `texdoc` seem a good place to start.

But knowing what is there is a difficult task, so I thought that a nice CW list would help us all find something to read on those long winter nights.

I think that this is an obvious CW question (assuming it doesn't get closed) and one organised answer would be better than a load of disorganised ones.  What would be useful information to have would be:

1. Name of book
2. `texdoc` invocation
3. Which main distributions is it in (TeXLive? MikTeX?)
4. Vague area of coverage

As I intend this to be CW, we can build that up incrementally, so if you know of a book but don't know about distributions, list it and someone can test if it's in their distribution.

One thing to be clear is that this is *not* for individual packages, even if the documentation is more like a book than anything else.

Comment: Good question.  I didn't "grow up" with texdoc and as a result, it is always my destination of last resort and I have no idea what is there.

Comment: None of the `texdoc xxx` with the the books listed in these posts works for me with MiKTeX 2.9. For manuals of packages that I have installed, it does work. Does MiKTeX not contain them or might there be some other issue so that I should ask a separate question?

Comment: @doncherry: (I don't have MiKTeX so can't test this myself) are the files on the system?  Can you search for, say, `texbytopic.pdf`?

Comment: @Andrew: No, can't be found. I don't have the full install of MiKTeX though, so only when I first use a package it's downloaded. I double-checked the package manager and found something, I'm working on an answer right now.

Comment: `texdoc texdoc` does not  produce an infinite loop but brings the documentation of `texdoc` up. It is useful for those who do not know what `texdoc` is.

Answer (score 23):

In addition to "*TeX by Topic*":

1. Oetiker's "*The Not So Short  Introduction to LaTeX 2ε*" in English.
   Available in other languages as, for example, `texdoc lshort-german`
   but these are usually older than the English version. Invoke as
   `texdoc lshort` in TeX Live 
      
   Not all language versions are obvious; to get a full list of what's
   available, at least on linux, `texdoc -l lshort`; as of July 2014, there
   are over 60 possibilities, of which 17 are marked "The document itself".
2. Knuth's “*TeX82*” (= "*TeX: The Program*"). Invoke as `texdoc tex` in TeX Live.
3. "*TeX for the Impatient*” (2003) by Abrahams, Hargreaves and Berry.
   Invoke as `texdoc impatient/book.pdf` in TeX Live. Also
   available in French as `texdoc impatient-fr/fbook.pdf`.
4. "*A Few Notes on Book Design*" (2009) by Peter R Wilson. Available as `texdoc memdesign` in TeX Live. Whilst originally part of the `memoir` class documentation it is now separate from that documentation and is a volume on book design in its own right so I think it can satisfy the criteria for this list.
5. "TeX in a Nutshell" (2020) by Petr Olsak. Available as `texdoc nutshell` in TeX Live. It briefly summarizes basic TeX features and TeX primitive commands and plain TeX macros.

Answer (score 16):

It seems to me that given a package name, `texdoc` will search for a PDF in the package directory and display it using your favorite PDF reader.

For example, when typing `texdoc impatient`, it opens:

```
/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/doc/plain/impatient/book.pdf
```

When typing `texdoc texbytopic`, it opens:

```
/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf
```

etc. With that in mind, here is a quick and dirty way to get a list of parameters you can pass to `texdoc` using `sed`:

```
find /path/to/texlive/2011/ -type f -name '*.pdf' | sed 's@.*/\([^/][^/]*\)/[^/][^/]*\.pdf@\1@' | sort -u
```

which on TL2011 returns 1720 names.

That said, the books you mentioned were found specifically in `/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/doc/plain`, so you can restrict that to:

```
find /path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/doc/plain/ -type f -name '*.pdf' | sed 's@.*/\([^/][^/]*\)/[^/][^/]*\.pdf@\1@' | sort -u
```

which returns 14 results:

```
fontch
font-change
gentle
getoptk
hyplain
impatient
impatient-fr
metatex
mkpattern
newsletr
pgfplots
present
texbytopic
tugboat-plain
```

Comment: Exactly!  1720 is a bit too many for me to go through and figure out which are *books* and which are *package documentation*.  I'm after the things that you can get via `texdoc` that you would never find if all you ever did was `texdoc package`.

Comment: For some reason the `sed` command didn’t work on my Mac – not sure what the issue is (surely something to do with extended regex) but the following version did: `sed 's@^.*/\([^/]*\)/[^/]*\.pdf$@\1@'`.

Comment: @Konrad: MacOS doesn't use GNU Sed, it's another version (with slightly different options and syntax).

Comment: @Raphink True but I’m not aware of any syntax changes in the above expression. Specifically, `\+` should normally work the same since both commands use the BRE dialect by default.

Comment: The `sed` command should now work on both Mac and GNU/Linux. I converted Raphink's regular expression to POSIX BRE format (and dropped the unnecessary `-e`).

Answer (score 13):

`texdoc gentle` gets you michael doob's "a gentle introduction to tex", which was the precursor to "tex starting from square 1" and still a good resource for learning about plain tex.  in tex live; don't know about other distributions.

somewhat more obvious is `texdoc metapost`, "metapost, a user's manual"; although this is user documentation rather than a formal book, mp is a large enough system that the user's manual (it doesn't cover the program code itself) seems to fall within the subject category.

although it's not about tex itself, `texdoc comprehensive`, for "the comprehensive latex symbol list`, covers an area that's the subject of lots of questions, and might be the resource most frequently cited in answers.

in the tex family, though also not about tex itself, `texdoc mf` gets "metafont: the program".

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the above answers, In TeXLive distribution the [`texdoc` command line](http://www.tug.org/texdoc/doc/texdoc.pdf) has a Perl/Tk-based GUI known as [`texdoctk`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texdoctk) for easy ac­cess to pack­age doc­u­men­ta­tion.

On Windows 7 with TeXLive 2012 it works without any installation `perl/tk`

[image]

On Ubuntu with TeXLive 2012 it needs installation `perl/tk`

[image]

With any keyword/package name in GUI `TeX Documentation Browser` search box it leads to list of relevant pdfs similar to `texdoc -l <keyword>`

PS: It's another choice available, kindly ignore incase you know or prefer command line. To have it for record.

Answer (score 7):

### MiKTeX

Most of the answers here refer to TeX Live and I couldn't really retrieve any of them with MiKTeX 2.9, so I tried to find out what MiKTeX has in store. The package manager lists the following as "Documentation":

```
comprehensive
es-tex-faq
first-LaTeX-doc
firststeps
fontsampler
greekdoc
guides
Italian-doc
knuth
l2tabu ~-english ~-italian
latex-doc-ptr
latex-veryshortguide
latex2e-help-texinfo
latex4wp
lkort
lshort-english ~-finnish ~-french ~-german ~-mongolian ~-persian ~-polish ~-portuguese
     ~-russian ~-slovak ~-slovenian ~-spanish ~-ukranian
metapost-examples
tds
tex-refs
uk-tex-faq
```

To be able to access these, you need to [install them via the package manager](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html) first.

I tried invoking some of these via `texdoc` and it seems to me that you can only invoke those available in a compiled form (pdf or dvi) or as HTML files ([TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org)). `texdoc knuth` doesn't work, presumably because you're not allowed to compile The TeX Book. (See additionally [How to force MikTeX' texdoc to open package manuals with a PDF reader rather than the DVI viewer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54474/how-to-force-miktex-texdoc-to-open-package-manuals-with-a-pdf-reader-rather-tha.))

Obviously, not all of these can be called a *book*, but I'm afraid this is all there is in MiKTeX.

Comment: How to deal with documents like `ascii-chart` and – more important, I think – `voss-mathmode`, what are uncategorized?

Answer (score 5):

My LaTeX books can be read via `texdoc`:

```
texdoc dickimaw-novices
```

for ["LaTeX for Complete Novices"](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/) (introductory) and

```
texdoc dickimaw-thesis
```

for ["Using LaTeX to Write a PhD Thesis"](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/) (thesis-related topics).

The article ["Creating a LaTeX minimal example"](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/) (debugging techniques) is also available via `texdoc`:

```
texdoc dickimaw-minexample
```

I will also add my pending LaTeX book ["LaTeX for Administrative Work"](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/) (intermediate to advanced admin-related topics) to [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/dickimaw) at some point after it's published. If you do:

```
texdoc -l dickimaw
```

you'll get the list of available documents. (Available on both MiKTeX and TeX Live.)