# \@ifnextchar and friends documentation

Tags: macros, books, latex-base

While reading [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57788/412) and its answers I tried to find where, for instance, `\@ifnextchar` is documented. I'm afraid I couldn't... I looked in *TeX: The Program* and *TeX for the Impatient* which can be found in `texdoc`([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27636/which-books-can-i-read-via-texdoc)) and of course in Google, but found no real documentation. **My question is where is it documented?**

Actually a broader question is where similar internal commands of `(La)TeX` are documented? I encounter in TeX.SE many answers which involve core components of `La(Tex)` but I usually fail to find a rigorous documentation of these elements. 
This makes it more difficult to have deeper understanding of the answer, and in particular try to modify/adopt the solutions to slightly different problems. So the main question is: **Where core command are documented?**

***Edit:*** Let me fine tune my question since most of the answer aimed mainly at the `\@ifnextchr`. What is a (the?) *canonical* documentation of both `TeX` and `LaTeX`, where magic like `\@ifnextchr` and similar `@` involving elements are documented? Is it only TeXbook? What is the `LaTeX` equivalent of TeXbook?

Comment: `texdoc source2e` from your terminal

Comment: latex source available in hardback: [latex2e] (http://www.lulu.com/shop/tim-arnold/latex-sources/hardcover/product-971405.html;jsessionid=581F56D7DADA216166C9BD61DE2BF2D4)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The definitive source for the documentation of the LaTeX kernel is `source2e.pdf`, compiled from the `.dtx` files from which `latex.ltx` and the auxiliary files loaded at format creation time are extracted. The PDF file should be available in your TeX distribution (`texdoc source2e`).

For example `\@ifnextchar` is documented in section 11.3 of `source2e.pdf`

Its definition is in lines 253ff. of `ltdefns.dtx`, but it's best understood by examples.

```
\def\input{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\@iinput\@@input}
```

If the token following `\input` is an open brace, then execute `\@iinput`, otherwise execute `\@@input` (which is the primitive meaning of `\input`).

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\sqrt{\@ifnextchar[\@sqrt\sqrtsign}
```

If the token following `\sqrt` is an open (square) bracket, then execute `\@sqrt` (there's the optional argument), otherwise execute the simpler `\sqrtsign`: `\def\@sqrt[#1]{\root #1\of}` reduces `\@sqrt[#1]` to the Plain TeX derived construction.

Notice that the following token is *not* removed (unless it's a space token), so after `\sqrt[3]{x}` there will be

```
\@sqrt[3]{x}
```

that is then parsed correctly.

`\@ifnextchar` is used in the definition of `\@ifstar`:

```
\def\@ifstar#1{\@ifnextchar *{\@firstoftwo{#1}}}
```

So `\def\xyz{\@ifstar\s@xyz\@xyz}` will do, with a following `*`,

```
\xyz*
\@ifstar\s@xyz\@xyz*
\@ifnextchar *{\@firstoftwo{\s@xyz}}\@xyz*
\@firstoftwo{\s@xyz}*
\s@xyz
```

and, when there's no *,

```
\xyz t
\@ifstar\s@xyz\@xyz t
\@ifnextchar *{\@firstoftwo{\s@xyz}}\@xyz t
\@xyz t
```

so we see that `\@ifstar` *does* remove the `*` (with a clever trick). Here `t` stands for any token that's not a `*`.

It's quite important to note that `\@ifnextchar` uses `\if` to perform the test, so, for example,

```
\let\myasterisk=*
\xyz\myasterisk
```

will be the same as `\xyz*`.

Answer (score 14):

`\@ifnextchar` is not a primitive TeX command but an internal macro of LaTeX. It is documented in [source2e](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) in section

> **11.3 Command definitions**

Comment: Is there some `TeX` equivalent where standard plain TeX macros are defined?

Comment: The magic incantation here is `\futurelet`. It will save a token from the current input to a control sequence without actually reading it (but catcodes get fixed of course). `\@ifnextchar` and friends use that and ten look at that saved token, deciding what to do next. `\futurelet` is documented in the TeXbook, with a similar application IIRC.

Comment: So *the* canonical documentation of `TeX` is solely TeXbook?

Comment: @Dror It's the only one I have ;-) Apart from this I mostly look in the sources.

Answer (score 10):

You can take a look at »[macros2e](http://ctan.org/pkg/macros2e)«. It's a quite comprehensive overview for often used macros (mostly by package writers). Type `texdoc macros2e` on the command line for instant access.

Answer (score 6):

There is also an implementation in LaTeX3. The module `l3token` is introduced with:

> `\peek` for looking ahead in the token stream

Here an example

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \mytestfunction
 {
 test~the~next~token:~
 \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF \c_group_begin_token
  { TRUE } { FALSE }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\mytestfunction

\mytestfunction[]

\mytestfunction{}

\mytestfunction      {}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

As @egreg said, source2e is the canonical source for LaTeX "core" macros. You can launch source2e from the command line with "`texdoc source2e`".

However, source2e is a giant document. You need to know how to use the index to find the definition of a macro. For example, here is the entry for `\@ifnextchar` (truncated):

> \@ifnextchar . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
>   . . I3, I13, 23, a45, __ d253 __, d258,
>   d274, i44, i206, k163, m13 ...

In the PDF you'll see that "`d253`" is underlined. The underline means the definition of the macro can be found in that section.

To find the definition of a given macro, look for it in source2e, then click the underlined section.

Regarding TeX, you can use "TeX for the Impatient" to look up "Plain TeX" macros. Again, at the command prompt, type "`texdoc impatient`". The index of that book follows the same conventions of source2e (which, in fact, follows the conventions of "The TeXbook"). The TeXbook is the **definitive** source for Plain TeX macros, but you need to buy a copy; it does not ship with any TeX distributions (in PDF form). So "TeX for the Impatient" serves well enough.

Unfortunately, there isn't a definitive way to tell where a particular macro is defined; i.e., if it is "Plain TeX," "LaTeX," or some other packages macro.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is the type of documentation you're after, but there is an alphabetical list of all tex commands (with descriptions) [here](http://www-sop.inria.fr/marelle/tralics/index.html).  For example, the command from the op is found [here](http://www-sop.inria.fr/marelle/tralics/doc-i.html#cmd-ifnextchar)