# Greek `\chi`'s subscript expressions: how to make it smaller or offset lower?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, etoolbox, xparse

I am unsatisfied with the way **subscript is rendered for the Greek letter** `\chi`. This particular letter is rendered with a small downward offset.
I occasionally have to prefix the subscript with `\sciptscriptstyle` such that, in effect, an expression may look like

```
\sup{\chi_{\scriptscriptstyle A_n}(x)}[n]
```

where

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\sup}{m O{}}{
    \operatorname{sup}\ifstrempty{#2}{}{\limits_{\mathclap{\substack{\expandafter{\scriptscriptstyle{#2}}}}}}
        \expandafter{#1} 
}
```

(*I admit this snippet is a little messy, especially due to the uncanonical declaration of the optional argument as `O{}` and testing via `\ifstrempty` instead of `o` for the argument type and `IfNoValueTF`--using the [xparse](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package. I am not entirely clear yet about what syntax is more straightforward.*)

Is there a way to **redefine** `\chi` **keeping the syntax in line with all semantically equivalent concepts**, i.e., letters, but having **only** `\chi`'s subscript expressions **smaller or slightly lower**? To clarify, I am thinking of redefining the subscript operator `_` for `\chi` only. But I naively suppose TeX' grammar would not let me do that.

An evident work-around would involve defining a new macro using a different syntax like

```
\newcommand{\Chi}[1]{\chi_{\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}}
```

So effectively, what I want is just

```
\chi_{expr}
```

where `expr` is **rendered smaller or offset lower** than default.

Comment: Alternately, you could render `\chi` a slight distance vertically higher (all the time, not just with subscripts).  While messing with a designer's fonts is not ideal, the alternative you propose of setting different size subscripts at the same nesting level could be very confusing.

Comment: What about `$\chi_{\textscit A_n}`? The problem is not so much with the letter chi than with capital letters in subscripts. Or you might define a new math alphabet  with italic smallcaps, and use `mathchoice` to use this new alphabet in (sub)subscripts.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I would rather abstain from changing the familiar look of `\chi`, changing it may seem confusing to some readers.

Comment: @Bernard: There are subscript expressions I come across in particular disciplines quite often that are less trivial, e.g., `\chi_{\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} A_j}`.

Comment: I see. I'm afraid there's no universal solution. Maybe redeclaring the font sizes for (sub)subscripts… But then, maybe you'll find "ordinary" subscripts  too small.

Comment: I've just found two similar questions (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83554/59118 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118508/59118) dealing with closely related issues. I've never used the `@`-commands but I'll read it up in `source2e` (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59402/59118) to try to understand the answers to the questions cited.

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks. Yes, this is one of my major concerns and the reason why I would not do it globally.

Comment: `\chi^{}_{A}` will have `A` slightly lower than in `\chi_{A}`, which might be what you want.

Comment: Why does this have the [tag:tikz-pgf] tag?

Comment: It's not clear at all what's the role of the redefined `\sup` in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `\scriptscriptstyle` is not a good typographical device, because it will make unbalanced symbols.

Here's the way for ensuring the subscript is shifted down as if there was a superscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\let\latexchi\chi
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chi{\@ifnextchar_\sub@chi\latexchi}
\newcommand{\sub@chi}[2]{% #1 is _, #2 is the subscript
  \@ifnextchar^{\subsup@chi{#2}}{\latexchi^{}_{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\subsup@chi}[3]{% #1 is the subscript, #2 is ^, #3 is the superscript
  \latexchi_{#1}^{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
$\latexchi_{A}\chi_{A}$\\[2ex]
$\latexchi_{A_{n}}\chi_{A_{n}}$\\[2ex]
$\chi_{A}\quad\chi_{A}^{2}\quad\chi^{2}_{A}\quad\chi^{2}\quad\chi$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578896/4427 for a more “modern” coding.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another possibility one might want to consider: Redefine `\chi` so that the bottom half of a "math strut" is inserted automatically after the character. (Aside: A mathstrut is a TeX object of zero width -- hence it's invisible -- and the height and depth of a round parenthesis, i.e., `)`.) That way, the position of any subscripts will be keyed off the `{\chi\mathstrut}` combo rather than the `\chi` symbol. Because the depth of the mathstrut exceeds the depth of `\chi`, the subscript will end up being placed lower -- as desired.

The solution below employs the `amsart` document class, which loads the `amsmath` package automatically. For non-AMS document classes, be sure to load the `amsmath` package so that the `\smash[t]{...}` macro is available.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\@latex@chi{\let\@latex@chi\chi}
\renewcommand*\chi{{\@latex@chi\smash[t]{\mathstrut}}} % want only bottom half of \mathstrut
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
Text before $\chi_{A}$, text after.

Text before $\chi_{S_{i}}$, text after

Another couple of lines of text for testing consistency of the gap between the 
baselines.  Some more text.  Some more text.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: @Mico: Good suggestion.  Why don't you directly edit my answer?

Comment: I've taken you up on your suggestion. :-)

Comment: @Mico: Now I am facing the problem: how can I pass on to you the upvote I received?  Your edit made a substantial improvement to my answer, and I feel like I’m stealing reputation from you!  :-)

Comment: Nah, no stealing involved here!

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\mychi}{\raisebox{0pt}[1ex][1ex]{$\chi$}}
\newlength{\temp}

\begin{document}
\[ \textrm{before}\quad \chi_A^2 \quad\textrm{after}\quad \mychi_A^2 \]

\settoheight{\temp}{$\chi$}
\noindent\the\temp\newline
\settoheight{\temp}{\mychi}
\the\temp
\end{document}
```

[image: chi squared]

You can fine tune the \rasisebox parameters as desired.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across the same problem. The solution that works for me is just writing it as a sub-subscript:

```
\chi_{_{A_n}}
```

[image: Rendered code]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the power of `xparse` to define new sub- and superscript arguments and pass them as optional arguments. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245422/21930) is the full code and explanation.

Basically you use `a` and `b` arguments in `xparse` that search for `_{#1}` and `^{#2}` respectively and then do whatever you want with those arguments. I use here the solution from egreg to show you how easy it is.

```
\let\originalchi\chi
\RenewDocumentCommand\chi{ab}
  {\originalchi
   \IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}%
   \IfValueTF{#2}{^{#2}}{^{}}}
...
$\originalchi_{A}\chi_{A}$\\[2ex]
$\originalchi_{A_{n}}\chi_{A_{n}}$\\[2ex]
$\chi_{A}\quad\chi_{A}^{2}\quad\chi^{2}_{A}\quad\chi^{2}\quad\chi$
```

`a` and `b` (and `A{<default>}` and `B{<default>}`) behave exactly like the rest of `xparse` arguments.

Here's the full compilable code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_count_type_k:w #1
 {
  \__xparse_single_token_check:n { #1 }
  \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:Nn #1 { \__xparse_bad_arg_spec:wn }
  \__xparse_count_mandatory:N
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_count_type_K:w #1 #2
 {
  \__xparse_single_token_check:n { #1 }
  \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:nn { #2 } { \__xparse_bad_arg_spec:wn }
  \__xparse_count_mandatory:N
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_add_type_k:w #1
 { \exp_args:NNo \__xparse_add_type_K:w #1 { \c__xparse_no_value_tl } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_add_type_K:w #1 #2
 {
  \__xparse_flush_m_args:
  \__xparse_add_grabber_optional:N K
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__xparse_signature_tl { #1 { #2 } }
  \__xparse_prepare_signature:N
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_add_expandable_type_k:w #1
 {
  \exp_args:NNo \__xparse_add_expandable_type_K:w #1 { \c__xparse_no_value_tl }
 }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__xparse_add_expandable_type_K:w #1 #2
 {
  \__msg_kernel_error:nnx { xparse } { invalid-expandable-argument-type } { K }
  \__xparse_add_expandable_type_m:w % May be create this?
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K:w #1 #2 #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
 {
  \__xparse_grab_K_aux:NnnNn #1 { #2 } { #3 } \cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn
   { _ignore_spaces }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K_long:w #1 #2 #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
 {
  \__xparse_grab_K_aux:NnnNn #1 { #2 } { #3 } \cs_set_protected:Npn
   { _ignore_spaces }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K_trailing:w #1 #2 #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
 {
  \__xparse_grab_K_aux:NnnNn #1 { #2 } { #3 } \cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn
   { _ignore_spaces }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K_long_trailing:w #1 #2 #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
 {
  \__xparse_grab_K_aux:NnnNn #1 { #2 } { #3 } \cs_set_protected:Npn
   { _ignore_spaces }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K_aux:NnnNn #1 #2 #3 #4 #5
 {
  \exp_after:wN #4 \l__xparse_fn_tl ##1
   {
    \__xparse_add_arg:n { ##1 }
    #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
   }    
  \use:c { peek_meaning_remove #5 :NTF } #1
   { \l__xparse_fn_tl }
   {
    \__xparse_add_arg:n { #2 }
    #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
   }
 }

\prop_put:Nnn \c__xparse_shorthands_prop { a } { k \sb }
\prop_put:Nnn \c__xparse_shorthands_prop { b } { k \sp }
\prop_put:Nnn \c__xparse_shorthands_prop { A } { K \sb }
\prop_put:Nnn \c__xparse_shorthands_prop { B } { K \sp }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\let\originalchi\chi
\RenewDocumentCommand\chi{ab}
  {\originalchi
   \IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}%
   \IfValueTF{#2}{^{#2}}{^{}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$\originalchi_{A}\chi_{A}$\\[2ex]
$\originalchi_{A_{n}}\chi_{A_{n}}$\\[2ex]
$\chi_{A}\quad\chi_{A}^{2}\quad\chi^{2}_{A}\quad\chi^{2}\quad\chi$
\end{document}
```