# Displaying $\chi_{A}$ properly?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\begin{document}
$\chi_{A}$

$\chi_{S_{i}}$

\end{document}
```

I found that the `$A$` in `$\chi_{A}$` does not look like a subscript; it seems too large. This problem becomes more obvious in the second example, `$\chi_{S_{i}}$`, which looks like `$\chi S_{i}$`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Okay, yes, thank you for your efforts. I did not find it.

Comment: You've deleted the the Font question some minutes ago -- Well, I want to delete my answer to it too, but I can't it. So undelete it please, I will delete my answer, you can delete your question, if you really think this is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Is the following too trivial?

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\begin{document}
$\chi_{\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\scriptstyle A$}}$

$\chi_{\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\scriptstyle S_{i}$}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. But, since I may use chi with subscripts (as an indicator function) many times, is there any alternative once-and-for-all way?

Comment: In my opinion, the better question is, why is $\Chi$ written so 'low' by default? I also somehow struggle with it.

Comment: It's not ‘so low’.  `χ` is a Greek letter with descenders, exactly the same as f, p or q for Computer Modern.

Comment: @Bernard: I wanted the effect to be clearly visible, so I chose a pretty large value.  One can substitute a smaller one, _e.g.,_ `-3ex`.  You might also want to have a look at the [answer I added to the other similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250556/69818).

Comment: Yes. I think another solution might be to have a (slanted) `mathsc` alphabet. The problem doesn't happen only with  χ, but with lowercase variable with descenders. Or one mightto defines different sizes for sub(sub)scripts, depending on whether they're uppercase or lowercase letters.