# Books for Library

Tags: books

Suggestion Required: I want to purchase a set of Latex books (Regarding Typesetting, Beamer, Tables, Graphics) for my library. your expert opinion regarding this matter is required.

Note: I already have LaTeX Beginner's Guide by Stefan Kottwitz.

Comment: The manuals for some of these things are always good to print out. `texdoc` the following: `beamer`, `memman`, `memdesign`, `booktabs`, `tikz`, `pstricks`, ….  See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27636/which-books-can-i-read-via-texdoc.

Comment: yes you are right that one can printout the manuals, but i want to place these books in my official library and it is not a good practice to have prints in library instead of books.

Comment: @Ahmad Why keeping manual printouts in a library is not a good practice? If they serve the purpose why should they be inferior to the more expensive solution?

Comment: due to copyrights etc.

Comment: @ MMA, thanks. I just asked our librarian, he replied that if book/manual is under general Public Licence then we can have prints.